# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - 12/2020)

Tags: discussion, re-open, big-list, undeletion

The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require reopen and undeletion votes. A request should be posted as an answer below (one request per answer).

Some guidelines:

- Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community. This goes for the person making the request as well as those commenting on it.
- There is a reopen queue. Please wait until a post has gone through this queue, before posting here. Notice that the first edit after the question is closed pushes the question into the reopen review queue if the edit is done within 5 days of closure, and so does a reopen vote.  (If the review has already been finished, it is shown on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) of the question.) When in doubt, wait 24 hours after the last substantive action.
- To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please add the information  **Reopened** or **Undeleted** at the start *once the request has resulted in some action*. (If the action is undone, add this too, like **Reopened, Reclosed**.)
- Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of `link`". Instead, make a case for your concern. Yet keep in mind that it can be easier to get your request handled if you try to frame it in a way that takes the feedback the post received into account positively rather then seeking confrontation. Also, try to improve the post before posting here.
- In case of "small" requests, like one missing vote, it can make sense to ask in chat instead of posting here. The room [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) is a reasonable place for such requests. The same guidelines apply there.
- If you are involved in the thread which you post about (e.g., you asked the question or you answered it), please disclose this.

---

Earlier versions of this thread that served as a model:

- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - 07/2018 )](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424)

Comment: I edited the post inspired by a concern expressed in a comment.

Answer (score 11):

**Reopened**

---

This is on the chopping block again:
[Is zero a prime number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539174/29335) The question was the subject of this meta discussion: [How to prevent the loss of excellent answers to poor questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21800/29335) which resulted in reopening.

(Disclosure, I have a solution on the question. I feel the question and solutions are worth fighting for, in this case.)

The reason *this* time for closure is "too broad", but it is far from obvious that this objection is valid. The OP asks three complete and answerable questions, two of which have answers elsewhere on the site. The remaining question became the focus of some of the answers, and there does not appear to duplicate with comparable content.

So for all intents and purposes, there is a single, clear question that seems rather likely for a layperson to ask, and there are good answers. There is nothing about the breadth of the question which inhibits solutions, as can be seen.

Furthermore, on the holistic side, after so many upvotes on the question and its solutions, and approaching now 30000 views, it seems that the post IS manifestly useful. So, I request your votes to re-open this.

Comment: I agree that this rather should not be closed, especially after the improvement of the post. (Yes, the question still has some shortcomings, but I feel it is "good enough".) I tangentially got involved last time; but stopped short of taking action. I reopened it now. (This is less of a so-called unilateral action as it was 'nearly' reopened two weeks ago. )

Comment: @quid Thank you for your attention to this!

Comment: @quid I'm curious:  my understanding was that closed questions were still viewable and not eligible for automatic deletion (assuming that the question is upvoted and has upvoted answers).   Why is it inappropriate to close the question and leave a message to the effect of "This question has been preserved because of a good answer.  It is never-the-less not a high quality question."  For example, the lock message on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good).

Comment: @XanderHenderson 'Why is it inappropriate to close the question and leave a message to the effect of "This question has been preserved because of a good answer. It is never-the-less not a high quality question.' Why do you use the indicative here? No one did that, as far as I know. In any case not recently. The question was reopened after a substantive edit, and then reclosed without comment, as 'too broad'. It also had a delete vote. Maybe more to the point, I would not consider it as inappropriate. But frankly given the edit I don't consider the question as all that bad.

Comment: Sure, it is a bit of a laundry list, and the last question is a bit strange, but in it's naive way even this seems like a genuine question. But it is also not unreasonably broad. Would it be asked now, I'd recommend to split it up, maybe. But this is not easy to fix now, and maybe not that important either. Maybe the  combination of question even can be seen as hinting at the level at which the questions is asked. To only ask "is zero a number" might be ill-posed or underdefined, but in context I think it works.

Comment: Then there is also a community-aspect. Somebody actually put some non-trivial effort into improving this question, and the result is not that bad.  If even this is not enough, at some point the line of argument that users should improve post  they care about loses credibility, which leads to less improvements.  @XanderHenderson

Comment: @quid I apologize---my original comment was poorly phrased, and likely not really related to this reopen request.  A better phrasing might have been "In cases where there are really good answers to questions of marginal merit, (1) don't those answers automatically get preserved even if the question is closed? and (2) can such answers be protected?  Since you seemed kind of ambivalent with respect to reopening (which I see now was an over-interpretation on my part), I was asking about an alternative.

Comment: In any event, thank you for the feedback.  I honestly do value it. :)

Comment: For the record, I stand by my thoughts from 2 years ago:  the question is not a good exemplar for the site.  It is too broad (it asks three distinct questions, each of which might merit a quality answer), but there are good answers which I think should be preserved.  I am still in favor of closing the question (to send the message that it isn't really up to snuff), but locking it so that it isn't (and cannot be) deleted.

Answer (score 10):

> **Reopened, Put on hold, deleted, undeleted, deleted, re-undeleted, re-deleted, undeleted again, deleted again, locked, unlocked and reopened**

Please consider reopening [What digits is the "number" $\infty$ composed of?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709657/what-digits-is-the-number-infinity-composed-of).  This question was closed as "not about mathematics".  Obviously, this question is based on some misconceptions of what infinity is, but they are perfectly natural misconceptions for a layman and that hardly makes the question "not about mathematics".  The question has a nice answer which clarifies the misconceptions and is a valuable addition to the site.

Comment: I agree. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I don't think having that question around helps us in building a useful math Wiki, [which is what the founder of the site had in mind](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/).

Comment: Questions like this have really interesting and revealing answers. I'm thinking about padic numbers and infinitely long strings of digits depending on the base, but I feel like I'm denied my reopen vote by the vigilantes who co-ordinate their fast deletion vote, so minimally many users have the power to reinstate it.

Comment: I don't think the question is particularly bad, and not worth deleting. It addresses some common, layman misconceptions, and I don't think that is such a bad thing. (Maths suffers from a poor understanding at all levels of society - let us do what we can to help!) Also, the question is 4 years old. I favour keeping open older questions rather than judging them by todays standards.

Comment: The question is currently undeleted but closed. The questioner seems aware that "infinity" might not actually be a number in the usual sense, but so far there's no answer explicitly saying how it differs from numbers.  I would like it reopened to allow someone to post one.

Comment: @timtfj: It is deleted again. Some discussion regarding the recent deletion can be found in the CRUDE chatroom.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I disagree that the question is without use. I think a plausible-yet-naïve-question like this one has a lot of utility to *resolve a misconception that others are probably going to have*.  I can't say I like this particular question, but I can say that I think it's dumb in this case to work so hard to delete it.  (It seems to me that a useful wiki would want mechanisms to resolve misconceptions, anyway.  Full disclosure: I don't really buy into math.se-as-a-wiki.)

Answer (score 8):

> **Closed**, **re-opened**

[Solve for $x^2 + 7x +1 = 3n(x^2 + x +1), n \in \Bbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184575/solve-for-x2-7x-1-3nx2-x-1-n-in-bbbz) 
My this question was put on hold as off-topic because it lacks context. It also gives a link to how I can add context. 
The link gave the following points

1. Include your work 
   My response - I answered that question which I asked. I got a few hints from the comments which helped me. Should I give a summary of my solution it the question?
2. Motivation for question-
   My response - I said in the details of the question that the original problem was a trigonometric equation which I solved but was stuck there.
3. Where did the problem come from? 
   My response- it came from a book which is suppose to help me in my College entrance exam. But in this context it is really irrelevant and rather obvious.
4. give your background
   My response- I did give my background. I am a high school student who is self studying for college entrance exam.
5. reference
   My response- None exist.

I am not critising the one(many) who put my question on hold because nobody  have to answer my question as this site is run by volunteers. I am just curious. How can I improve my question?

Answer (score 8):

> **Closed, re-opened**

Please consider reopening [What is wrong with this solution of find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168377/279515).

- This question is closed as a duplicate of this previous question by the same OP: [Find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3166878/279515) but the two questions are different. The closed question asks why a particular method of solution does not work, which is very different from the duplicate target.
- Perhaps relevant: the OP has also posted [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30110/279515) on Meta asking about the site policies on marking posts as duplicates (in general, and not pertaining to the reopening of this specific post).

Comment: Also, OP has indicated that he/she no longer cares about the question, and in particular is not seeking reopening.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, but the post itself belongs to the community and I feel it is worth reopening, hence the request.

Answer (score 7):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2873767/revisions)**

I edited the question [Variable in upper bound of sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2873767/16397) when it had 4 votes to close, and I also posted a rather detailed answer (which the OP accepted).  It got "put on hold as unclear what you're asking" even though I think it's now quite clear and on-topic. Can the question be re-opened?

Answer (score 7):

> **Reopened**

This meta question has been closed as a duplicate:

[Can we please STOP closing and deleting old posts with answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30163/10513)

However, it is *not* a duplicate. The [older question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28168/10513) is about deleting questions with answers, which is a more general question. (Indeed, it starts with the phrase "A few deays ago I posted an answer...") The newer question is about a special case, and which deserves a separate discussion. In particular, the newer question states [emphasis *not* mine!]:

> Recently...quite a few **old** questions with good answers are being closed and **deleted**...I do not see any merit for closing such old questions: who the heck do we really expect to come back and "provide additional context" for a question that was asked two or even six years ago?

Of course, you may believe that this question is *not* worthy of a separate discussion. That's fine, but I believe the correct way of expressing this opinion is the answer the question saying so, and linking back to the older question.

Comment: Well, it would help if the poster(s) of new meta discussions would take earlier ones into account more systematically. But, yeah, I'll reopen it. If people want to discuss again, that's fine to a point. .

Comment: @quid My point is that the word *again* is not relevant. Its an essentially new discussion, not covered in the older post. Do you not agree? (It would be nice to clarify the reopening reason first, for posterity's sake.)

Comment: Yes, I'll leave a comment. The issue with these things is that even if the question is technically different, the discussion is often not focused enough. I know that you noted that with the other answer there.

Comment: @quid Thanks. Incidentally, is it possible to delete the other answer, the one I commented on? (Or does that take moderation too far?! I flagged it as "not an answer" a wee while ago.)

Comment: Well, depends who you ask. I prefer not to delete it, but you could request it in aa comment.

Answer (score 6):

**Reopened**

---

The question [A Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870349/a-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic) was rightfully quickly closed as unclear, but the asker has since edited to clarify what they meant and what specific difficulty they had adapting the standard proofs to get what they want.  It seems to me to be a perfectly reasonable question which is mostly clear (though a constraint like "not using integers or rational numbers" is inevitably going to be a little slippery).

Answer (score 6):

> **Reopened**

I would like to see the question "[What is $\nabla X$ in Riemannian geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3125972/26369)" re-opened. (I see from [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3125972/timeline) that the reopen queue has finished. In hindsight, I should have edited the title when I made the reopen vote.)

It appears it was marked as a duplicate of [Gradient of a vector field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156880/26369), seemingly because the short version of the question (and the old title, "What is $\nabla X$?") is very similar. But I would say that the rest of the question and the context (including tags) make it a question that necessitates an answer that would be inappropriate on the other question. "Gradient of a vector field?" has a tag and context of multivariable calculus, not Riemannian geometry.

Since "What is $\nabla X$ in Riemannian geometry?" doesn't yet have an accepted answer, I would like it re-opened so others can contribute.

Answer (score 6):

**Reopened**

The OP added an attempt to [Determine the number of ordered triple $(x, y, z)$ of integer numbers (negatives and positives) satisfying $|x| + |y| + |z| \le 6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157381) in a comment to an answer while there was still only one close vote. I have moved that attempt to the question. I think that the question now meets the criteria for context.

Comment: Doesn't the question now contain a complete solution to the problem? which makes it a pretty peculiar question?

Comment: It gives context, which was why the question was closed. It doesn't really matter to me since I've already answered the question. Questions are not closed when the OP answers them, so I thought this one shouln't be closed for lack of context. Other answers might provide different insights.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310980/good-book-recommendations-on-trigonometry/2920602#2920602) from 7 months ago was apparently deleted by Community as spam or offensive yesterday. I don't see how it could be offensive, and such an answer to a question tagged [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) is surely not spam. Why would someone flag this answer?

And in any case, it's certainly not a great example for a [review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191208)...

Comment: I failed a [similar review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191114) today...

Comment: Same answerer, posted the day after, deleted more or less at the same time with a link to the same site and in both cases the post is identical to the linked review... It's weirder than I thought.

Comment: I think only moderators can undelete a post deleted by Community, right? (it's even locked in this case)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20431/what-happens-with-the-deleted-questions/20433#20433) and the linked Meta answer, this is indeed the case for posts deleted *as spam* (in fact they are locked) but not the others.

Comment: Are spam flags handled by Community?

Comment: [Again?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191553) (notice the answerer's account has been deleted, which still exists yesterday)

Comment: There is also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2915781/revisions), though I don't know if it has been used as an audit. The same user also has a deleted answer on MO apparently, though I don't have the rep to see it. I understand the deletions a bit more now...

Comment: I've added a post about these audits in [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits/30150#30150).

Answer (score 6):

> **Undeleted, reopened, closed, reopened**

[Minimum Elementary row/column transformations to find Inverse of given Matric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147807/minimum-elementary-row-column-transformations-to-find-inverse-of-given-matric)

This question was definitely not up to site standards, but it had a couple of really cool answers, one that I had awarded a bounty to. I think it's worth undeleting for the answers alone.

Comment: If the question is "definitely not up to site standards," then it really shouldn't be on the site. If you could edit it to bring its quality up, then that would be nice... but as it stands, I really oppose the undeletion or reopening of this.

Comment: @T.Bongers That's why it probably should be closed, so it can be improved by the asker. I could edit it, but I don't want to hijack the asker's question any more than I have. I think it should not be deleted because it has illicited some interesting, unduplicated mathematical content that is, IMHO, worthy of the bounty awarded.

Comment: The asker had 28 days to improve the question before its closure, and another 5 before its deletion - they chose not to. Do you expect that to change if the question is undeleted?

Comment: @T.Bongers no obviously no, Theo is not expecting the question to be improved but to show to the rest of the community the couple of really cool answers the 'bad' question has.

Comment: @T.Bongers I don't, no. I don't have any reasonable expectation the question to ever be re-opened. But in the interest of generating and collecting interesting mathematical content, I think it's worth keeping the question around. Are you saying I should edit it, replacing the asker's wording with my own, because the asker has abandoned it?

Comment: My opinion, Theo, is that if you can edit the question to bring it to where it can be undeleted, reopened, and stay open, then more power to you.

Comment: Generally, it's not clear that the asker abandoned it. Anyway what I'd propose is that yes you edit it to something more readily comprehensible and detailed. I don't think there is a need to overdo this. For example, spell out the method the asker refers to, and rewrite the question so that no words are missing. Leave a friendly comment to OP saying that you found the question interesting and therefor fleshed it out a bit. If there is some problem with this approach, you can always ask your own version of the  question and then ask for a merge, which would transfer the answers.

Comment: @quid I might do the latter. I hijacked the asker's question to have a subtly different focus anyway. Once I've asked it, do I just flag a moderator's attention and request a merge?

Comment: Yes, a flag for mods is the way to go. However it'd be good to wait until the discussion has settled as once we merged it's near impossible to go back.

Answer (score 6):

> **Undeleted**

Requesting an undelete for this question. I'm having trouble seeing why the question was deleted, and the asker did so after I provided an answer, which seems like a possible abuse of the Q-A system. The question itself was well-written and motivated, with clear effort put in, and received three upvotes. Further, I didn't come across any duplicate questions in math.se, though I may have overlooked them.

[Proposition 5.4.4. in Tao](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258124/proposition-5-4-4-in-tao)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492862/proof-of-the-trichotomy-of-real-numbers-using-cauchy-sequences) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841268/prove-that-for-all-x-in-bbb-r-precisely-one-of-the-statements-x0-x-0-o) might be (partial) duplicates, but that doesn't warrant a deletion. Voted to undelete.

Answer (score 6):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3625877/revisions)

[How many cycles are there in graph with $n$ nodes, where each node is adjacent to the next and all nodes are adjacent to a node in the middle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3625877)

The OP asked a question and made a genuine attempt to answer the question and explained their thought process. I wrote a detailed answer to help correct their mistake and demonstrate the pattern that leads to the final answer. The OP thanked me in a comment and then deleted the question. I feel that there is no reason this question should be deleted, since the question quality and answer quality are at the appropriate level. Can this be undeleted?

Comment: Usually in this thread only the *change of state* is included (such as undeleted, reopened - and maybe later deleted again, reclosed, etc.) - and not the state in which the post was at the time of the request.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the clarification, sorry about that

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened, closed, reopened**

---

I just came across this question: [Derivative of Square Root Visual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824922/derivative-of-square-root-visual) after [failing a reopen review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1041429) and I'm wondering why it's still closed: *unclear what you're asking*. I agree that the MathJax formatting isn't the best, but it is still readable.

The OP has actually shown what they've tried, and what they didn't get, so the reason for closure is beyond my understanding. I thus request to reopen the question.

---

I have now edited the question to make it look neater.

Comment: Well it is definitely unclear what they are asking... One has to take roughly 10 mins  to watch the youtube videos to see what they are trying to say (watching parts of 2:25 and 12:48 don't quite work, at least to me).

Comment: @JohnMa I think they meant 3:25, as it looks much more relevant?

Comment: They start the $x^2$ example at 2:35, and then to power rule (up to 10:30). Then they switch to $1/x$ (it seems this is the more relevant one).

Comment: Thanks for the update @Brahadeesh. It's now reopened.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened, then closed as off topic, deleted**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903382) (does the existence of an lcm in a commutative ring imply the existence of the gcd of the two elements) was closed as a duplicate, pointing to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449521) (which shows *inter alia* that the existence of an lcm in a domain implies the existence of a gcd). In fact, I had done the same thing yesterday.

However, this is not a real duplicate. The question here is about rings, whereas the alleged duplicate is about domains. The proof there does not easily translate: for example, the first step of the proof in the question pointed to is to take $m=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, let $s$ be such that $ms=ab$, write $m=ar$ and $m=bt$, and then claim that $s=\gcd(a,b)$. The first step is to show $s$ divides $a$, which it does by showing that $(ab/m)*(m/b)=a$. This is equivalent to saying that $st=a$; but I do not see how to conclude this in a ring (in a domain, multiplying through by $b$ and then cancelling will do it, but how do you do it here?).

As I had already closed it, and then re-opened, I can no longer vote to re-open on the page.

Comment: Were it me, I would have voted to close the question for lack of context.  There is zero context.  Where did the question come from?  What is the background of the asker?  Why should anyone care about that question.  It really isn't a very good question, and it probably should be closed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: That's valid, but the problem right now is that it points to a question claiming that it provides an answer when it does not.

Answer (score 5):

> **Closed, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened**

This is being deleted repeatedly by the same people even though it has a great answer. There are several votes to reopen. I think it should be reopened because of the answer.

[Cevians $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are concurrent, as are cevians $DP$, $EQ$, $FR$; show that $AP$, $BQ$, $CR$ are concurrent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038892/cevians-ad-be-cf-are-concurrent-as-are-cevians-dp-eq-fr-show-t)

Comment: By my standards the Question has sufficient context in respect of the OP's remark (in the original body of the Question) that we should try to apply Ceva's Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

This question I asked was closed for lacking context. After context was added, the hold was never lifted, and eventually was closed.

[$X,Y$ not homeomorphic if $X\backslash x$ is disconnected for all $x\in X$ but $Y\backslash y$ is connected for some $y\in Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175408/x-y-not-homeomorphic-if-x-backslash-x-is-disconnected-for-all-x-in-x-but)

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted, and closed as off-topic, re-deleted, undeleted (after editing)**

Please consider undeleting the following post:
[What is the area of the shaded region.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3187298/9464)

Considering the high quality of several answers to the question, I do not think we should delete the post.

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted, redeleted，re-undeleted and locked (but for how long?)**

[About the Continuum Hypothesis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124651/about-the-continuum-hypothesis) asks a reasonable question that has been answered many times before. It was properly closed as a duplicate.

But it was then deleted, even though it had *six* upvoted answers with scores from 3 to 13.  I think this was unnecessary and counterproductive.

I'd like to see it undeleted.

Comment: "I think this was unnecessary and counterproductive." I don't see why  it was counterproductive. Could you please elaborate? What I see is that there is quite questionable content in the question-post and the thread does not add anything that is not on the site elsewhere. Thus it is good that it is deleted.

Comment: @quid is it that because are we running out of space in the site?  :P

Comment: @Isa in a sense of memory, of course not, and deletion does not change anything. In the sense of giving space to good content over not so good one, in a way yes. We should get rid of not so good stuff so that better stuff gets more visibility. For the specific questions, there are just odd things in the question: "OK found out about Aleph numbers - so it isn't based on reality, but on some imaginary stuff. That's fine by me, my reality says integers < rational < real, but to each their own ..." Why should we disseminate this?

Comment: @quid: Exactly, and that's not the only comment of this cranky sort by the asker, slashmais, who for example commented on hdhondt's answer saying "I think however that there is a major flaw in this reasoning and that I can demonstrate why the flaw occurs as well as how to resolve it, but it would be inappropriate for this site (elicit a discussion) - I would appreciate if you (or anyone else) can point me to a forum meant for such discussion.".

Comment: I think the productive way forward is for any answerer, who thinks that his/her answer hasn't been expressed clearly enough on the (very excellent) earlier question by Steve314, to add an answer to that thread instead.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer of mdp to the deleted question is so pedagogically excellent - better than any answer I've read so far on the other duplicates - that I can't understand the argument that its removal is good for the site.  Yes, mdp (if she/he sees this) could cut-and past her/his answer to one of the other questions, but it would lose all its up votes, and therefore its visibility.  Future readers would therefore be less likely to benefit from it.

Answer (score 5):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3543155/timeline), Reopened.

Please consider undeleting and reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543155/formula-for-angle-between-faces-based-on-angles-of-corners) which is a natural, well-written question on solid geometry that received a good answer.  It's not clear to me why anyone thought it needed to be closed, let alone deleted.

Comment: So this question was closed and then deleted? Why can't I see the history of the events? All I see is the question asked by Matthew without _edits_ at all.

Comment: @user486983 Since that post was never edited there doesn't appear a similar thing to click on, like "edited Feb 30 at 12:12", but you can see it by clicking on that clock bellow the upvote/downvote button, or alternatively here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3543155/revisions (replace timeline with revisions to arrive to this link).

Comment: It's quite sad that no one who voted to delete/close bothered to give OP lend op a hand after  it was clearly shown the desire to cooperate in the comments and decided it's better to silently get rid of that post. That message "needs details or clarity" is also quite handwavy(I might guess that those who voted to close, wanted to see more context and not that they considered it unclear, but well it's quite too late now).

Comment: @Zacky Thanks. I've always thought that the closed, deleted, etc. counted also as  _edits_ on the question, but it turns out nop

Answer (score 5):

**Reopened**

The question [Two definitions of tensor product: when are they equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71064/two-definitions-of-tensor-product-when-are-they-equivalent) was closed as a duplicate of [understanding the "tensor product of vector spaces"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51155/understanding-of-the-tensor-product-of-vector-spaces/51156#comment7460372_51156).  While both questions ask for a comparison of the standard quotient-of-free-vector-space definition with some alternative definition, the alternative definitions in the two questions are not the same.  Moreover, the two questions need different answers: the answer to the first is that, as suspected by the OP, the two definitions are equivalent only in the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces, while the answer to the second is that the two definitions are equivalent, even, it happens, in the infinite-dimensional case.  (The main concern of the second question, however, is the "how" of equivalence rather than the fact of equivalence).

Prior to being closed, the first question had received a nice answer, but the poster, fearing the question might be deleted, moved the answer to the second question, where it reads as a bit of a *non sequitur*, its purpose possibly mysterious to some readers.  I'm hoping that if the question gets reopened, the answerer (who recently added a disclaimer to the post) might feel encouraged to move the answer back to the post for which it was intended.

The first question is a pretty fundamental question about the different ways tensor products are defined in various strands of the mathematics literature, and seems to me like a question we ought to have on the site along with some good answers.  The second question is concerned with clearing up some misunderstandings about Timothy Gowers' article, [*How to lose your fear of tensor products*](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html), and also seems a valuable question.  But clearing up misunderstandings is better done by not muddying the waters with answers to a distinct question that happens to be just similar enough to make things confusing.

Comment: Reopened, but the "Possible duplicate" banner is still there. It doesn't disappear automatically? Someone can/should edit it out?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the banner out. It seems to be a known bug, occurring when reopening questions that were closed as duplicate when the UI was very different: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193951/313042

Comment: @Brahadeesh so they've known about it since 2013, and not fixed it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah :P There are a lot of bugs that are not feasible for the devs to spend time on, apparently. That's what I gather from browsing Meta SE.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

[Annuity immediate and present value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783424/annuity-immediate-and-present-value/)

I disagree with the reason for closure.  There is clear context in the form of a nearly complete (but ultimately incorrect) attempt to answer the question.  The only possible reason I can think of that it might have been flagged for closure is that those who voted to close are unaware of the terminology used in financial and actuarial mathematics.  But this is not a valid reason for closure, because a lack of familiarity with the subject material does not mean it requires explanation.  A student who does not know calculus should not expect to see a question about integration to explain what an integral is.

Answer (score 4):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2935555)

As per [quid's advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25522/5676), I would like to request that [Number of real roots of an iterated quadratic: $x^2-3/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2935555) be undeleted. The question was self-deleted within a few minutes of my posting an answer which claimed that the conjecture of the question was false, so the reason for the deletion appears to be embarrassment. However, the question itself was an interesting one, as evidenced by more than 10 upvotes and 7 stars.

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened**

Please reopen this [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163100/describe-the-natural-density-of-p-prime-and-non-prime-which-divides-natural). One user @lulu stated the question was clear but it is still closed.

If the question is unclear, state why?

Answer (score 4):

> **Reopened**

I would like to see this question opened:

[Intersection of a nested sequence of subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3191266/10513)

The OP has provided all the context requested in the comments. Also, it is an interesting and relatively hard question.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeleted, locked by a moderator, deleted by a moderator.**

Please consider undeleting this post: [Does the law of cosines contradict Pythagoras's theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659982/9464)

It has been recently [mentioned by Martin Sleziak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52627357#52627357) in the CRUDE chat room and a user by [GENTLE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52627183#52627183).

As Henning Makholm's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659982/does-the-law-of-cosines-contradict-pythagorass-theorem#comment5499218_2659982) under the deleted post mentioned, "... the asker is wrong, but he's presenting his wrongness clearly in a way that makes it possible to pinpoint how he's wrong, and he's asking about what he's missing. That's exactly what asking questions is for!"

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate. Do any of the answers contribute anything that's not in the answers at the duplicated question? (Not a rhetorical question – I'm just not interested enough to check for myself.) If there's nothing here that isn't already elsewhere, why undelete?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The closure as a duplicate could be fine, even if the other question is really poor as content. But the deletion is really not motivated for a question with more than 8k views and many upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> **Undeleted, Redeleted,undeleted, Reopened**

This interesting question on Euler's constant  was closed then deleted:

[Approximating Euler's constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550990/515527)

Please vote to reopen and to undelete. The question got two wonderful answers by @robjohn and @Gary.Now it's completely hidden. And some members can't benefit from the nice answers posted there.

**Edit1:**
Thanks a lot for you help. The question is now undeleted and accessible to all. But we still need two votes to reopen the question.

Comment: Even though I think the post is worth keeping undeleted as it contains useful content,  I think it's rightfully closed as it lacks context and I don't understand why you want it reopened (in the actual state).

Comment: @Zacky these questions get very nice answers that's why I think it should be left open. it's because it was open that RobJohn and Gary could answer the question.  But my first goal was  to undelete the question so it remains accessible to member with low reputation.

Comment: This chatroom, [GENTLE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle), might also fit well for your goal in the future too.

Comment: @Zacky Thanks a loot. Will look there.

Comment: A +10 answer and a +13 answer, deleted. Vandals. @LostInSpace I hope you can find your way back here, to vote to undelete.

Comment: It was a nice question with great answers. @GerryMyerson . it's undeleted Gerry

Comment: @GerryMyersonYes thank you a vote for undeleting was missing yesterday so I voted and the question is now reopened. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened, Closed again, Deleted.**

A first-time poster  asked about [27 and 37 as repeating decimals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697619/27-and-37-as-repeating-decimals). I found the question perfectly clear and on-topic and wrote an answer.

None of the five people who voted to close it as needing “details or clarity” bothered to leave a comment to say what they thought was unclear.

Comment: I'd like to add that I think it's shameful that a first-time poster was treated with such discourtesy.

Comment: I did not remark  that  close votes must be accompanied by comments.

Comment: The phenomenon is certainly an interesting one to ask for an explanation of...but the asker didn't ask for an explanation.  They just asked for a "name for this", and it is quite arguably unclear what they mean by that.  There is definitely a good question to be had here (and which you answered), but it's not clear to me that it was asked.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened, then closed as duplicate.**

It would be useful if [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509823/) can be reopened, so that it can be closed as a duplicate (see comments to post for more details).

Comment: I am not sure there is much benefit in re-opening questions just to re-close them with alternative close reasons. This particular post really should be expanded significantly, if it is to be saved.  Re-opening and re-closing will still probably lead to deletion. In particular, because it is a self-answered post, we can expect much higher standards than a post where the OP genuinely has a question.

Answer (score 3):

**Undeleted, then deleted again, then undeleted again, then reopened, then closed again, then reopened again**

Please undelete [Compare $\arcsin (1)$ and $\tan (1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877251/290189) because OP has made an observation $\sin(\tan1)\leq1$ in order to compare the two quantities in the question title.  This question has

- 4 net upvotes;
- 3 $\star$;
- 2 (ex)-moderators' answers; and
- 1 Undelete vote remaining to save this question.

Answer (score 3):

> **Merged**

Please Consider undeleting the following question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203711/what-are-the-steps-to-finding-int-01-frac-ln1-x-lnxx-dx

Of course, this one is a strict duplicate of the one for it was closed. However, regarding the fact that the answers to this question at all are quite spread I would like to draw attention to my own answer given here *collecting* some of the possible ways to evaluate this integral within one post.

Comment: Would it make sense to merge the thread with the duplicate target?

Comment: @quid That might a better way than undeleting the question, indeed. I'm ashamed to ask, but what exactly does it mean to *merge* a thread with another one?

Comment: It means that the answers will be moved to the other thread (and deleted on the original one). The Q can be preserved (like a duplicate) or not.

Comment: @quid That sounds pretty good. Shall I do this, at least with my own answer, by myself or do I have to request for this somewhere?

Comment: That's something only moderators can do. (Of course you could simply repost your answer on the dupe too, but that would not be merge.) I'll just go ahead and do it now.

Comment: @quid Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

New user Christophe has made edits which considerably improve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239552/find-limit-of-sequence-defined-by-sum-of-previous-terms-and-harmonics). Currently, it needs one more reopen vote to remove the hold. Please consider voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2406710/revisions)**, **Reopened**, **Reclosed as a duplicate.**

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2406710/11619) sufficiently non-trivial.

> Given that the series of positive numbers $\sum_n a_n$ converges, can we say anything about the convergence of $\sum_n a_n^{(n-1)/n}$?

So, as a salvage effort I added some preliminary thoughts to it. Do check whether it now is good enough to be undeleted and/or reopened?

I'm not saying it would now be a great question. This is also a way of repeating my old maxim that the interested parties should always try and edit closed/deleted questions they find interesting into shape, and only *after* that ask others to reconsider.

Caveat: <strike>I didn't feel the need to check for duplicates. So it is possible that it should later be closed and redeleted as a dupe.</strike>
Not entirely unexpectedly Martin Sleziak found no less than three near duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867911/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2891237/11619) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949143/11619).

Comment: I'm happy with the current status (closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3426993/25554) asks about the existence of a series $f_i$ of complex functions with several properties: there should exist $x_0$ such that $f_i(x_0) = i$; the sum of the series should converge on some open region to a function $f$;  the analytic continuation of $f$ should exist at $x_0$.

It has attracted several answers, some quite detailed, but has been closed as being “not about mathematics”.

Answer (score 3):

> **Undeleted.**

Please consider undeleting this post: [Help with proof of set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3527530/462).

The question asks for clarification of some details in a previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3474011/462) of mine. (In a perhaps poorly phrased manner, saying that it seemed there was an error and so the answer was meaningless.)

I took the time to ask in comments for the poster to clarify what precisely was confusing. Then I posted an answer with some additional details.

The poster proceeded to delete all their comments and the question, which I think is poor manners. The question is not terrible, and it may be useful to others.

Comment: "Reopened"? Shouldn't that be "Undeleted"?

Comment: Yes it should. 

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

Consider this question: [Find the height of a bar, given the lengths of shadows cast by it and another bar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471016/find-the-height-of-a-bar-given-the-lengths-of-shadows-cast-by-it-and-another-ba)

It is closed as a duplicate of a question that is closed with the missing context reason, with no attempt and only one answer. The question I linked has an attempt and the question and many answers are highly upvoted, yet people are voting to delete it, presumably because it's a duplicate. It will require 10 delete votes.

I think we should reopen this question and close the other question as a duplicate of this one. Afterwards, if people are really so thirsty for deletion, they can delete that one.

Answer (score 3):

> [**Undeleted, Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3335454/revisions)

Please undelete the following:
[How many ways can I go from 1 to 10 in the following diagram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335454/how-many-ways-can-i-go-from-1-to-10-in-the-following-diagram)

This question has an answer (mine) with more than $50$ votes. The question should stay closed, as it did not follow MSE guidelines, but the highly voted answer is very good.

The question now has more context and pictures.

Comment: "How many undelete votes does this question have?" (added in your recent edit). If I count correctly, it took five users to deleted the question, so five votes to undelete should be necessary too. This is in accordance with the description in the FAQ, you have 5+51=56 (questions + top-voted answer), ratio 20:1 gives two additional votes.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks!

Comment: @Culver I think it would be a good idea to edit the question to improve it yourself, so that it doesn't get deleted again. You could just add something to the question to say why it's interesting. The question is the best part of a year old, so we can safely assume that the OP isn't going to improve it themselves...

Comment: (Also, for questions like this it makes more sense for the question to contain an explanation of why we should care about it, rather than containing some half-hearted attempted at a solution. I mean, you want this to be kept open for posterity, right? But noone in the future is going to care about the OPs "attempt"!)

Answer (score 3):

> [**Reopened, Deleted by spam flag, Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3787228/revisions)

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787228/how-to-show-a-given-function-satisfies-the-cauchy-riemann-equation-at-a-point-b)
which is asked by a newbie which obviously did not know how to ask a good question. After the closure they had edited to include their [efforts](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3787228/2), and I have fixed the formatting.

The reopening review task was [completed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1435966) just a while ago.

Comment: Somehow the question got flagged as spam.

Comment: I thought it's automatic deleted (by the script [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)) @MattSamuel

Comment: The history does say it was deleted by RemoveDeadQuestions, however if you look at the text of the post it says it was marked as spam as well.

Comment: I can't see that @MattSamuel (I have <10k rep, so I guess I might see less information).

Comment: The flag is for "spam or rude/abusive" content, but here the only rudeness is the terse initial phrasing in the imperative "solve it".  I scarcely think this is abusive.  If the subsequent edits are taken into account, the Question is suitable in my opinion, so I'm voting to undelete.

Comment: Without more upvotes it will just be deleted again. It needs at least a score of $0$ to make it through tonight.

Comment: Maybe someone could post an answer, as the question is currently open and not deleted.

Comment: Still waiting for someone to post an answer, also waiting for OP to correct the typo I pointed out (if it is, in fact, a typo).

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

Please, consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906003/its-confusing-to-calculate-euler-characteristic-of-this-surface).

The question was somewhat unclear when first asked, but was pinpointed down in comments. I also edited it providing a figure which helps to readily understand the situation.

The context provided by OP (by means of the "planified" picture) makes *the source of confusion* clear, and now that the *problem itself* is also clear, I think it fits the site well.

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

I request a reopen of [Are the corner hypercubera polytopes self-dual?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922113/are-the-corner-hypercubera-polytopes-self-dual). The question provides a v-definition of an infinite family of polytopes, and asks whether each member of this family is self-dual. (I don't see anything unclear about this question.) Other than being closed for being unclear, I haven't received feedback on this question.

I believe this Q&A provides the first known example of an infinite family of self-dual polytopes that is not a set of k-fold pyramids over a self-dual polytope.

Comment: The post reads as a blog post, not a question. It needs to be **vastly** more concise, and I frankly don't think that MSE is a good site to ask questions like this; you would do better just talking to someone in the field. You got a bit of feedback in your [last meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29113/tag-request-sierpinski-triangle).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I agree that a tag pertaining to just a question or two need not exist. As to the question, 1/3 of it is motivation, which I understand to be a requirement of MSE (I would just as soon leave it out). The answer is long because, while conceptually simple, the proof has a lot of tedious parts to it.

Comment: I've made my question more concise-it's now about 1160 characters & fits on my small Mac screen. My answer is about 18,000 characters. To analyze why it's so long, I counted the characters in eight distinct parts of the answer. Some parts are long because the thing to be proved requires a lot of words (wishing there was an elegant proof doesn't make it so).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question was closed, not the answer. The Q&A is good because it sets forth the first example (ever in the history of mankind) of an infinite family of self-dual geometric polytopes (one for each dimension d $\ge$ 3) which aren't a set of k-fold pyramids over a self-dual polytope.

Comment: I've improved my answer by adding headings, allowing the reader to more easily navigate or skim the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Undeleted.**

I nominate [Is the numerical range of Identity operator convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2985770/290189) for undeletion because the question asker self-deleted her question shortly after receiving an answer from a high-rep user.  That's an abuse of the system.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened.**

This recent Question [asks about a variant of the Secretary Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013115/choosing-the-best-or-second-best-secretary) which as far as I can tell has not been previously answered here.

I mistakenly proposed to close as a duplicate of the classic Secretary Problem, but this variant treats as equally successful the choice of either the best or the second-best candidate.  Please consider adding your **vote to reopen** to mine.

[NB: I edited the title of the post to clarify that this is not identical to the earlier Question, and I discuss in the comments there what little Math.SE discussion there had been on this variant (without supplying its literature references).]

Comment: I've edited the question to refine the formatting and grammar a bit, and to use more gender neutral language.  I don't think that the question is all that great (it is a problem statement question with a largely nonsensical "attempt"), but I agree that it isn't a duplicate question, and it is somewhat better than much of the stuff that gets posted.  In any event, the question is now open again.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted**

I nominate [Is the Balazard-Saias-Yor integral non-positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020198/is-the-balazard-saias-yor-integral-non-positive) for un-deletion and re-opening.  Being self-deleted by a deleted user, it has a score of +1 and two stars.  The topic adds value to the site and the question asker has put effort in the post.

Currently, only one undelete vote is needed to undelete this question.  I hope the two users who starred this question can see their favorite question re-opened.

Comment: It should be noted that "stars" do not necessarily indicate that a user finds the question useful or up to the standards of the site.  Many users use stars to keep track of questions with which they have interacted, and desire to return to at some point.  For example, I sometimes star questions which lack context or otherwise fail to meet the standards of this site.  After downvoting, leaving a comment, and/or voting to close, I will star the post so that I can return to it a few days later to see if it has been improved.  If it has, I'll retract my downvote and/or close vote.

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the case here; I just want to point out that "stars" should not be taken as a sign of quality vis-a-vis undeletion votes.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thx for comments.  Noted.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted and merged with duplicate**

I would like to see the question "[Finding sum to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078955/finding-sum-to-infinity)" undeleted. The OP says that they "tried using the Taylor series for $e^x$ but couldn’t figure out how to manipulate it to get the above expression", which seems reasonable. Moreover:

1. The question is a duplicate and is closed as such. It is not standard practice to delete duplicates (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29191/should-duplicate-questions-be-deleted)).
2. The question itself is on +5 (+6/-1), and one of the answers is on +12.

Comment: I don't get the argument. What is the value of keeping that question on the site?

Comment: I didn't realiize that "it is standard practice to not delete duplicates." Cite?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I also had entertained to comment on that. What  arguably is true is that "it is not standard practice to delete duplicates", which of course is not quite the same.

Comment: @Gerry What I meant was "a question should not be deleted simply because it is a duplicate" (so I've edited the post to quid's sentence). This was discussed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29191/should-duplicate-questions-be-deleted).

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted and reopened**

Please consider reopening the following question:

[Evaluation of definite integrals with exponential integrand in Fourier sine transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3166068/9464)

OP reduces the problem of finding Fourier sine transform to something that he/she does not know how to proceed further, which can be clearly justified as an attempt. I don't think we should close such post.

Comment: You ask to *reopen*, but you write that we shouldn't *delete*. As you know, closing/reopening and deleting/undeleting are two different things. Presumably, you would like both to undelete and to reopen. May I suggest you edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Sure. Edited. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @Jack I noticed that after the comment by Gerry you edited the question to only request reopening, but I find this slightly confusing. Shouldn't the post request undeletion instead, since the question is currently deleted?

Answer (score 2):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3229201/revisions)**

I nominate [Factorising the ideal $(14)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-10})$ into a product of prime ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229201/290189) for undeletion since the question asker has self-deleted his/her own question after receiving an answer.  This is unfair the answerer who spent time and effort writing the answer, which deserves evaluation from the community.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened, closed again as duplicate**

I nominate reopening [Non-negative integer solution for $ax + by = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191905/non-negative-integer-solution-for-ax-by-c). The OP updated the question with what I consider to be sufficient context after the first close vote, but before the final one. As I thought the updated text then made it an appropriate question, I provided an answer. After I discovered it was closed, I flagged it for reopening, but this was declined. FYI, the full timeline is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3191905/timeline). Please check this question to see if it should be reopened. Thanks.

Update: As explained in the comments, the question is really a duplicate. It's now closed again for what I consider an appropriate reason, i.e., as a duplicate.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490602/find-largest-k-such-that-the-diophantine-equation-axby-k-does-not-have-nonn and probably several others. If it's reopened, it should immediately be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I appreciate your feedback. Since it's a duplicate, I don't have any problem with closing it as such (if it's first reopened), and will even vote to do so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just gave the last vote to reopen the question. To follow through on what I stated above, I then tried to vote to close as a duplicate. However, because I gave a vote to close on April 18 and then retracted it (due to the OP giving more context so I thought it shouldn't close), the system won't let me vote to close it again, even though it's gone through a close/reopen cycle. As such, perhaps you may wish to start the process of closing it now as a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3027289/revisions)

Please consider reopening [Does non-uniqueness of solution to 1st order ODE implies the existence of infinitely many solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027289/does-non-uniqueness-of-solution-to-1st-order-ode-implies-the-existence-of-infini).

This is an interesting question about a not so famous result in ODE. The answers points to the correct reference. I've edited the question to include more context.

Comment: I agree it's an interesting question, and the updated text now has enough context, so I initiated reopening it.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, if you care, please consider also editing the answer there (to rollback to [edit 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3027303/1)). Now that the post is reopened, there is no need for that comment. I tried to edit myself, but the suggested edit [got rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1216858)

Comment: I agree the comment there regarding it being closed is no longer pertinent, so I did rollback of the edit.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted, reopened**

Please consider undeleting the post:

[Reference Request: Proof of H. Steinhaus' Lattice-Point Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2182209/9464), created on **Mar 11 '17**.

This question has two *good* answers.

Comment: Why don't you people leave these old questions alone? They're really not doing anyone any harm by being left on the site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "They're really not doing anyone any harm by being left on the site. " Got debunked numerous times. It's almost hard to believe that you just keep repeating it. To reiterate, not only does precedent get invoked in discussion, users also tend to go by the question they see when deciding how to ask. Of course one can consider this as not enough reason to delete them, but to simply claim  "not doing anyone any harm" is just false.

Comment: On the post generally, at least one might have restored the earlier more complete version. The current version is completely unclear as **question,** there is arguably more than one result that could be meant.

Comment: And one more thing @GerryMyerson to refer to a question from 2017 under "these old questions" is rather odd. Discussions about quality of questions were well advanced by then.

Comment: OK, @quid, I've rolled back to a more complete version.

Answer (score 2):

**Undeleted (and edited the duplicate target)**

---

Please undelete this post:

[Three coins are tossed. If one of them shows a tails, what is the probability that all three coins show tails?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889845/9464)

This question was marked as a duplicate to another question (created 2014) that was closed and deleted (2018).

Comment: It seems it took 9 votes to delete this question. I suppose that's because it had 30 upvotes? Anyway, currently it has 7 undelete votes. Does it need 9 to undelete?

Answer (score 2):

I nominate to undelete [*Bijection from a Variety to Itself, Necessarily an Isomorphism?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300261/bijection-from-a-variety-to-itself-necessarily-an-isomorphism). This question has been deleted by a moderator, so I guess it can only be undeleted by a moderator, too?

The question is interesting and has no apparent issues, as far as I can tell. It is well-formatted and well-formulated. It is no mere problem statement and precisely answerable.

The question has been stated yesterday and when I came back today to see if it got any answers, it was gone.

I honestly can’t tell why it should have been deleted. Although it seems that the questioner has been deleted, so maybe that has something to do with it? (If Asaf Karagila is reading this, would you care to explain your deletion?)

Comment: "If Asaf Karagila is reading this...." Never fear, Asaf is *always* reading this. It is odd that he deleted the post at 5:25:59, then undeleted it three seconds later, then redeleted it four seconds after that.

Comment: While we [the moderators] debate the whole thing, you can *usually* assume that if a moderator deleted a question then there is something *deeper* going on and some information that you might not be privy to.

Comment: (Even more so if you notice that the OP has become an ex-account, by the way.)

Comment: The user who posted the question has also been deleted, which I'm guessing is related to why the question was deleted.  Nevertheless I'm disappointed by the deletion of the question--regardless of what was going on with the asker, it is an interesting and nontrivial question.

Comment: @Eric: I will just comment that we have seen before that holding the quality of a question as a sacred candle which nothing else should extinguish is *not* a good standard for a functioning community.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In case you decide to leave the question deleted, please let me know, so I can consider to pose it myself instead. It would also be interesting to hear the reasons if you can disclose that. (Man, this starts to sound like some serious FBI shit or something.)

Answer (score 2):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3322249/revisions)

[Prove: there exists 3 sets: $A, B, C \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that: $A\cap B\cap C =\emptyset$ and $|A|=|B|=|C|=\aleph_0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322249/prove-there-exists-3-sets-a-b-c-subseteq-mathbbn-such-that-a-cap-b-c)

Please consider reopening my question as I've edited it in order to explain the full context of it.

Comment: The *current* status is only to be added *after* a change occurred.  In any case it should always be the *current* status of the post **not** the requested action.

Comment: I understand. thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3371720/revisions)

Please consider reopening [Minimal surfaces under conformal parametrizations - proof verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371720/minimal-surfaces-under-conformal-parametrizations-proof-verification)

It appears to have been closed after the user vandalised their question (rolling back the question would seem like the better approach, which I've done) and appears to have plenty of context and be a reasonable question asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

Could we please reopen: [How might I define a parabola in vertex form, such that…](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389403/how-might-i-define-a-parabola-in-vertex-form-such-that)

The OP has made an effort to improve their question. They have clarified the question by including the vertex form of a parabola for future reference, and have also added MathJax to the question. I have also cleaned up the tags to better reflect the question ('linear-algebra' was not appropriate).

The question is perfectly clear, and the OP has given the background to their own question which makes it perfectly answerable.

Comment: I have voted to reopen, but I note that the question already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Undeleted**

The following answer was deleted:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409573/10513

and I believe it should be undeleted.

The question is rather old (2013). The context of the question is that they are reading a research article which states a result, and the question is asking for a proof of this. Each of the other answers gives a citation rather than a proof. This specific answer is the same (citation, no proof), but the citation given is a modern, standard text and it makes sense for this book to be mentioned in some answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3454560/revisions)**

Please consider voting to reopen this question:

[Peak response of second order system with rectangular pulse input](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3454560/10513)

The OP has improved it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

Please reopen

- [Is a characteristic polynomial we consider in Linear Algebra a polynomial or a polynomial function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3633109)

The question is clear and natural to ask. It asks whether the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is a polynomial or a polynomial function. One common definition makes it look like the latter.

(Note that quantum groups are not groups and trigonometric polynomials are not polynomial in the usual sense).

Comment: It's considered good manners to indicate, when requesting a reopening, that you've provided an answer to the question yourself :)

Comment: @postmortes, thanks for the info, i didn't know it was relevant.

Comment: Generally if there's a benefit to someone personally by having the question-status changed (typically, they'll gain reputation from it) people here like that stated up front :)

Comment: @postmortes, i was ignorant of the personal benefit... I didn't know or forgot that answers to closed questions cannot be upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3687330/revisions)

The question [$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{A_p}{B_p}$ What is $A_p$ (mod $p^2$) where $\frac{A_p}{B_p}$ is a reduced form fraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3687330/279515) is closed as a duplicate of [Proof of Wolstenholme's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325491/279515), but perhaps this was a bit hasty. Quoting from the OP's update:

> It's been suggested that Wolstenholme's theorem can be used to finish the proof. The connection between the problem here and Wolstenholme's theorem is interesting so I will try to study Wolstenholme's theorem. However, it doesn't seem like a likely path to have taken from where I'm at in my understanding. I'm also skeptical Silverman had intended for the audience of his book to discover Wolstenholme's theorem as a lemma to proving that $_p$ is $0$ (mod $p^2$).

Based on this, I have added the [alternative-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) tag to it.

Can the question be reopened?

Answer (score 2):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2384486/revisions)

May I request that this old question [GCD of $n^a\,\prod\limits_{i=1}^k\,\left(n^{b_i}-n\right)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384486/gcd-of-na-prod-limits-i-1k-leftnb-i-n-right-for-n-in-mathbbz) of mine be undeleted?  The deletion was done by an automatic system (if that is the case, can it be voted to be undeleted?). I am certain that the question is well written with a lot of context.  I would like to put a bounty on the question.

Comment: It can be undeleted, but it will just be deleted again unless it gets an upvote or an upvoted answer. (There may be other conditions that would prevent it from being deleted, I'm not an expert.)

Comment: @MattSamuel  Perhaps, having a bounty is such a condition.  I am planning to offer a bounty on the question anyhow.  Let's see if that is the case.  (Thanks for your votes.  You have been a tremendous help.  And Zacky too!)

Comment: @Batominovski Your guess is right, questions with an active bounty will not be deleted by Roomba while the bounty is active — see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/313042) on Meta SE.

Answer (score 2):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3674717/revisions)

Please consider this question [Some Combinatorics and Some Prime Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674717/some-combinatorics-and-some-prime-numbers) to be reopened. This was posted by me seeking for other solutions rather than mine. I think it's well explained.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines in posting here. In particular this (quote): To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please add the information Reopened or Undeleted at the start once the request has resulted in some action. (If the action is undone, add this too, like Reopened, Reclosed.)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 2):

[**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2906269/revisions)

---

Please undelete [Invariance of the Lagrangian vs invariance of its integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906269/invariance-of-the-lagrangian-vs-invariance-of-its-integral)

It was recently autodeleted by Community because its net vote count was reduced to $0$ by a single vote cast in a recent downvote spree targeting me.

I'm still interested in the topic and am looking forward to an answer or two...

Answer (score 2):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3780454/revisions)**

Please reopen: [Given $\sinh x$, find the exact value of $\cosh x, \cos 2x$ and $\tan 2x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780454/given-sinh-x-find-the-exact-value-of-cosh-x-cos-2x-and-tan-2x).

As the question stands now, there is evidence of clear and informative context, and through this, the OP has managed to answer their own question. The reasons for closing this question stem from when the question was in a worse state, but after the edits, there is nothing confusing, or anywhere in the question that lacks context.

The answers to this question are of good quality, so it would be nice to preserve the answers to this question, without forcing the OP to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Undeleted, closed, deleted, undeleted, deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2840649/revisions)**

I think there's a consensus that we undelete questions when they are deleted by the user who posted them after someone else has posted an answer (see, for example, the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759560/extending-the-triangle-inequality#comment5694741_2759560). In accordance with that consensus, I propose undeletion of this post:

[Solutions to $\sum_{j=0}^k r_j^2+3r_j+2\equiv 0 \mod p $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840649/solutions-to-sum-j-ok-r-j23r-j2-equiv-0-mod-p)

Now I'll own up that I'm the one who posted the answer to the question. My answer was exceedingly terse, and came out of a review with the note, "This does not provide an answer to the question (and so on, and so forth)." But it does provide an answer. The question was to prove or disprove that there are no solutions to a certain equation (congruence, actually, but never mind), and my answer gave a solution.

Comment: Is this actually a consensus?

Comment: @Did, if you look at the previous edition of this thread, you'll find that in April-May, GNU Supporter posted 4 requests for undeletion, all on the grounds that OP had deleted a question after receiving an answer, and all four questions were undeleted.

Comment: Yes, and? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did For what it's worth, I have the same impression about the consensus. Preventing an asker from covering up their own question seems to be something the community values, even if it's closed later.

Comment: @T.Bongers (and also Gerry Myerson):  I think that there is a moderate consensus that it is bad form to ask a question, get an answer, then delete the question.  It belies an ignorance of the functioning of the site (i.e. questions are supposed to be helpful to *everyone*, not just the one person asking the question).  However, in this particular case, the question is of pretty low quality, and should be closed and deleted (in my opinion).  It seems like a waste of resources to have opened it back up again...

Comment: For what it's worth, I have expanded my answer to the question on main.

Comment: "For what it's worth, I have expanded my answer to the question on main."  On this topic, my understanding is that the consensus is that a good (or even great) answer is not really enough to justify keeping a poor question around.  [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20875) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16462) are relevant.

Comment: @Xander, the highest-voted answers and comments on your first link hardly support your understanding. The second link, even there there is considerable support for not deleting questions with good answers. I'm not convinced there is, was, or ever will be a consensus on this issue. A majority, maybe, but no consensus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you and I must be reading very different answers.  In answer to the question of whether bad questions with good answers should be preserved, my reading of the top three answers ([(1)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16464/468350), [(2)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16497/468350), [(3)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16465/468350)) suggest that it *might* be worth protecting a poor question if it hosts an *excellent* answer.

Comment: On the question of upvoting poor questions with good answers, the top voted answer is [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20876/468350), essentially "I don't do it, but there could be an argument in favor of it."  The [second answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20915/468350) is similar, with the idea being that a good answer should be preserved if it might be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: In both cases, it seems clear *to me* that the consensus is that it might be reasonable to preserve a poor question if it attracted a really good, useful, generally helpful answer.  Again, a good answer (or possibly even a great answer) is not, by itself, enough to preserve a poor question.

Comment: Finally, I note that I made my initial comment in response to your assertion that you have improved your answer.    Are you further asserting that the improvements created something that is of such lasting value that it will be beneficial beyond asking that poor question?  Despite the fact that this question and answer have been the topic of discussion here for a couple of days, your answer has not attracted any upvotes...

Comment: @Xander, I'm not in it for the upvotes. I objected to a user posting a question and then deleting it when it got an answer, as I agree with a moderator that such an action is an abuse of the site. Once the question was undeleted, I took the opportunity to improve my answer, in response to a comment from another user. What's wrong with that? I'm not asserting anything about the lasting value of the question or the answer, other than the answer being fuller now than it was. The answer may help someone coming along who is interested in sums of two squares modulo a prime. Fire away.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: it isn't pleasant to see one's own answer deleted, but in this case the question is clearly not up to many users' standards, so I think it is not surprising to see it deleted. At this point, the question is no longer deleted by the OP, but by several other users.

Comment: @Carl, it isn't pleasant to see any answer with nonzero mathematical content deleted. More to the point, I would not have put the question up for undeletion, had it been deleted by votes of users. My objection was to OP abusing the site by deleting the question after getting an answer. I thought that was clear.

Comment: @Jack  Why? This question has no context, is highly downvoted, and it was deleted automatically because the community regarded it as "not useful." Why are you championing this question?

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

(This is to break this [request post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/28765/1) into two)

I would like, if it is possible, remove the labels close-hold for some of next of my recent post
[Convergence of $\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{i^n}$, where $i$  is the imaginary unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831119/convergence-of-prod-n-2-infty-left1-frac1n2-rightin-where-i)

I think that the answers are very interesting and very good, and I think that the questions are in the standard of questions of MSE. Any case many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider undoing the duplicate votes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862662/quicker-and-less-error-prone-methods-for-finding-determinant). The [duplicate target](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857224/efficient-algorithm-for-calculating-determinants) is quite different as it asks for algorithms while this questions asks for easy ways to calculate determinant (so that careless errors are less likely to commit). The duplicate target is a poor question without context (though with some decent answers).

FYI: It failed the reopening review [five times](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2862662/timeline) before, as of 3rd Sept. 2018.

Comment: Two points: 1. did you ask the user that put it on hold as duplicate about it? 2. It seems that the answer on the dupe target includes the answer on the original question. // Personally I think the answer given on this question is pretty much besides the point. And the question is very localised. Long story short. I'd delete post.

Comment: @quid: I didn't (I thought this case is obviously wrong, and it had 4 reopen votes already). I agree that the question is localised and deletion is also a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please re-open this question which is put on hold:

[Understanding De/Suspension $\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma{X})\neq X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887114/understanding-de-suspension-sigma-1-sigmax-neq-x)

It was said that "unclear what you're asking" and people do not know the def of de-suspension.

However, the suspension is introduced earlier in the cited question:

[The suspension (topology) and elementary examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884901/the-suspension-topology-and-elementary-examples)

While the desuspension is also quoted/linked to the Wikipedia (withe refs given by Wiki). I also include a new note: "The desuspension is arguably firstly introduced in the cited text mentioned in H. R. Margolis (1983). Spectra and the Steenrod Algebra. North-Holland. p. 454." And the ref cited.

Follow people's comments, I modify to also ask the basic definitions:

> Question: How do we define desuspension exactly? (Please see the comments below, people complain about the meanings of desuspension in Wikipedia is useless).
>
> Are we able to have the desuspension acting on the topological space as the suspension does? Or do we only have the desuspension act on the spectra but not the space?

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2573873/revisions)**

Please consider reopening [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573873/when-is-a-conic-represents-a-pair-of-planes). It was closed originally as missing context. The OP provided some context in the comment and I have added a little bit more. Hope it is okay now.

Comment: Wow, this question was through reopen review queue [already four times](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2573873/timeline). It makes me wonder what is the record.

Comment: I think it just how difficult it is to reopen a post using only the review queue. @MartinSleziak

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2862662/timeline) has 5 and is still closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening the question [A functional equation of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2928177/64809) that is placed On Hold. I have added my attempt at the cracking the problem if the lack of it was the reason for placing it on hold. The question itself is technically perfectly sound.

Comment: You should have just edited your previous answer, and not added another "answer."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: What do you mean? "Answer" to my question that I linked to? I did not post an answer to my own question.

Comment: No, *answer(s) on the present meta page*, there should not be two for a single post on main.

Comment: I have removed the second post, since this one has been edited to indicate the reopening. I've also edited and deleted/undeleted, so whomever downvoted can undo their vote.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh, sorry. I did not know the first request was posted as I remembered closing the page rather than posting the "answer" as I needed to leave in a hurry earlier. I posted the second request thinking that the first request was not posted. This is the first time I post in the meta question site.

Comment: Why this post says "reopened" when the linked question is still on hold [at the moment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2928177/timeline)?

Comment: @Martin, seems to have been a mistake, which I have rectified.

Comment: The thing that is missing in the current version of the question, more than work, is the source of the problem.  Why do we expect it is true in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2952039/timeline)

The [deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2952039/290189) for *[Show that there does not exist a unique stationary distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2952014/290189)* should be *undeleted*.

The question is about "existence of unique stationary measure", and the answer is concise and *to-the-point*.

> "$(1,0,0,...,0)$ and $(0,0,...0,1)$ are two invariant distributions so uniqueness fails."

The [existing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2952122/290189) shares the *same* idea with the deleted one, and it has passed a [Low Quality Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1083858).

(Edit: **comment removed**)

The deleted answer attracted an comment from a high-rep user during another [Low Quality Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1083741).  However, by appealing to his/her tag score for the relevant tags ([markov-chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markov-chains), [markov-process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markov-process), [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory), [stochastic-process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-process), [stochastic-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-calculus), etc) (and the *contributing posts*) and comparing them with those of the answerer, you'll have a better idea about their contributions to the site in those areas.

Comment: Oddly, the deleted answer was deleted, not through review, but by its owner.

Comment: You could ping the author on another of his posts, but I generally oppose undeleting a self-deleted post.

Comment: The author has commented on the other answer, so he can be pinged there if necessary. This is an odd situation.

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I did ping the author.  He can undelete this anytime he wishes.  I ponder [whether CRUDE is healthy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28390/290189), when some of its active users vote to delete short answers _outside their familiar tags_ regardless of the quality of the answer.  This isolated example shows that its malfunctioning in terms of quality control.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 This isolated example shows nothing about CRUDE, since the delete votes and the associated comment came from the review queue, and the answer was never mentioned in CRUDE. Besides, I'm not sure tag scores are necessarily an indicator of expertise : for example I have a low score in "integration" because I don't really like to compute integrals, but I still know the basics and I think I'm competent to judge the quality of reasonably simple answers on the topic.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I see your points, but let me clarify my stance.  1. To be more precise, I would say that this post shows the _influence_ of CRUDE participation on _other_ posts (not listed on CRUDE).  In a review queue, it's possible that one votes to close/delete within a few seconds.  Given the amount of posts that they review every day (in/outside CRUDE), this example reminds us the adverse effect of their rare mistakes dispite their high reputation.  2. That's why I've added "contributing posts" inside the brackets.

Comment: If you read the _posts_ instead of the scores, you'll find out the truth:  a) there's _no_ probability theory in his/her "probability theory" answers.  These are mistagged (elementary) _probability_ questions.  b) His/her stochastic calculus tag score comes from a reference request question.
By the way, he/she has **removed** his/her comment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted, closed, deleted, re-undeleted, reopened**

I nominate [How to use derivatives to prove that $f(x)=2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(x\right)=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988824/290189) for undeletion since OP has self-deleted his/her question after receiving an answer.  This is *unacceptable* on Math.SE.

Comment: It's better to write self-contained posts. In the current case for the moment there was no big risk, but it's still not ideal.

Comment: @quid Thanks for your intervention.  I'll correct this now.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed and deleted by users. It is *not* unclear what they're asking. (It may not be *true*, but it is certainly clear!)

Comment: @user1729 Some users don't like wrong info in the question.  They have standards so high that $D(\sin x)$ and the RHS of $f'(x)$ doesn't please them.  It's possible that they used their power to get rid of this question.

Comment: It's definitely not unclear—the questioner gives the problem, shows what they did, and asks what's wrong with it. I think it could do with an additional answer which makes crystal clear what the error was and how the (interesting!) technique works, and **reopening** would allow someone to post that.

Comment: @timtfj It's now reopened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 At least it's clear that their expectations could never rise to match the size of your assumptions...

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

---

I nominate [Group algebra&algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2978538/290189) for undeletion so as to give the community enough time to judge this value of its answer, which is deleted due to the question asker's self-deletion.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted and reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3056520/revisions)**

unfortunately the question I asked   [Why is the zero polynomial the only one to have infinite roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3056520)
was put on hold as off-topic first and then closed. I edited it much for it to be reopened but it wasn't opened. I apologise if it was off-topic to you, but I edited it. If it being off topic yet, kindly suggest improvements or reopen it.

Comment: Please include a link to the question.

Comment: its humble request

Comment: why you deleted that

Comment: @quid couldn't you suggest edits

Comment: "couldn't you suggest edits " What do you mean? How am I supposed to know which question you mean?

Comment: @quid the link of which i have given above

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. I did not delete you question. At the moment I do not plan to get involved.

Comment: Two posts here about the same question. Are we supposed to expect some more any time soon?

Comment: @Did, the first post was about closure, the second, deletion. Unless there is some action more severe than deletion, I'd guess there won't be any more posts about the question.

Comment: I have flagged the question on main to ask the moderators to let the community make the decision.

Comment: The main problems with the question seem to be that (i) the questioner is confused, and (ii) it's tricky to answer in a way that properly addresses the confusion. The first seems a good reason to ask the question, and the second suggests that good answers will be thoroughly explanatory and therefore of high value.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

I nominate [A question of arithmetic regarding erection cost of a structure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963680/a-question-of-arithmetic-regarding-erection-cost-of-a-structure) for reopening since the question asker has shown his/her work in solving the problem.

Comment: I agree, but think they should also be encouraged either to edit what they said in comnents into the question, or to give someone else permission to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Please reopen [The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^n$ if and only if $\text{Tr}(A^i)=0$ for all $1\le i \le n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983730/290189) due to the reasons listed in OP's comment.  The first duplicate matches half of the question.  The hypothesis of the second duplicate is *different* from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Please undelete [Generalization of the fundamental theorem of duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3112873/290189) since the question asker has deleted his/her own question shortly after receiving an answer.  This is an abuse of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted and reopened**

Please reopen [Proving the greatest lower bound.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559291/290189) because OP has self-deleted his/her own question after I've answered this question.  This inhibits the community from viewing the question.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Is there an injective homomorphism from $S_4$ to $GL(2,C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3143415/290189) because the question asker has shown efforts in solving the problem, and it has a score of 4 with an accepted answer of score 3 from a 25k user.

Comment: Answers should not be used to judge whether a question should be reopened. But in this case, the asker did include sufficient context, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: "Answers should not be used to judge whether a question should be reopened." That's your opinion, @user – it is not a rule, or even a consensus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It is **your comment** that is an opinion; it's not even a consensus. Both [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16464) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16497) clearly demonstrate a consensus that "bad questions beget bad questions" and "closed questions can and should be deleted even if the have good but standard answers; only truly great answers should rather not be deleted".

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for your comment.  I'll be aware of that next time.

Comment: @user, your quote refers to deletions, not closure/reopening; what's more, the part that says "only truly great answers should rather not be deleted" plainly contradicts your assertions that "answers should not be used to judge...."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Firstly, if a bad question ought to be deleted, then **obviously** it should not be reopened. Secondly, it would be real silly to assume that everything I say is to be taken completely rigidly with no room for exceptions; from my very first comment I meant that **as a rule of thumb** answers should not be used to judge...

Comment: @user, I'm not sure how I am to tell which things you write are to be taken completely rigidly, and which allow room for exceptions. Maybe we could work out some signal, so in the future I'll be able to tell.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Usually, I try to be precise, using words like "typically" or "almost always" but, you know, that that is very tiring to do in every single statement. How about you just assume that there may be rare exceptions unmentioned unless I use the word "absolutely"? I don't think anyone is 100% precise all the time anyway, so that works for interpreting others' comments too.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please consider reopening the following question:

[Maclaurin Series Expansion of $\ln(1+\sin x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202935/maclaurin-series-expansion-of-ln1-sin-x)

The details which were included afterwards contradict the reason of closure. Moreover they indicate that the OP has as fundamental erroneous understanding of the concept of a MacLaurin Series - and how to derive them -rather than the unwilligness of showing his own efforts. In my opinion the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please reopen [Am I have right answer about dual problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3203415/290189) since OP has responded to the comment and used MathJax to type out the math.  In the *revised* version, OP has attempted to construct the dual program of the primal program, so it's OK for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

This question was closed as "unclear what your asking":

[Show that the order of an element g is well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3200560/10513)

The issue and its resolution can be seen in the comments to the thread. A brief summary is: I and others didn't understand the question (possibly others influenced by me), but I understand it now. Its fine in its current form.

Comment: @Brahadeesh How is it closed as a duplicate? I didn't see it when I clicked into the question...

Comment: @YuiToCheng Terribly sorry, I could swear I saw it was closed as a duplicate. I'm reverting my edit. Don't know how that happened. :/ I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted and closed as duplicate**

[Choose 2 good batteries out of 8 (4 bad 4 good)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189483/choose-2-good-batteries-out-of-8-4-bad-4-good) was deleted by its author, after an answer was posted. This is considered to be an abuse of the system.

Full disclosure: the only answer posted before the self-deletion was mine.

Comment: Currently closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted, put on hold, deleted**

Please undelete https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3209899/290189 since OP self-deleted her own post after receiving an answer.  This is an abuse of the system.

Comment: I undeleted it. Please try to use correct terminology. Undelete and reopen are not the same.

Comment: @quid Thanks for your undeletion and reminder.  I'll be aware of that next time.

Comment: Question is currently on hold.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for notification.  Status updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

Please undelete [A probability to 6 in a dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3223004/290189) since OP has self-deleted his/her own question after receiving an answer. This isn't fair to the answerer because his answer deserves review from the community.

Answer (score 1):

> **Both undeleted, second link redeleted**

Please undelete [A contradiction in calculating the legendre symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3224462/290189) and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3224172/290189 because OP's have self-deleted their question after receiving an answer from others.

Comment: I undelete both. At least for the one, it'd also have  been possible to let it deleted as it was a relatively simply oversight. It's not clear there is any value in keeping that around. But there is also no harm, so.

Comment: Please adhere to the "one request per answer" format; having multiple requests in the same answer makes it difficult to track changes.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thanks for your comments.  I'll beware of this practice next time.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted.**

Please undelete [Bounding the number of edges in a graph satisfying a certain property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234747/easy-bipartite-ramsey-theory) since the question asker has self-deleted his/her question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

Please consider undeleting the question:

[Intersection of Normal closure and Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250701/10513)

The OP deleted question after answer was given.

Comment: I undeleted, but maybe write a proper answer next time.

Comment: @quid I like hints (plus its a pretty straightforward question - I spent a while debating whether to just leave it at "kill $t$").

Comment: Then maybe start a Q&H site. This is Q&A site.

Comment: @quid the hint was clearly sufficient for the OP - they wouldn't have deleted their question otherwise! :-)

Comment: That's pretty irrelevant to my point. Further, If "sufficient for the OP" is your main concern, why do you bother us with an undelete request? // The way that hint was orginally presented to me personally made it pretty confusing. The new format is in a way better. But, frankly I just despise that form. I know it's popular but I think it's terrible style.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3262238/revisions)

Please consider reopening [Does knowing the surface area of all faces uniquely determine a tetrahedron?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262238/does-knowing-the-surface-area-of-all-faces-uniquely-determine-a-tetrahedron).  This is a very natural and self-motivating question that does not need any additional context, and it's gotten several great answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening this post, suitably narrowed since originally closed as "too broad":

[Book recommendation... Linear Programming for self-study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260586/book-recommendation-to-study-topics-of-linear-programming-for-self-study)

I don't believe there has been another such request, and under my pestering the OP has provided context for what sort of self-study they've previously undertaken.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3093232/revisions)

Please consider undeleting and reopening this post:

[How does one prove the inequality $1+|x|\le (1+|y|)(1+|x-y|)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3093232/9464)

OP clearly indicated the context of his/her question: it is from a proof in Wolff's lecture notes on harmonic analysis.

[Added upon request: this post has also been [edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3093232/timeline) into a (more) decent one.]

Comment: If you edit a post significantly indicate so in the request. I have no problem with it by itself, but since such actions are quite frequently overlooked by observers it can lead to the **false** impression that a relatively decent post was deleted.

Comment: @quid If someone else (not OP) edits OP's question to make the question 'fit' on MSE, then does the question gets reopened or undeleted always?

Comment: I said different by OP because sometimes the question is old, say 2015, and OP hasn't visit MSE since 2015.

Comment: @Isa I'd say yes for the most part (although what 'fit' mean of course leaves room for interpretation). That said, some users do not like the practice, thus there can also be push back. But in abstract and as a general principle (there can be exceptions in special cases) if a question is a good fit for math.se we usually keep it around no matter how it arrived in this state.// If you want to discuss this in more detail please open a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened, closed as duplicate**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2790867/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this well-received (33 net upvotes) question under the tag of `probability`: [Probability of drawing the Jack of Hearts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2790867/9464)

There are useful discussion and several good answers, one of which has 77 upvotes.

Comment: The question was originally closed as "off-topic: lacking context" (which, in my opinion, was not unreasonable).  It is, however, also a duplicate of other questions, as indicated by the comments.  If it is to remain on the site, it should be properly linked via a dupe closure.

Comment: At most "similar" or "related". Not a *duplicate*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what?  The question above asks us to determine the probability of drawing a Jack from a deck of cards from which an unknown card has been removed.  One of the two questions in the dupe target asks for the probability of drawing an Ace from a deck of cards from which an unknown card has been removed.  These are precisely the same question, and answers to the older question completely answer the newer question!  How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Mr. Henderson, I have a very narrow definition of "duplicate" from yours. No need to be sorry. And of course you do have the right to vote it as a duplicate.

Comment: I marked it as a dupe. That said @Xander I think the difference is slightly larger than you make it look. This question is about one specific card (a jack *of hearts*), while the dupe is about a group of cards (an ace). I still think that is a duplicate. // Since the comment on main got auto-deleted I'll add that two users other than me had mention it as a dupe. Thus, it was at least a trilateral closure. :-)

Comment: @quid Indeed, I had missed that.  That said, as you note, the distinction is not fundamental.  Thank you for handling it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/507796/revisions)**

---

The question [Problem with sum of projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/problem-with-sum-of-projections) was incorrectly marked as a duplicate of [Orthogonal projections with $\sum P_i =I$, proving that $i\ne j \Rightarrow  P_{j}P_{i}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117702/orthogonal-projections-with-sum-p-i-i-proving-that-i-ne-j-rightarrow-p).  The latter question has the additional hypothesis that the projections are self-adjoint (i.e., orthogonal projections) which allows for some rather different proof methods.  Indeed, none of the four answers to the second question solve the first question.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

I asked a question yesterday: [Coupon collector's problem: mean and variance in number of coupons to be collected to complete a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453965/coupon-collectors-problem-mean-and-variance-in-number-of-coupons-to-be-collect)

This asks for the mean and variance of the coupon collector's problem in the general case when the coupons have unequal probability. It has been marked as a duplicate of this one: [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die)

My edit clearly explains that I'm asking for the variance in the general case, while the question it is a supposed duplicate of asks only for the mean and that too in the special case of the coupons having equal probabilities.

So, the first question is not a duplicate of the one linked to it for sure. For this reason, I wanted the duplicate tag to be removed if possible.

I did ask a similar question myself in another post a few weeks ago here: [Coupon collectors problem: variance calculation missing a term.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439096/coupon-collectors-problem-variance-calculation-missing-a-term)

However, I wish to delete that post (the only answer there is my own) and want people to refer to this one since it is much more comprehensive.

In any case, the current question linked there is clearly more limited in scope along multiple dimensions.

Comment: I suggest that in the interests of transparency you edit a link to your earlier question into the body of the newer question, and vice versa.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm going to delete the other question, so this might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3056616/revisions)**

Please consider undeleting [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3056616/242)

It is a nice instructive problem about a topic that deserves to be much better known and often proves troubling for students - namely Kronecker's ideas relating the factorization of polynomials to the factorization of their values.

Because these ideas are so little known I can understand why the author had trouble getting started (not to mention a red herring assumption added about the polynomial degree). It's such a nice problem that I even added an answer a year later when I stumbled upon it in order to explain how it relates to the general ideas, hoping that I could link to it when similar problems are posted. Alas, that is not possible given the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3522319/revisions)

Request to reopen [Derive an atlas of Monge patches for a surface in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522319/derive-an-atlas-of-monge-patches-for-a-surface-in-3d)

Since the votes to close (without any comments), I've added links to sources and multiple links to material that motivates the question. I've also clarified what would constitute an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

I'd be glad if my question [Operator characterizations of continuity and “co-continuity”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892976/87690) was undeleted. It was automatically deteleted after one year since there were no answers, no comments and no votes. Recenly I wanted to reference the question in another answer and it was very hard to find it (see [my post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343430/700929) for more details). I think the question itself is written well enough and that it contains a useful summary.

Comment: If the question doesn't generate some activity, then presumably it will be auto-deleted again somewhere down the track.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hopefully, that would happen no sooner than in one year, so there is chance to get some activity. In fact, it got an upvote after the undeletion.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3571028/timeline)

Please consider undeleting [Complex Analysis: Showing analytic function is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571028/complex-analysis-showing-analytic-function-is-zero)
.

The post itself might be a PSQ and a frequently asked one at that (I guess that is because an easier version of this [Privalov's Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Privalov_theorem) is an exercise problem from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis textbook) but there are some good answers with valuable insights that are not 'textbook' in my opinion.

P.S.: The exercise from the book additionally assumes the holomorphic function converges uniformly to $0$ on the portion of the arc. For example see

(1) [Uniqueness of a holomorphic function with certain boundary values on an arc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893114/uniqueness-of-a-holomorphic-function-with-certain-boundary-values-on-an-arc)

(2) [$f$ is bounded, holomorphic in the unit disc, and converges to 0 uniformly in a sector then $f$ is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460924/f-is-bounded-holomorphic-in-the-unit-disc-and-converges-to-0-uniformly-in-a)

(3) [stein and shakarchi complex analysis exercise 3.15 (b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597461/stein-and-shakarchi-complex-analysis-exercise-3-15-b)

Comment: Is this the exercise from the book, or what is the exercise in the book?

Comment: The exercise asks the same problem but with additional condition of the function being continuous upto the boundary of the disk.

Comment: Could you edit that into the post as context? (Or maybe you cannot as it is deleted. In which case I ask would you if undelted.)

Comment: @quid If the post is undeleted can I put a link of this post in the question?

Comment: I prefer if the relevant context is put into the actual post, you can link to the discussion here in a comment. (Generally As a rule, no "meta" content in a post. If it need be there can be a comment.)

Comment: Now undeleted. Please edit as indicated previously.

Comment: Voted to reopen still need a vote to reopen the topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Closed, Deleted**

I believe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644075 should be reopened (despite the bad title). It asks how to locate a a mathematical paper but was closed as “not about mathematics”. Reference requests are allowed – this is not a reference request, but the intention behind seeking a reference and seeking to locate a known reference is essentially the same; I see no reason why one should have its own tag ([reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)) and the other should be off topic.

Comment: The question is though is the question *to locate* the reference or is the question *to get the document delivered*. The former is maybe borderline on-topic, the later is off-topic, and indeed not about mathematics.

Comment: It is also not clear from the question whether the OP looks for the original or they want to know about existence of English translation. The tags (reference-request) and (translation-request) might be suitable there.

Comment: @quid: How do you mean, "delivered"? Do you mean the question could be interpreted as asking for someone to send them the paper? I would take "seeking" to mean that they would like someone to point them to where to find it (in an archive, in a collection, ...).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. (If "send" includes provide a link to a download.) Having looked at the edit history I agree with @MartinSleziak that the intent of the question is rather unclear. Maybe it could be on-topic but as is it's unclear what even is asked.

Comment: @quid: But what's off-topic about seeking a link where one could download a paper? How is a link different from a reference? They're both resource locators. Where else would a person be on-topic asking where to find a math paper if not here?

Comment: @quid: I posted that before seeing the edit to your comment. If it's unclear, it should be clarified, or at most closed as unclear; then the OP can clarify it and get it reopened. Currently the close reason is telling the OP that questions about locating papers (or translations thereof) are not welcome here, which would be news to me.

Comment: The question is what does "locating" mean in your comment. Typically with an exact reference it is trivial *to locate* a version of the document. Yet to  access them might cost time and/or money, and helping with the last step is not about mathematics.

Comment: @quid: What are you basing this on? I can't find any related policies. You're dividing locating resources into steps and defining some of the steps as off topic and others not. But finding a way to download a paper somewhere is just as much or little about mathematics as finding a classical reference to it. Being trivial is different from being off-topic. Lots of uncontroversially on-topic mathematical questions on the site are trivial.

Comment: Common sense. But actually it also did come up I think. And to elaborate on the "common sense" providing service to access documents given a reference is a service that is provided. The people that provide it are, eg, librarians, often without any particular competence in the subject of the paper but instead in well providing access to the literature.

Comment: @quid: OK, that's a criterion that makes sense to me. So the question would be off-topic if it asks for a service that doesn't benefit from mathematical expertise (and could in fact perhaps be performed better by a librarian than a mathematician), but would be on-topic if if benefits from mathematical expertise? That distinction would not always be clear-cut (mathematicians probably know their way around some online math resources better than librarians), but it would be a sensible explication of what it means for a reference request to be "about mathematics".

Comment: Yes it is not always clear cut. Regarding the distinction it is relevant to know what do you mean by "finding a classical reference"?  The word "finding" specifically. If I have a mathematical result and I want *to find* a reference for it, that is, I want to learn about a book or paper that contains it, then this is on-topic. If I want to read chapter 3 of Hardy and Wright  "Introduction to the theory of numbers" and I ask where to find it, then this is off-topic.

Comment: @quid: That last case is clear-cut because it clearly doesn't require mathematical expertise to locate that book. But with a little-known article in a little-known journal, it's less obvious whether mathematicians might have a better chance of knowing how to find it than others.

Comment: With exact bibliographic data  I don't really see that Where it starts to become interesting is when the bib data  is incomplete or unclear and one basically needs to be able to infer what it should be. Anyway, the question as is, seems at least unclear **and therefore should be closed**; if it is clarified it possibly could be reopened. If you care, you can guide the user in revising their post. (No it is not necessary to undo the closure to close as "unclear " instead.)

Comment: @quid: What are you basing the last sentence on?

Comment: Tradition. We never where super-exact with the exact reason. But no problem, if it gets reopened, I'll reclose as unclear if that's what you want.

Comment: @quid: I see. I think that's a bad tradition. Perhaps I'll write a post about that some time.

Comment: If you do that, you might want to keep in mind that several reasons can apply. Anyway, I really don't think it's an overly pressing concern and anything useful will come from it.

Comment: @quid: Speaking of tradition: It seems that in the olden days people were more willing to act as mathematical librarians. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40762/finding-a-paper) and its several answers have lots of upvotes and no downvotes; the answers provide both general advice on how to locate papers and specific links for the specific search that prompted the question. Interestingly, one of the answers is by amWhy, these days not a stranger to advocating for closure as off-topic (and, incidentally, for leaving incorrect close reasons in place).

Comment: I removed the last sentence from my comment, which indeed was not quite appropriate. Speaking about non-appropriate why  drag unrelated users into this? Either way I provided an exact reference to the English translation.

Comment: Beyond it being close to a decade old, that question is quite different in that it asks for methods in general. That's way different. It also mentions a specific paper, but it couches it into a more general question.

Comment: On more remark; it should be obvious that for various reasons we should not encourage requests for specific documents. First it is often not a question of interest beyond the immediate need of one person, but let's leave that aside. It invites answers that involve resources whose legality is at least up for debate.

Comment: @quid: On your previous comment: Yes, I was aware of that difference, but that difference doesn't make a difference with respect to the one thing we agreed on above, that a sensible criterion for being on topic here is whether mathematical expertise is beneficial for answering the question. If mathematicians are particularly competent to give advice on methods in general, then they're also particularly competent to help in finding specific papers.

Comment: @quid: On what are you basing the implication that questions shouldn't be encouraged that are not of interest beyond the immediate need of one person? Lots of uncontroversially on-topic questions are like that.

Comment: Since you care about the old days, certainly you still recall "too localized".

Comment: @quid: Lucky for me that you don't care as much about the old days :-)

Comment: The principle still persists to some extent. Either way, the main reason I gave was a different one.

Comment: Since you asked about policy from the FAQ about the meta-tags on tag ref request : "Questions of the form "What is the earliest known proof of X", or "Who is the first person to observe Y" fall under this category, as are questions of the form "Where can I find a proof of this Theorem/Inequality/Algebraic Identity?" "  Nowhere does it mention "Where can I find this article?"

Answer (score 1):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3688041/revisions)**

How to undelete the following question [$\sum_{i=1}^n ( nGx_i^{G} + G^{x_i}) \ge n^2G + G^2n$, for all $x_i>0$, where $G=\prod_{j=1}^nx_j$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3688041)

As you see, some users have done serious contributions in order to solve the conjectured problem, so it may be unfair to permanently delete the whole discussion. My own attempts to solve the questions were fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted, Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3648024/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen [If $AB\parallel DC$, $BC\parallel AD$, and $AC\parallel DQ$, find $\Bbb X$ in terms of the areas $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb B$, and $\Bbb C$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648024/) (the asker showed attempts as discussed in the META question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31606/can-we-please-stop-voting-to-close-a-question-just-because-the-question-is-short)).  More context has been added.

Let it be known that I answered the question.  This information seems unnecessary.  My answer is there when you open the link (and you have to, if you want to decide whether to reopen/undelete the question).  Why do users insist on having this information disclosed, even if the information is public?  Whether you want to reopen/undelete a question should depend on your opinion on the question and answers there, and not on the person who asked the question or who answered the question.

Comment: We note that user Batominovski has posted an answer to the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I am not sure why this seems to be an issue.  Many users here also requested questions they have answered to be reopened/undeleted.  I can make my answer a community wiki post if that is a problem.

Comment: No need to go community wiki, just be transparent when you have an interest in a question, please.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3752559/revisions)

I tried my best to edit this question to make it more concise, if anyone has recommendations on how to make it even better pls just ping me

[Why do sometimes care for where vectors originate from and sometimes not? and exactly how many kinds of vectors are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752559/pivot-of-vectors)

Answer (score 1):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1367901/revisions)

May I request that this old question [Countably Infinitely Many Points in a Euclidean Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367901/countably-infinitely-many-points-in-a-euclidean-space) of mine be undeleted?  The deletion was done by an automatic system (if that is the case, can it be voted to be undeleted?). I am certain that the question is well written with a lot of context.  I would like to put a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I request that my question here is reopened:

[Do I understand the difference between $\implies$ and $\to$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808485/do-i-understand-the-difference-between-implies-and-to?noredirect=1#comment7851878_3808485)

I ask some very specific questions about the use of $\implies$ and $\to$ that it is different from the duplicate question.

Comment: I suspect it would help your case if you edited your question to remove anything covered by the linked question, and also to made clear the differences between your question and the linked one (whilst still making the question readable, etc.). This would make it easier for people to judge the differences.

Comment: @user1729: I can do that. I just wanted to give the context that I was working in.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened and Undeleted, Closed again, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted again](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3796724/revisions)**

I think the following question should be reopened: [What Are The Elements of $e$ in Set Theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3796724)

It is an intriguing question which is no less deserving of attention than many of the questions we get here (I'd rather this kind of conceptual question than *yet another* integral to solve). It seems to me that the issue with the question is that it is not well-posed (to quote Asaf's answer, the answer "depends on which set is $e$"). However, the answers are explain the issue with the question and how to resolve it, which is the kind of answer I think the question needs.

Comment: Maybe the question is not that bad as it has elicited nice responses from various well established users. But the asker is not really keen on learning from the responses, and perhaps not really clear about their purpose in asking the question. It should be closed as "needs clarity". If the questions includes some proper context about definition of $e$ as well as its representation then it is more likely a candidate for reopening.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I disagree. It is clear that their purpose is that they wished to understand a comment of Asaf from elsewhere. One of the key points in the answers, and one of the subtleties of the question is that it matters how we define $\mathbb{R}$, so asking the OP to clarify this undermines this. Also, I don't think we should be judging the question based on the user, or their comments to the question; indeed, if we ignore the comments then everything is nice.

Comment: I am not judging users, the question does require a bit more clarity, for example what particular definition of reals is being used. A link to Asaf's comment on which this is based should also be included. Is the asker familiar with the set theoretic development of number systems or not?

Comment: Had these points been included in the question I think it would have been received very differently.

Comment: It is hard to believe the question is honest given the comments left in some of the answers.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I don't think we should be judging the question based on the user (who has a reputation for crankery), or their comments to the question; indeed, if we ignore the comments then everything is nice.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I learned from the responses that there exists more than one possibility for the elements of e, and it's cardinality. I didn't realize that before I had asked the question. I asked about how they could all represent the same set, since once set doesn't have two cardinalities. I didn't get a response to that, and one person apparently wanted no learning about the cardinality of e.  Perhaps my incorrect assumption was that there was one unique set theory, when there exist multiple set theories with conflicting concepts of e.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: I am not an expert on set theory so can't really say much here. Perhaps you should add all such clarification as a part of your question.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The point is that the "cardinality of $e$" doesn't matter, because its elements however you define is as a set mean different things depending on the definition. If you define it as a Dedekind cut, it is the set of all rationals less than $e$ and countable, and if it's as an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences then it's uncountable, but you can't compare the two sets by looking at their elements because it isn't meaningful. Equality has to be taken in a broader sense here as not meaning exact set-theoretic equality, but rather equivalence. Different sets, same real number.

Comment: @Doug: Your comments here seem almost dismissive of set theory, as something that you expected to be somehow "unique" but isn't. But again, go back to my answer, and actually read it. Are you surprised that there are different browsers (which in the past were almost incompatible with one another), or that there are different banks, different shops, or different operating systems? But if you want to buy a shoe online, which shop and which bank you use, and which delivery company does the actual delivery turn out to matter less to the *end result* of you having a shoe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've started a sandbox for a "canonical" form of this question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6554/10513), as mentioned in the comments to the question. Feedback (from anyone!) is appreciated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I'm not surprised by different browsers, different banks, or different shops.  But also, there isn't a presentation of all those things as if they were one, unitary entity.  The end result from purchasing things can differently significantly with respect to real world products.

Comment: @Doug: Nobody presents constructions of the real numbers in set theory as "this is the only way to do it".

Comment: @AsafKaragila It does seem to me, and perhaps this is my mistaken impression, that set theory, or at least ZFC (yes, I know there exists other choices like Von Neumann's), gets presented as a single theory for mathematics.  It doesn't seem so when talking about how *just one* real number might get constructed.

Comment: @MattSamuel "Equality has to be taken in a broader sense here as not meaning exact set-theoretic equality, but rather equivalence. Different sets, same real number."  I've been assuming that for all x, where x is a number, x = x.  I don't see how equality fits here, because of the inequality of different construction of 'e's.  I have to wonder if non-standard models might come into play here somewhere, given that x = x, gets suggested by one e having different members than another e.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Consider the two examples I gave. For the Dedekind cut, the relevant number is the least upper bound. For the Cauchy sequences, the relevant number is what the sequences all converge to. Those two are what you are comparing; the numbers are equal if the least upper bound is equal to the limit of the sequences.

Comment: I have asked a version of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828775/10513). I have also created a chat room for this topic [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113085/the-elements-of-a-real-number). @DougSpoonwood could you please ask further questions/clarification there, as the comments here are not really the place?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've asked the question, to try and divert the conversation from this meta thread :-). Is it possible for you to merge them, or should I request this via a flag?

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted, re-deleted, re-undeleted, closed, deleted again**

Before I could upvote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3923603/290189), the question asker self-deleted her question.  That's an abuse of the platform.  Please undelete.

Comment: If you can still access the question, you could flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for suggestion.  I've done so.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2875728/revisions)**

2 reopen votes left please:

[Prove $ \lim_{z \rightarrow z_o} f(z) \in \mathbb{C}$ if $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_o} (z-z_0) f(z) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875728)

I made a new question, where I tried to be as clear and narrow as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**, **redeleted**, **undeleted again**, **reopened**

[Statements that look obviously false but cannot be disproved.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919890/statements-that-look-obviously-false-but-cannot-be-disproved) is at $+15$, and has answers at $+7,+10,+14,+20,+21,+8$, and $+15$. Please consider voting to **undelete**. [In the interests of transparency, I note that the $+15$ answer is mine.]

Comment: I agree that the question is highly upvoted and has highly upvoted answers.  That does not make it an appropriate question for MSE.  With regard to what is [on-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it isn't a problem or puzzle, and I see no clear indication that there is a particular topic that needs to be clarified.  With respect to [what not to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), the question seems designed to engender discussion, not to seek explanation.

Comment: For the benefit of the people who cannot see deleted questions, I'll add that this MO question is mentioned in comments: [The most outrageous (or ridiculous) conjectures in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259844). (Even if this one does not get undeleted, the linked MO post might be interesting for people who would consider [Statements that look obviously false but cannot be disproved](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919890) interesting.)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Just curious, what would you then consider as on-topic for the [`soft-question`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) and [`big-list`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tags?

Comment: Surely we have better things to do that relitigate this post over and over again, and remove the collective efforts of 16 people. I see no harm from the existence of this post, except for the ruffled feathers of people who are inclined to overmoderation.

Comment: In my opinion, if some want content and others do not then it should stay. The veto should be over removal rather than the converse. I will never understand why it's so important to wreck somebody else's party.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

---

There have been at least five questions asking how to prove
instances of the general proposition $\log_m(m + 1) > \log_n(n + 1)$
for integers $n > m > 1$:

1.
[How to know if $\log_78 > \log_89$ without using a calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140337/how-to-know-if-log-78-log-89-without-using-a-calculator)
(3 May 2012), with an exemplary answer by user22805.

2.
[Logarithm inequality problem: $\log_2 3 > \log_3 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943588/logarithm-inequality-problem-log-2-3-log-3-4)
(27 Sep 2016).

3.
[Compare $\log_34 $ and $\log_45.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201152/compare-log-34-and-log-45)
(24 Mar 2017).

4.
[How to compare logarithms $\log_4 5$ and $\log_5 6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930365/how-to-compare-logarithms-log-4-5-and-log-5-6)
(25 Sep 2018).

5.
[Comparing $\log_5 6$ and $\log_6 7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948737/comparing-log-5-6-and-log-6-7)
(9 Oct 2018).

There have been at least three other questions asking to prove
inequalities of the form $\log_a{b} > \log_c{d}$ for integers
$b > a > 1$ and $d > c > 1$:

6.
[Which is bigger among (i) $\log_2 3$ and $\log _3 5$ (ii) $\log_2 3$ and $\log _3 11$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415500/which-is-bigger-among-i-log-2-3-and-log-3-5-ii-log-2-3-and-log)
(9 Jun 2013).

7.
[How can I compare $\log_2 3$ and $\log_3 5$ without using a calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417520/how-can-i-compare-log-2-3-and-log-3-5-without-using-a-calculator)
(5 Sep 2017).

8.
[Comparing $\log_2 3$ to $\log_3 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678913/comparing-log-2-3-to-log-3-5)
(6 Mar 2018).

There has also been at least one more complex question in the same broad
category:

9.[Prove $\log_{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{8}{7}> \log_{\frac{1}{5}} \frac{5}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199606/prove-log-frac14-frac87-log-frac15-frac54)
(20 Sep 2012).

Most recently, the following question was posted, but it was quickly closed
as a duplicate (I confess to being one of those who voted to close it):

10.
[Comparing logarithms with different bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968235/comparing-logarithms-with-different-bases)
(23 Oct 2018).

The close message for question 10 reads:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   How to compare logarithms $\log_4 5$ and $\log_5 6$?
>   *6 answers*

But the only method used to answer a previous question (1-9) that can also
be applied to the present question (10) is to find positive integers $m, n$
such that $b^n > a^m$ and $d^n < c^m$ (as in Eudoxus's theory of proportion),
so that $\log_ab > \tfrac{m}{n} > \log_cd$.

In a comment (which has now been incorporated into the text of the question),
the questioner showed that he was aware of this method, and had already used
it to answer his own question.  He continues:

> However, that method doesn't work for every example, and I wonder if there's
>   a easier way to solve this?

Strictly speaking, *any* logarithm comparison question *could*
be answered in this way.  But that is not always very practical, because
one one has to search for suitable values of $m$ and $n$, which may be
quite large.  Some previous answers state or imply the general rule that
$\log_a{b} > \log_c{d}$ if $\tfrac{b}{a} > \tfrac{d}{c}$ and $a < b$,
but that rule does not apply in this case.  It is interesting to ask if
some other rule might be applied, eliminating the need for a possibly
haphazard search for $m, n$.  Failing that, *ad hoc* solutions
to the present problem are also of interest.

Question 10 meets MSE's selection criteria, so it ought to be reopened.

Comment: The question lacks contract in any event. Most importantly: why were the specific constamts in the problems chosen? If the problem is about arbitrary constants, it should be rewritten to say so. If the OP was already aware of a method to solve the problem, that context should also be in the post. Overall the post does.noy seem to demonstrate much effort to write a good post.

Comment: @Carl On that basis, Diophantus would have a hard time posting a question here! Where, in MSE's rules, does it say that every question must be framed in the most general terms possible? What is wrong with asking a question about particular numbers? Especially as no-one has (yet) posted a general answer *or* a general question covering this particular case. Finally, even *if* it were granted (purely for the sake of argument) that an experienced user ought to have asked a more elaborate question, shouldn't a new user be cut some slack?

Comment: @Carl  Also, it was closed as duplicate, and my point is that it is *not* a duplicate. The close message is a false statement, and the close decision should be reversed. (Of course, anyone can also vote to close it for another reason, and no such person need feel obliged to vote for reopening.)

Comment: !Calum: there's no problem posting a question with specific numbers - but it *is* up to the OP to include adequate context, and the reason for choosing seemingly arbitrary numbers is (in my opinion) part of that context.  If this was asked person to person at a department tea, we would expect the asker to say something about the numbers involved. The OP should be encouraged to improve the problem, they have plenty of "slack" to do so.

Comment: I think my guilty conscience over this has now been assuaged. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Closed, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened.**

Unfortunately, the question I asked [Why is the zero polynomial the only one to have infinite roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056520/why-is-the-zero-polynomial-the-only-one-to-have-infinite-roots)
was put on hold as off-topic first, then closed, and then deleted. I edited it much for it to be reopened, but it wasn't reopened. I apologise if it was off- topic to you, but I edited it. If it being off topic yet, kindly suggest improvement or undelete it please.

---

Note (quid): I reopened this now. The mass-editing and double posting OP is gone, the question is simple and a bit confused, but arguably not overly contrived and understandable, and answered. It's not impossible somebody else might find this useful at some point.  Let's move on.

Comment: Have you finally made up your mind between "Wikipedia" and "wikipedia"?

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3101846/revisions)

I nominate [Optimization problem for routes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101846/290189) for undeletion because the question asker self-deleted his question shortly after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted, redeleted, re-undeleted, reopened**

Please consider reopening the following question:

[O is a point in triangle ABC. OA, OB and OC are joined and produced to meet BC, AC and AB at D, E and F. Find the value of OD/AD+OE/BE+OF/CF.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3187120/9464)

OP clearly indicates his/her attempt in the post:

> I took the special case when O is exactly in the centre of the triangle and got the answer $1$. But how can I prove it by taking the general case?

This is not a zero effort question.

Comment: Question was not merely closed, but deleted. Now undeleted (but still closed).

Comment: It's worth noting that [special cases](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27923/290189) provides is an effect way to prevent "*no-clue* questions".

Comment: The real missing context is the source and motivation of the problem.

Comment: CRUDE: "What is the source of FLT?" Fermat: "myself" CRUDE: "What is the motivation of FLT?" Fermat: "for fun"

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 If you actually believe that this is the way that Fermat conceptualized his work, then I would suggest that you have a deeply flawed view of history.  While the culture of mathematics was quite different in Fermat's time (e.g. methods were generally regarded as secrets), I am quite certain that he was more than capable of describing motivation for his work and the context into which it fit.  Your caricature of Fermat does a disservice to your argument.

Comment: Q: Where's the proof of FLT?  Fermat: I don't have enough space to write it.  Do we have as much sense of humor as the French three centuries ago?

Comment: @GNU sorry to be blunt, but that just does not add up at all. So much so that there just is no joke there even. For a start, the problem is **not due to Fermat.** The famous margin is that of a published book he was reading (Arithmetica by Diophantus, IIRC) that presented the problem. I am to lazy to check what exactly it is but it's a  certainty that there was some context there. For example, that for $n=2$ there is an infinitude of solutions that can be parametrized.  Second, and crucially, **Fermat never published** or even mentioned that 'note to self' (likely as he realized it was wrong).

Comment: @quid Thanks for your math history lesson, but I supposed that's a classic joke whose truth value wouldn't be judged as on the main site. Looking back, that doesn't suit serious math historians.  Another meta post might be needed to avoid extended discussion here.

Comment: @GNU what exactly should have been funny? You tried to ridicule others.

Comment: @quid Your question concerns a subjective feeling, so the response is personal, and clearly mine can't be carried to serious math historians, but the historic truth itself is not the main point. If you wish a more serious example, you may consider [Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39099/290189) instead.

Comment: @GNU well, whatever, it seems you did try ridicule others. You tried to make a joke at their expense. This is has little to do with subjective feelings. It's an observation. If your intent was a different one, then what was it exactly? Example of what? Do you want to present Ramanujan as a good example of mathematical communication? What the example maybe shows is that just because something is presented intransperently one should not dismiss it out of hand. However, it seems to me that Hardy and maybe others did try to get Ramnujan to be more transparent. So what again is your point?

Comment: @quid My "joke" is an response to Carl Mummert's comment.  It's actually much more simpler than you think.  Good math questions can come without source and motivation (comprehensible to others).  If asked for a "motivation" and "source" for one of Ramanujan's identities (perhaps by Carl Mummert), what would Ramanujan respond?

Comment: @GNU it's a bit amusing that to prove your point you linked to a question that specifically asks for motivation. Apparently that question for motivation was deemed as a quite meaningful one. First, it's not clear to me what *question* Ramanujan would have asked. Once you clarify that we might discuss the point. Generally, it's not even clear what your point is. What one might deduce is that "because something is presented intransperently one should not dismiss it out of hand." It's still poorly presented. And, incidentally Ramanujan had to get lucky for somebody even considering it at all.

Comment: Quoting from Ramanujan's wiki page: "An equation for me has no meaning," he once said, "unless it expresses a thought of God."  From this, a sensible response for Ramanujan would be an appeal to his own religious beliefs.  From your comment to one of my recent meta answer, he wouldn't need to post the religious motivation on the main site.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 maybe it would be a response consistent with that quote, whether that's *sensible* would be a separate matter. I think there is a high risk in taking things at face value and outside their cultural context. Examples of this abound, not only related to religion. Anyway, if you want to take this to then end somebody presents an equation here and asks if it is known/true and then reply to the request where it comes from that some deity send it to them in their dreams then well that's still some context.

Comment: Of course this has nothing whatsoever to do with what Carl said since in all likelihood that poster did not come up with the Q but read it somewhere. If they claim they came up with it themselves, with divine help or otherwise, again that'd be context.  @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: @quid I was typing on mobile, and my question "what would Ramanujan respond?"  is intended to be answered in the reponse that follows.  Many main site questions ask for proofs for an equation/inequality.  Which particular identity is not important. Anyone will do, say, Ramanujan's triple product identity.  According to Carl Mummert, in order to qualify as a good question, Ramanujan would have to provide a "source" and a "motivation" of his own identity.  As a result, he would have appealed to his God, but that's not what the community wanted.  So a request for motivation can get sth illogical.

Comment: @GNU again, "I came up with this myself" or your "for fun" is some context. Just like "read it somewhere." Just that, is of course not ideal, but in my book it's *much better*  than nothing. I don't know what's difficult to accept about this. And if there would be some "by experimentation", "by extrapolation from  X", "in analogy with Y" there too. It might be pretty reasonable as context.

Answer (score 0):

Can this answer (on permutation groups) be undeleted:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3197094/10513

It was deleted for not providing an answer to the question. However, it gives a decent hint which leads to a solution. The hint is essentially "consider odd vs. even numbers". This was made formal in the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3197096/10513), which used mod 2.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch from that hint to the accepted answer. The hint ought to be a comment (in my opinion).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hints are a grey area. But I don't think deleting them because they are "a bit of a stretch" is the right thing to do.

Comment: It would have been better, had a moderator converted the "answer" to a comment. You could try flagging the question for moderator attention, and making that suggestion.

Comment: I flagged it beforehand, and was told to post my request here (admittedly i didn't suggest making it into a comment)

Comment: OK, now you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Undeleted**, **Merged and then deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3208119/290189 since OP has self-deleted his/her own post after getting an answer.  The community should have been given enough time to vote.

Comment: You can't reopen a question that isn't closed, GNU. *Now* it has been closed, as a duplicate, but I don't see how $x^y+y^x=(xy)^2-19$ is a duplicate of $x^y-y^x=xy^2-19$. So, I'm flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By the moment I posted this answer, I _did_ voted to close this question as missing context.  I _did_ notice the difference between the two.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson a problem is that the original version of the question was incorrect. A third party edited it to this version, while main OP had re-asked a different version.

Comment: I deleted it after the merge now. This did not work out ideally, but it's near impossible to fix. If somebody wants that version of the question on the site I recommend to ask it anew.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened**

Please consider undeleting this post: [What is the formula of this angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249440/9464)

There is a well written and well-received answer to this interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Reopened, closed**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2236416/revisions)

Please consider reopening (also for the sake of avoiding further unreasonable strong action of deletion, there has been a delete vote already): 
[How to show for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $|x|\leqslant 1+x^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2236416/9464)

This is completely a legitimate question to ask for a beginner. Also, OP did show his/her work in the post, although he/she did not notice what he/she proved is actually a stronger result. Furthermore, it has very well written answers.

I feel it very harsh to close/delete such posts.

Comment: I'd agree with Jack's assessment that the OP already has $2|x|\le1+x^2$ and they missed that this implies the result - and this should count towards context. It would be nice if the OP included how they got $2|x|\le1+x^2$, even if only as a link to some place where this is proved - but since the OP hasn't been seen for a long time, it is unlikely that they add this to the post now.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to call this "legitimate question to ask for a beginner". It seems to me that noticing that $|x|\leq 2|x|$ and knowing that order is (by definition) transitive is more basic than proving $2|x|\leq 1+x^2$, so I would interpret the question more as the OP having been just momentarily distracted. I doubt it's really necessary to keep that question and its answers.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, put on hold, deleted, undeleted again (the war goes on)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3261057/revisions)

Undelete please this topic: [Minimum of $x^2+y^2$ for $\frac1x+\frac8y=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3261057)

The topic starter solved this problem by using "differentiation or Lagrange multipliers", but he looked for a short solution and he got it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1930743/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this old post: [Show that a function $f:P(X)\to P(X)$ preserving the subset relation has a fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930743/9464)

It was created on **Sep 17 '16**, has two good answers.

Comment: It seems to be a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791411/every-increasing-function-from-a-certain-set-to-itself-has-at-least-one-fixed-po), and Aloizio's anwer in fact answers the general question. So if the goal is to preserve answers, the logical thing to do would be to move them there.

Comment: It seems to me the Question at issue here has the more general formulation (it does not require an "increasing" function).  In any case I've voted to reopen as the Question at issue meets my threshold for context (and it otherwise also on-topic).

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that the question has two good answers.  It has one good answer, and a hint.  The question itself is not good at all.  I am content to see the question left undeleted, but I see no reason to reopen it.  Arnaud D.'s suggestion is, I think, preferable.

Comment: "I am content to see the question left undeleted." Well, that is what my proposal is. I agree that the question itself *was* not good enough and thus I did not ask for reopening. @Martin Sleziak has added useful information to the post. (Thanks!) Also, Aloizio's good answer mentions at the beginning "the nice answer by @Brian".

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened, closed**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3241237/revisions)

[What is the maximal number of subsets of a finite set, such that no one is the unions of some other ones?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241237/what-is-the-maximal-number-of-subsets-of-a-finite-set-such-that-no-one-is-the-u) is a serious mathematical question which has attracted two useful answers (full disclosure – one of those two answers is mine). Please have a look and consider casting the third vote to undelete.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2981718/revisions)

Please consider undeleting and reopening this post: [radical center of three circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2981718/9464).

This post clearly indicated an attempt and has a detailed [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2981827/9464).

Answer (score 0):

> **[Undeleted, Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3063922/revisions)**

Please consider undeleting and reopening this post: [Convergence or diverge of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - e^{-n^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063922/9464)

OP clearly indicated his/her thoughts at the beginning of the post, and there is a well written (with 10 upvotes) answer.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened, closed**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/905653/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this post:

[How to find ${\large\int}_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x} \mathrm dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905653/9464)

This is not a trivial exercise and OP shows his/her thoughts that "Routine textbook methods for this complicated integral fail." It has several *very* well-written detailed answers with rather high number of upvotes.

Comment: '[S]hows his/her thoughts that "Routine textbook methods for this complicated integral fail."' That's not relevant context. Most likely it's a constructed challenge and should have been declared as such. This type of post borders on a misuse of the site. The following comment at score 13 is relevant **I feel like it's becoming a trend to ask questions about practically impossible integrals.**

Comment: **You** think "That's not relevant context." And this proposal focus particularly on *undeleting* the post. Considering **THREE** high-quality answers (4+31+40 upvotes) that **already existed** I find it ridiculous (yes, this is my rant) to delete this OLD post. If there is any misuse of this site at all, the deletion, in this particular case, IS misuse of the privilege of votes. [mod redacted]

Comment: Bringing up other users in this form is out-of-line, in general. In the specific case it's also **highly** misleading. (I removed it.)

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted (mod)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3292066/revisions)

Please consider casting the final undelete vote to this post:

[Which among the given series converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292066/9464)

This is not a zero effort post: OP has ruled out some choices for the problem and has reduced the problem to a simpler one. This is a good attempt. Also, @Theo Bendit has posted a well written answer.

---

Mod comment (quid): I deleted it as the question remains unclear in its formulation. As such it has the potential to create confusion and in any case the mathematics is well-known and in one way or the other certainly on the site. It is good that OP apparently got competent help. This does not alter the fact hat preserving the thread as is in my opinion does not ad value to the site and to the contrary degrades it (adding a confusing question).  If somebody want to preserve the answer they should have improved the question, or create a separate one. That's still an option.

Comment: The asker has not ruled out several choices for the problem.  The problem is not a multiple choice question.  Rather, they were asked to examine each of those four series, and determine which converge.  If anything, the question is four distinct true / false questions (making it "Too Broad").

Comment: Moreover, you claim that it is not a zero effort question.  Even if I agreed with you regarding the idea that "showing effort" is, in and of itself, sufficient context, I disagree about the effort which has been shown.  The question is ultimately about one of the four series being presented, and there is no work shown for that series.  For the remaining three, the asker claims to have already found appropriate counter-examples, but don't actually show any of that effort.  Claiming to have done something is not the same as demonstrating it.

Comment: *"The problem is not a multiple choice question. ... which converge."* One could turn almost all the multiple choice problems into non-multiple-choice ones in such a way.  The rest of your comments are based on this biased assumption. *"the asker claims to have already found appropriate counter-examples, but don't actually show any of that effort."* OP summarized as partial work that three items haven been done and now he/she focuses on item (c). Not guilty. The strong action of deletion of this post is unreasoning.

Comment: The question consists of four different T/F questions.  It is not a single multiple choice question.  There are four different questions here.  Determining the truth or falsity of parts (a), (b), and (d) does absolutely nothing to shed light on (c), especially considering that the asker doesn't actually show any of their work, but simply states that they have already completed those parts.  It lacks context and is too broad.  It was rightfully closed and deleted.

Comment: One has to wonder how they could show b yet not c. Makes one wonder of the merits of their undisclosed approaches.  The paraphrase in meta OP is false as pointed out by @XanderHenderson and your reply is strange in that the critique of you paraphrase (not even the main OP) was not that the question is a multiple choice question but rather that there is not partial progress to the question asked. The best one can say is that the question is *not* 'several questions asked in one' (contrary to what one might think) and the Q provides some limited context by giving related problems they can solve.

Comment: I'd say if they had sketched their solutions to those they can solve, it might be sufficient context. As is, it does not add all that much, especially since the partial progress is implausible. Indeed it appears it is partly false as they might have misunderstood the question (the meaning of necessarily). Of course, it's anyone's guess since they do not provide the claimed solutions. Clear case of actual lack of context; we cannot identify the extent of the  problems of OP.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened, closed, deleted, undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3297280/revisions)

Please consider undeleting the following question:

[Is $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Gamma(x)}}\mathrm dx$ a rational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297280/what-about-irrationality-of-int-1-infty-frac1-sqrt-gammax-mathrm-dx)

I agree on the reason for closing this question. Even though the post is somewhat strange in its wording it appears to be overall interesting for the community (as the upvotes outweigh the downvotes resulting in a balance of $+6$). Additionally, the integral appearing in the question is strongly related to the Fransén-Robertson Constant and might be of help as future reference for this topic (as a number of relevant posts is also linked with the deleted one).

---

The question has got deleted *again*. I have still my POV listed above and I would like to hear the reason for re-deleting the question.

Comment: I voted to undelete, but I have to say, it's a highly undermotivated question. I could write down a thousand expressions evaluating to real numbers, and ask for each, whether it's rational, without giving any reason to think it is, or any reason to be particularly interested in whether it is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have to agree on this issue. And indeed, the motivation is clearly missing but what remains is a relation to an actual known constant, which is from my POV the only thing which makes this question worth keeping.

Comment: OP has shown no interest in the question, having refused the invitation to improve it. mrtaurho, I suggest you post an improved version of the question, and your answer, so the material won't be lost.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, for your response. I will do so, as soon as I have time! :)

Comment: I see, mrt, that you never did get the time, which is a shame, since (as I commented on the question the other day) I don't think the main objections to the question have been addressed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was rather busy. Additionally, I was (and still am) rather confused what to do about this question. It has been reopened two times and so posting a new question (even an appropriate) would be in fact a duplicate. So I decided to wait for now.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed as duplicate, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3285270/revisions)

Please consider to undelete this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285270/515527).

The OP brings some background about the problem and is just trying to find an easy solution. The one provided by me looks quite unknown (as it seems from the comments and the answers) thus I think it can be of future help if the question is undeleted.

Comment: It's good form to  disclose that one has an answer on the post oneself.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of many other questions on MSE.  While I don't think that it is worth keeping (it brings nothing new to the table), if it is going to be kept, it should be closed as a duplicate.  I left comments indicating a couple of potential dupe targets.

Comment: On the contrary I believe it brings something new to the table. My solution is different than any other from all the linked posts.

Comment: @Zacky In that case your answer will stand its ground as an answer to the duplicate target as well, and you might consider relocating it there! Just by posting a new answer, the thread of your choice will be bumped to the front page, meaning that many viewers will see it and be able to vote it. <- This could be my template reply to all the users who are sad about a deletion of a duplicate. They can easily save their work this way!

Comment: "Partial fraction without defraction for an integral" What the heck does that mean? Is *defraction* really a word? Why has no one edited that title to something intelligible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that no one had edited the title into something intelligible because no one actually knows what the asker intended.  That is part of the problem with the question (aside from the fact that it is a duplicate).

Comment: @Zacky Honestly, I think that Jyrki's advice is good advice.  Indeed, I think that your answer would be a better fit for one of the other questions, if for no other reason than the current question *specifically* asks about partial fraction decomposition, while the others don't.  Your answer would be a *better fit* for a different question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson something looks off. You said that it brings nothing new to the table and it's not worth to be kept, you even ranted on how my answer isn't a "pedagogical". Are you sure that you honestly believe that is a good advice?

Comment: I also wrote in my pre-edit for OP: "Since this is just for your training, here's a more different approach for it. If it doesn't fit for you, I will delete it (it doesn't use any partial fractions)", when OP commented I think I received a positive feedback about it from OP.// Indeed it doesn't answer the exact question, but another answer (which got accepted by OP) shows a way with partial fractions. I only posted my answer after I saw it, and after the comments (from some high-rep users) who encouraged OP to not look for a better way?

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

---

Please consider reopening the question:

[Theorems with the greatest impact on group theory as a whole](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476972/10513) (note that the question is about *infinite* group theory).

It is currently closed as "primarily opinion-based...Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

I disagree with this close reason:

1. As the 11-upvoted comment states, "This is a good question and does not deserve to be closed. Understanding the theorems that are considered most important in any field of math is an important step towards understanding that field." The theory of infinite groups is an area of active research, and is not covered specifically in an undergraduate course on groups. In fact, many results covered in undergraduate group theory are not applicable to infinite groups (Sylow's theorems are a good example, and are mentioned in the question).
2. The boiler-plate reason is that "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise". There are currently two answers; both are based on facts and references, and both are by professional mathematicians (one is by Andrés E. Caicedo and the other is by me, and indeed my research is in infinite group theory).

Finally, I want to end with a comment: The question is almost 6 years old (5 years and 355 days, or so). The close votes here seem to have occurred after a re-tag (which I presume happened after I linked to the question elsewhere). Closing reasonably-upvoted old questions like this has the potential to discourage improvements to old question and to discourage linking to old questions.

Comment: re 3. The question had been closed back then already.

Comment: I've edited 3 (it wasn't really a reason to reopen). Yes, it was closed and then it was reopened.

Comment: So, the question was already controversial back then. Which is documented by the first comment at score +12. Don't create false narratives;

Comment: @quid I don't see what was false about my narrative (or that I have written a narrative). My the purpose of the final paragraph (in both current and original form) was to point out the age of the question and what closing such old questions could mean. I did not mean to suggest that the question was not originally "controversial".

Comment: Further, professional mathematician or not (what type of argument is that by the way?), one of the answers does not even seem to answer the question at all. // The (at least implied) narrative is that after years were this question was welcome  suddenly people took issue with the question, which is incorrect or at least incomplete. To not even mention this is careless at best.

Comment: People can (and should) look at the question and make up their own mind. I do not believe that it is my job here to give them *all* the relevant information (because what is relevant differs from person to person - for example, you focused on the close votes, but the question has only one downvote). Re "professional mathematician": my point was what I have the specific expertise to answer this question (and ignore the other answer if you wish).

Comment: It might not be your job to give all the relevant information. But I do believe that integrity ought to dictate not to give a highly biased description of the situation.

Comment: The above being said, I do not have a particular issue with the question itself. I'd say  it still falls on the good  side in the good subjective-bad subjective dichotomy, and the questioner had made an effort to steer clear of the pitfalls of the superlative. I cast the final vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider undeleting and reopening this elementary question: [On proving $\sum_{k=1}^{2^n+1} \frac{1}{k} > \frac{n}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322635/9464)

OP had his/her thoughts on the problem and also added an attempt for verification in the post after interaction in comments with others. This question has also been edited.

Comment: Did you check to see whether it's a duplicate? Looks to me like the kind of question that would have been asked before.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I can only find a [similar one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1520295/9464). Since I have a very narrow definition of duplicate, I don't consider it as a duplicate to the mentioned one. Others may probably find closer one. One may close it as a duplicate *if* one does find one. But I would object the strong action of deletion of this post.

Comment: Asker account deleted, answer a brief hint, the argument definitely on the site numerous times, the specific variant a bit artificial. Why in the world should we keep that?

Comment: @quid Why the account deleted is a 'point to count' to support the deletion?

Comment: @Isa sometimes arguments are made along the lines of: "Maybe the post is not great, but OP made an effort and we should not discourage them via deletion." There are also glimpses of that in this meta post. Once the account is gone that caries rather less wait. Differently, it's not so much that it's a point for deletion, but it's a point less against deletion.

Comment: @quid I don't get it. Your previous comment suggested like 4 'bad' things about the post, so why to keep that.

Comment: @Isa I asked why we would want to keep the post. A common argument given is that we keep it not to penalize the person that asked it. This argument does not really apply in this case. Another argument is that the answer is good; Again does not apply. Still another argument we keep it for others users. But it seems unlikely to be useful, as the argument in principle is on the site numerous times and the specific version is a bit strange in a non interesting way.  Thus, I still am at a loss why anyone  would bother to keep that particular post. Surely there are plenty of better deleted posts.

Comment: @quid I may agree with you the day I had 10k :) with your  mentioned points: _answer a brief hint, the argument definitely on the site numerous times, the specific variant a bit artificial._ Except your first point: account deleted. I don't see any possibility of me agreeing with that point.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the question seems rather close to [Prove this inequality: $\frac n2 \le \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac1{2^n - 1} \le n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366267). However, it's not suitable for merging - the bounds for sum are different, the other post has an answer rather similar to the one already posted.

Answer (score 0):

> [Undeleted, reopened, closed-as-duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3247145/revisions)

Please consider undeleting and reopening the edited post: [How can one show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}=e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3247145/9464)

The user had difficulties in articulating his/her own thoughts. The elementary question in the post is clear. It is also clear from OP's comment and picture attached to the original post what the asker was thinking.

Comment: You should disclose the fact that you made *significant* edits to the question after it was deleted.  The question itself is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382928/) (and probably has other, better dupe targets; I just happen to know the one I linked to since I interacted with it two years ago).  I don't see a reason to undelete it.

Comment: I posted a link to an exact duplicate under that thread. Pointless to reopen I think.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3329506/revisions)

I have edited my post [“Most intuitive” average of $P$ for all $x\in A \cap [a,b]$, where $A$ is countable and the average is unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329506/most-intuitive-average-of-p-unique-for-all-countable-x-in-a-cap-a-b) and waited for five days. Is it clear what I am asking? If not, could any suggestions be made?

*Edit:*

Users are trying to delete my post. If a post is unclear why would you to delete it? This is Math Stack Exchange, not Math Overflow.

I made more edits. Is it clear now? If not please explain. Offer one hint.

If you are wondering why I have a hard time explaining my post it’s because I have not mastered the concepts needed to explain this? I don’t care if this is worthless or gold. I don’t care if anyone steals this. I just want some guidance and most of my professors are too busy.

*Second Edit:*

I shortened the post to one question and a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Rahul commented on 21 August that you had a couple of equals signs where there should have been element-of symbols. You never engaged with that correction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Correction made. Is there anything else?

Comment: I don't know. It's not my area, and it's long enough to be a PhD thesis. Sorry, but I won't be going through it in detail.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Users are trying to delete my post. Is this acceptable?

Comment: As Gerry has pointed out, your post is very long. Have you thought in splitting the content and ask many questions instead of only one?

Comment: Or you could also start a bounty :) I think you can set one for +150

Comment: I really don't know what to tell you. Maybe what's unclear is which of these many questions is the question:

What is the "most intuitive" average of $P(x)$...?

What do you think of these properties/examples? Are they reasonable? If so, how can we create a measure that suits these intuitions? And if not, how can we create a measure that suits better intuitions/intuitive examples/properties?

So far, are my intuitive properties reasonable? If not, could we find the most "intuitive" Folner Sequence of any countable set? What would be the measure and average be?

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3349269/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen this post:

[How to show $13\left(x^{2}+1\right)+\sqrt{2\left(x^{4}+1\right)}+62 x-\frac{45\left(x^{2}-1\right)}{\ln x}>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3349269/9464)

Context for the question was added upon request by the asker, which has been lifted to the post.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3304930/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen this post: [How can one integrate $\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^4(x^2+1)} dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3304930/9464)

OP wants to calculate this integral. He/she is not asking for a solution to this integral *per se* but states in the post his/her frustration on partial fraction decomposition (PFD) of the integrand. OP even has attempted to use something else (u-substitution) to solve this problem. [Benard's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3305010/9464) addresses the difficulties of PFD without divulging the complete solution to OP.

Answer (score 0):

### Reopened

Please reopen [In chapter 7 exercise 23 of baby Rudin (3rd edition), where does the given recurrence of polynomials come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613090).

It was closed for the understandable reason that it lacked sufficient detail to be comprehensible by someone without Rudin's book to hand, and not only that, the reference to the book was inaccurate! But the poster, a newcomer, has carefully edited the question to provide more detail, and to correct the erroneous reference. Then, after waiting for five days, he asked politely if there was anything more he needed to do. Meanwhile, another poster had provided full details in a comment - whose length even provoked some controversy!

I don't think anything more needs to be done (unless someone with moderator privileges wants to edit the comment into the question).

The question has two reopen votes already.

Comment: You certainly have those moderator privileges to edit the question, if you want to do that yourself. I also believe the length isn't the problem with that comment, but the fact that it contains those superfluous "begin quote" and "end quote". Perhaps by flagging a moderator is willing to edit that out, since otherwise it's an useful comment.

Comment: @Zacky Thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659982/does-the-law-of-cosines-contradict-pythagorass-theorem

This question was undeleted by 10 people then subsequently deleted and locked by a moderator. I request that such a heavy handed, unilateral action be undone since clearly many people disagree.

Comment: Also the subject of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30914/8269

Comment: Very poor post that is thankfully deleted.  You should have considered keeping this poor answer deleted as well, @Matt.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

I would like to see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3677292) reopened. It is certainly not a duplicate of the previous question as here a double sum have to be evaluated. A partial answer ("the inner sum") which was considered in a comment as "promising" is in fact not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Closed, Deleted**

Please consider **undeleting** and **reopening** the post (question & answer both): [Why integral of $dx$ is not $∫dxdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684878/why-integral-of-dx-is-not-int-dx-dx/3685330#3685330).

This is a basic question came to OP's mind on the subject. There are a lot of people who have the same doubt about the fact. It will be very much helpful for those. Also my answer was accepted by OP and also being appreciated by the other members on this site. I think those question and answer are suitable for the site. I strongly recommend to undelete the post.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3504128/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen [Proof of $(1 + \delta)^{1/2 + \delta}(1- \delta)^{1/2 - \delta} > 1$ for $0 < \delta \leq 1/2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504128/proof-of-1-delta1-2-delta1-delta1-2-delta-1-for-0-d/).  Let it be known that I answered the question.  The question should now have sufficient context.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3687760/revisions)

Please consider this question [Prove that $\gcd\left(n^{a}+1, n^{b}+1\right)$ divides $n^{\gcd(a, b)}+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687760/prove-that-gcd-leftna1-nb1-right-divides-n-gcda-b1) to be reopened.  I answered the question.  And more context has been given.

Comment: You should, perhaps, note that you answered this question, and received a bounty for that answer.  Hence you are not a disinterested third party.

Comment: What's the point of undeleting the post after it is reopened? You have nothing to request.

Comment: @ArcticChar I didn't undelete it.

Comment: @ArcticChar I actually rather disagree. A record of the activity should be kept at least for some time.

Comment: I guess Shubhrajit just deleted another request, @quid (I don't have 10k to see what exacfly happened)

Comment: @ArcticChar I have deleted my request. Always my requests get downvotes. I answered and invested time for them. Why can't I just request for questions to be reopened which are answered by me? I don't want to make any further requests. I started to hate MSE for many reasons including bad and unfriendly behaviour from users.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya You do get positive net votes for quite a number of your request, and quite a lot of your request resulted in reopening/undeleting, so I don't see why you seem to be upset....

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya While it is fine to request reopening/undeleting of posts that you are involved, we suggest users to explain why actions should be taken. The reason "I have answered the questions/ I have spent time on it" is not a very strong reason.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3765168/revisions)

I propose to reopen [Which Combinations of Roots of Unity are Zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765168/which-combinations-of-roots-of-unity-are-zero), which is a perfectly phrased and interesting question of which I have no idea why it had been closed. There was some debate about whether the questioner meant to ask for real or integer linear combinations of the roots of unity, which is now settled by an edit – it’s about integer combinations. (But even the version with real coefficients would be interesting and worthy of this site, in my opinion.)

It would also be nice to hear from the ones who have closed the question or are in favour of leaving it closed as to why this question should be closed. I have not the slightest idea.

Comment: Hm. Reopened. That was fast. : )

Comment: When considering why a question was closed, you might do well to look at the edit history, and look at [the version of the post which people voted to close](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3765168/1).

Answer (score 0):

> [**Undeleted, Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2922411/revisions)

I would like to request that this thread be <strike>undeleted</strike> <strike>and</strike> reopened: "[If $\#(S)<\#(\Bbb N)$, then prove that $S$ is finite, without using the Axiom of Choice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922411/if-s-bbb-n-then-s-is-finite-without-using-the-axiom-of-choice)."  I did not answer the question, but I think the thread is useful for people to learn which argument relies on the Axiom of Choice, and which does not.

Comment: I am confused why my undelete vote wasn't there.  Maybe I forgot to vote myself. What a blunder!  I might have forgotten to vote to reopen too.  However, I might also have voted to reopen,  but the reopen vote might have also expired.

Answer (score 0):

[Why is the the number of regular payments with a balloon payment n-1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791360/why-is-the-the-number-of-regular-payments-with-a-balloon-payment-n-1)

Again, people who are unfamiliar with actuarial mathematics are taking legitimate questions in this area and closing them as not being about mathematics.

Let me be clear:  either remove the actuarial mathematics tag entirely and specifically prohibit this entire topic as being suitable, or stop closing questions that are well-understood by those of us who actually know the material.

Comment: Ross Millikan has commented in that post, explaining how they think it is not about Math. Do you care to explain why Ross is wrong?

Comment: This seems like the wrong place to talk about how well understood, or not, the actuarial-science tag is -- you should write a question for meta where it'll be seen by more people :)

Comment: Regardless of one's perspective on actuarial mathematics, it's important to note that the OP doesn't provide the key definition of what they're not understanding here. Providing definitions is a basic step in providing context for questions on MSE and the fact it's missing here is why I voted to close this question. Until that's fixed, I don't think it should be reopened.

Comment: The question has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Locked, Unlocked](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3809115/revisions)**

Please reopen this thread: [Given $n$ integers $p_0, p_1,...,p_{n-1}$, what is the smallest possible degree of a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(i) = p_i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809115/given-n-integers-p-0-p-1-p-n-1-what-is-the-smallest-possible-degree).  I answered it (although it is now a community wiki post), but the thread is very much self-answered.

I think the thread is useful.  There are many questions of the form: "Given a part of a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}$, determine the value of $a_m$ for some integer $m\geq n$."  I personally dislike such questions because the given information is not sufficient, but with the added assumption that the sequence is a polynomial sequence (of degree at most $n-1$), then such questions become answerable, and we can use some idea from the thread above to establish answers to such questions.

Comment: Interesting to see a moderator joining an edit war...

Comment: @ArcticChar  That is why I think the moderator's actions were inappropriate (whence the complaint in Math Mods' Office).

Answer (score 0):

> **Closed. Edited. Left closed. Deleted.**

I think this post (it was closed!)

[Alice Through the Looking-Glass: is there a mathematical description of this infinite regression paradox?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819555/alice-through-the-looking-glass-is-there-a-mathematical-description-of-this-inf)

is answerable now and is about mathematics.

I added images and a formal example.

The question is about some properties/abnormal behaviours of functions (/transformations). I want to know if there are known examples, if they are studied, if they are formulated and etc.

I am aware that it's not the best and most usual and most non-controversial question... but I think it has its own good sides!

Maybe someone can help to reformulate it so it won't be connected to Carroll's book? (Although the basic and most general premise is heavily connected)

I want to ask about functions/transformations that can lead to similar abnormal/paradoxical behaviours or results and if there're famous examples or how mathematicians deal with them and etc.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**

[vertices on a path](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3919051/290189) received one answer, but the question asker deleted his own question.  This is an abuse of the system.  Please undelete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reopening [How to intuitively understand the $n$-dimensional cube as the dimension grows large](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3955791/3736) (or suggest a more suitable duplicate target—I was unable to find one). I would like to add an answer that would be inappropriate at either of the suggested duplicates, which are both mostly concerned with visualizing 4-dimensional cubes and not on developing intuition for large dimensional cubes.

Comment: Um.... weird situation. While I agree with the OP that the duplicate do not compare the $n$-balls and $n$-cubes, they actually accept an answer that IMO completely ignore this aspect.

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't know why the OP decided to accept the one answer that was given before the question got closed, but they might still be open to reading additional answers. Even if not, future readers with the same question might be interested in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, closed, deleted, undeleted, redeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2991071/revisions)

I nominate [Solve the recurrence $\sqrt {x_n} − 5 \sqrt {x _{n−1} }+ 6\sqrt {x_{n−2}} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2991071) for undeletion because OP has self-deleted his post shortly after receiving an answer. That's rude to the answerer.

Comment: I agree that the question should not have been deleted by the original asker, and would have voted to undelete had I seen this before the question was undeleted.  That being said, it is a pretty low quality question, and would like to now nominate it for closure and (if it is not improved) eventual deletion.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Agreed and updated the status of my answer.

Comment: It is inconceivable this question is undeleted. Even the answer is pretty low-quality.

Comment: I find that revision history really surprising : one (now removed) user voted to undelete and then close the question, OP initially self-deleted the question but 5 days later voted to undelete after the second deletion, and now you've voted to undelete and then redelete the day after. Pardon my French, but WTF?

Answer (score -1):

> **[Undeleted, reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2997340/revisions)**

I humbly request undeletion and reopening of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997340/), if you see fit to do so, because

a) reasons for closing should be derived from the question itself and not from [speculation about the skills of the asker](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47839103#47839103).

b) the given [reasons for closing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47838037#47838037) are incorrect - while the question sails close to an open problem, it asks a different but related question - it asks if the open problem (which relates to a series of polynomials) can be extended to its limit point.

c) the time from entering the reopen queue to deletion was less than two hours, denying any who might have been interested in its reopening the opportunity to declare the same.

d) moreover, I think others will find the question and any prospective answers of interest and value.

Comment: The time from entering the reopen queue to deletion may have been short, but the question had been on hold for five days already. As for the close reasons, I'll note that 2 of the close voters did not use "not math". I think that personnally I would have probably voted to close as unclear what you're asking, because on a first reading I honestly had no idea what you were talking about.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, but the reopen request followed an edit which increased focus on the actual question and removed the motivation for it, when I believe the question's motivation was almost certainly the cause for the down votes and closure in the first place, rather than the question itself which stands alone.

Comment: By the way, I think the most recent edit on your question (post-deletion) already makes the question more interesting. It only consists of adding a Wikipedia link, but that link already explains some of the context better than your question (for example, I hadn't realized that you were talking about polynomial bijections $\mathbb{N}^k \to\mathbb{N}$, but maybe that's just me).

Comment: For what it's worth, the reopen review was completed before the deletion, as one can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1111878).

Comment: @ArnaudD. good point, although predominantly the same users. Is there a better review link that shows timings etc.? I thought I saw one before but can never re-find it.

Comment: There's the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2997340/timeline), but I don't know if it is as detailed as you'd want. (By the way, there's another [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) about how to find it).

Comment: Setting aside all other issues, there are some obvious (and, I think, easily correctible) errors in your question's key equation, stating the F-P conjecture: the right hand side has no $y$ in it, and the index of summation $n$ appears nowhere in the expression being summed.  I'm pretty sure you want the summation to go from $k=1$ to $n$, not $n=1$ to $k$, with $f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ on the left hand side, not $f_k(y)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra thank-you.  I think I intended $y$ to be the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_k\}$ and yes, I agree I appear to have exchanged an $n$ with a $k$ but alas no edits are allowed on a deleted post so I can't correct it :(

Comment: @RobertFrost That's surprising. In any case, I've just done the correction.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks and you even got the $f_n$ I thought might get missed.

Comment: What do you mean by "timings"? The time of the review is there exactly. As usual, hover over the time stamp to get a resolution to the second.

Comment: @quid thank-you. That probably covers it although I can only see a deleted post on desktop so I'll have to check later

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank-you for the edit.  A reopen vote would be greatly appreciated (only if you think it appropriate). Else the deleters will reverse the undeleters!

Answer (score -1):

> **[Deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed as duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2665553/revisions)**

Please reopen [Calculating the summation$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665553) because it's *not* an elementary question and OP has tried checking the proposition using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: In my opinion it's very poor style to reignite this after month without mentioning any of the earlier activity in which you even were involved. Thus, I locked the post for now.

Comment: I'm puzzled. A "content dispute" notice was lifted in March 2018. The content has not been altered since then. So it seems strange to lock it for "content dispute" now, @quid. [I guess I should mention that I was involved in earlier activity.]

Comment: @GerryMyerson Are your really puzzled or are you just searching an argument? First, the content of the post *was also not changed* between the first locking and the first unlocking. Second, the lock was not lifted in the sense of somebody lifting it, it simply expired. It was not reinstated as there seemed no need back then about a year ago. Then half a year ago, there was one more round of undelete-delete but it fizzled out quickly. Now somebody wants to go back to this again, indeed without any further changes, simply picking up the del-undel again. To prevent this, I locked it.

Comment: Third, it might be relevant to note that the lock was "lifted" *while the post was deleted.* Thus, if consistency is the concern of course I should lock it again now. I could also have it become undeleted and then personally delete it again. Last time around some where keen on locks being used. So, there you go. Of course that's not fine for you now either, presumably because it does not cater to your personal preferences.

Comment: To sum up, I locked it to prevent the delete-undelete cycle being restarted. By now the question was deleted four times. Plus it is an odd situation, in that it first got siginificantly improved by a third party only for this then being undone If anything should happen likely a completely new version should  be posted. This would be a reasonable thing to do if preserving content is the actual goal. Of course if playing un-del games should be the goal... thus locked. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @quid, when I write that I am puzzled, please do me the courtesy of accepting that I really am puzzled. I'm puzzled not so much by the locking but by the phrase, "Content dispute", when there was no change in content. Had the locking notice said "Prevent delete/undelete cycle" I don't know that I would have made any comment. Does a moderator have the option of inserting custom-made locking notices, or is "Content dispute" the only phrase available? Also, I always assumed that when a moderator locked a question, the question stayed locked until a moderator decided it was time to unlock it....

Comment: ....I didn't know that locks expired of their own accord after a week. I've been here almost a decade, and I'm still learning how the place works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the list of reasons is fixed (we can ask for additions in principle but not spontaneously)  "content dispute" is the one commonly used in this case, others are "off topic comments", "contest question", "cw answer", "historical significance". We can lock for an hour, for a day, for a week, or permanently. Usually one tries to avoid permanent locks.

Comment: Probably it's worth mentioning that there already [is one answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-07-2018/28017#28017) in this thread about the same question.

Comment: @quid, thanks for the explanation about length of locks. It's not possible, is it, for non-moderators to see what length a moderator has chosen when that moderator locks a question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson indeed I think that's not possible.

Answer (score -1):

> **Deleted by a moderator**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648787/how-to-check-if-a-a-relatively-small-number-is-prime-4-digits-at-most) was closed and deleted with the reason given "This question is missing context or other detail".  However the author of the question explained both his educational background (he is an undergraduate) and his motivation for the question (it was information that wasn't covered in his degree).

This information is sufficient context to give an answer, indeed I can't think of any further context that a person asking the question could add that would result in a better answer.

Comment: The body does not even contain the question. That question-post is poor, and the thread of very limited value overall. The answers being pretty terse and not giving enough detail. // Added: Given the comment below I'll add that it was not I that deleted it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if a post was deleted by a moderator - like [in this case](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1648787/revisions) - the deletion cannot be reversed by regular users. (Of course, voting your posts still can show to which extent users support undeletion - and if there is some support, perhaps moderators might have a look at the the question again.)

Comment: @quid can you explain what is poor about the question?  Broadly speaking pen and paper methods of factoring numbers is a subject that the site should have coverage of.

Comment: I already mentioned one shortcoming. Further and more drastically, the question does not contain any relevant thought of the OP or even just explanation what they want that information for. For example, do they realize that one can easily recognize that some number are not prime? How would they approach the problem for two digit numbers? Or something else, would all make the question better. That said, the question would arguably be saveable. But what for? The answers are low quality. I'd prefer somebody, say my students, won't find any information here rather than those answers.

Comment: Fortunately similar information is available in other and better threads. In my opinion, the site is quite simply better without this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Please undelete https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2192864/290189 because OP has self-deleted his question one minute after receiving an answer from me.  This is an abuse of the system.

Comment: OP shouldn't have deleted it, but what a miserable excuse for a question! With all due respect, I don't think you should have answered it, not without first getting OP to bring it up to standards.

Comment: The question was deleted one minute after receiving an answer, but this request was posted more than two years later. If the asker deleted the question to cover up the fact that they got help, then they already succeeded. I don't really see a reason to undelete this, because it would just get closed and deleted again.

Answer (score -1):

Please unmark the duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245142/area-of-a-spherical-cap-crossing-an-intersection). I have clearly said that my question has nothing to do with duplicate one. I am asking totally different thing and the duplicate question's answer does not help me at all. It is also an unique question which follows m previous question.

Comment: I don't believe the relationship between the Questions is quite so simple as one "has nothing to do with" the other.  Both involve intersections between two spherical caps, although you might not have visualized your problem in this way.  There might still be a further problem in stating the area in terms of how you parameterized the spherical region, I grant, but it would be worth understanding the solution of the proposed duplicate to try restating the area given there in your terms.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, locked and merged with duplicate (mod)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3268621/revisions)

Please consider undeleting: [How to count the number of good permutations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268621/9464)

This is not a duplicate and has a good answer.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760360/how-many-permutations-of-1-ldots-n-exist-such-that-none-of-them-contain ?

Answer (score -1):

Please consider undeleting this post: [Integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln (2\sin(\frac{x}{2}))dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270076/9464)

Whether the asker should articulate more details in "I've tried some substitutions" could be debatable for reopening the post; I do not think it should be deleted. There have been two answers, one of which has 11 upvotes.

Comment: The question was on hold for a week without modification before it was deleted.  The answers are fine, but standard, and don't rise to the level of exceptional.  I see no reason to undelete this question.  The asker clearly got what they wanted, and I don't see that question providing any lasting value to the site.

Comment: The lasting value to the site, like many other posts, is that there are two good answers to a tricky calculus question, which is not only useful for the asker but also future readers.

Comment: The first part of your reply to me does not contradict what I said: you say that there are two good answers, I said that there are no *exceptional* answers.  As to use to future readers: I disagree.  This is a specific integral which can be analyzed using relatively standard techniques.  The question itself is not terribly searchable (it is only going to come up if someone wants to deal with that specific integral (e.g. they are assigned the same problem as a homework exercise, and are trying to cheat), and the answers are not of any general interest (they are standard, but not general).

Comment: Disagree. "This is a specific integral which can be analyzed using relatively standard techniques. ... the answers are not of any general interest " does not justify the deletion. MSE is not MO: most, if not all, of questions here "can be analyzed using relatively standard techniques". For instance, [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3143084/9464) that has two good answers, the accepted one written in detail nicely by you,  is a rather "standard" one. I would certainly not vote to delete such posts. (In case of any possible confusion: this is NOT sarcasm.)

Comment: It is funny that you pick that example.  I downvoted that question, and [voted to close it](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1167289).  It was not closed, and the other answers were, in my opinion poor answers (as they failed to address the key point, which is that an induction proof is needed *somewhere*).  If the question is not going to be closed and deleted, it should at least have a correct answer.  I would still be happy to see that question closed, and would not object to its deletion---my answer is nothing special, and doesn't (IMO) rise to the level of exceptional.

Comment: Moreover, applying standard results to a specific problem is very different from demonstrating the correctness of standard results then leaving it to the reader to apply that result to their specific problem.

Comment: Well, (1) I have done my proposal for undeletion. Readers can make their own decisions. (2) I will object strongly the post I just mentioned being deleted, considering the quality of your exposition and egreg's good answer. (How do you find the review history by the way?) (3) ... have to leave now.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of one or more of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815762/show-that-if-a-le-1-then-int2-pi-0-log1-aei-theta-d-theta-0 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889902/can-we-find-a-point-m-on-the-unit-circle-such-that-prod-i-1n-ma-i-1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679233/integral-int-02-pi-logei-theta-1d-theta and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656431/zeroes-of-a-non-elementary-integral and also comes up in any question containing the name "Clausen".

Comment: @Jack To find the review history I go to the timeline of the post and then click on the link to the review event there. I don't know if there's a quicker way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: having read your links one by one, I would probably not called the post a duplicate of those, although they are *related* to the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function). (Never known this before, thanks for mentioning it.)

Comment: @Brahadeesh: Thanks for that. One can indeed use https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3143084/timeline

Comment: It's funny how those who voted to close/ delete are here on this site for a while, and even claim to know that the question is easily searchable. Yet, instead of trying to mark it as duplicate, they simply delete it. Also it's quite bold for a single group of people (CRUDE users) to decide that it has no value for this site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I wrote above in the third person since you're not the only one who believes that, but since you commented it here, can you please tell me why haven't you tried to mark it as duplicate (if it's easily searchable) and simply decided to remove the content? (maybe there's a reason that I'm missing).

Comment: @Zacky I have previously commented that the *first* question one asks should be "is this a good question?"  If the answer is "no", then the question should be closed and deleted.  If the answer is "yes", *then* it is worth looking for dupe targets.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270076/9464) is not a good question, so it was rightly closed and deleted.  Moreover, I don't see anyone claiming that dupe targets easily searchable, only that the answers use standard techniques, and do not rise to the level of "exceptional".

Comment: Thanks for your view. IMO it's not up to me or you to decide whether the answer is exceptional. Personally I see the integral quit treivial, however I also remember back when I joined MSE I struggled with such things too. So just because it's not exceptional for me (or for you) that doesn't mean that there aren't users who find the method impressive, after all this isn't MathOverflow. I also stand by this: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: -> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!. 
And the answers provided there are definetly good. Thus those who deleted it violated the "rule" that I copy-pasted. // A little off-topic, but I hope that you are aware that who asked the question couldn't care less if the question is deleted since he/she already took the informatio needed. Thus by deleting the question, it even helps that user instead of penalizing them.

Comment: -> Of course, the posts around here aren't only for those who asked, but for the whole community. I fail to see why there ins't a way to penalize the users (for example a "question ban" if the questions previously posted are bad), but instead the decision that CRUDE users took is to penalize the whole community by erasing good content. Anyway, it's pointless if I type here in the comments, soon I will try to make a meta post about something related to this. Thanks for your time and have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2946298/revisions)

Please undelete and consider reopening this post: 
[Show this equation has every positive integer as solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2946298/9464)

OP did give his thoughts. NOT a no-context question. And there are two good answers.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3048677/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this post: [How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 3} (x^2-5x+4)^{x-3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048677/9464), which is clearly not a zero-effort question.

Comment: You say that the question should be opened because it is "clearly not a zero-effort question."  This seems to imply that the question was closed because it "lacks effort".  However, "lacks effort" is not one of the close reasons used on MSE. Indeed, I see that question was closed for "lacking *context*".  For example, a description of what theory the asker is familiar with and what course they are taking.  Are they expecting a computation involving $\varepsilon$s and $\delta$s?  L'Hospital's rule?  What?  The question should be deleted.

Comment: Moreover, examining the comments attached to that question, it is not even clear where the function being discussed is meant to be defined.  Is it a real function with a very "hole-y" domain?  or a complex function, in which case one needs to consider branches of the logarithm?  It is not a good question.

Answer (score -1):

> **Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, delete (mod)**

Please undelete this post [Map subset of a group to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058161/9464)

This is not a trivial exercise. It has a very detailed thoughtful answer by @Arturo Magidin.

---

Mod comment (quid): I deleted this one, as the question-post is still not clarified and the thread including the answer post is a back and forth. Like: "It cannot be this, you may mean that. Oh, now you said it's about something else." I am glad that OP was helped, but  I think there is no archival value to this in its current form. As usual, those that want to can extract whatever they think is valuable, via edits or moving of content.

Comment: If you plan to keep saying things like "Redeleted (6/17/19) by a same group of users. One initiated three times the delete votes and one voted three times to delete this post. – Jack Jun 17 at 22:01"  you might refrain from voting to undelete repeatedly, especially on posts where there was not recast delete vote prior to that. (There is now though.)

Comment: There has been no action whatsoever (to my knowledge) from mods or the system to prevent casting/initiating deletion votes for some particular posts over and over again by mostly same group of users. It is not difficult to count such instances. I assume from such observation that repeated voting is not discouraged in general. "If you plan to keep saying things like" This is an absurd and **highly misleading** comment from a moderator: your quoted comment refers to [one particular proposal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30360/9464) and I have never said it somewhere else.

Comment: I take it you do not plan to keep saying things like the one I quoted, then. Well you did say "On the other hand, what one can see from the timeline is that a user voted to delete the posts twice while there are people who hold different opinions have already voted to undelete and reopen the post." which also raises double-voting in a critical way.

Comment: There has been no action whatsoever from mods or the system to prevent casting/initiating undeletion votes for some particular posts over and over again by mostly same group of users either.

Comment: @quid I think a mod deletion was *highly improper* here. Sad to see you once again forcing your *personal* opinions onto the community. These decisions should be made by the *community* - not an individual.

Comment: @Bill after about ten changes of status I think it's about time somebody decides it one way or the other. Visibly the community did not reach a solution.

Comment: @quid "Changes of status" are not harming anything. There have been more in the past and they eventually settled down.

Comment: @Bill it's a distractions, possibly confusing, and bumps this meta post. Certainly there are worse things, but I consider it as fundamentally unreasonable to have "blinking" posts that are un-deleted every other day or every other week. (This one is going on since a month.)

Comment: @quid I think there are for more important matters that deserve to be deemed  "fundamentally unreasonable". This shouldn't even be on the radar.

Comment: @BillDubuque examples?

Comment: @quid One of the reasons that I initially created this  thread (original version) was so that there would  be only *one* thread being bumped on such matters.  The bumps are expected and are completely normal. Those with no interest in such matters can easily ignore it.

Comment: @BillDubuque that's fine it does however not address the other points and does not provide any examples. Anyway, if you see things that I or another moderator should address please bring them to our attention. If you want to discuss this particular post in more detail, post a question about it.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3061543/revisions)

Please consider undeleting and reopening this post:

[If $\sin(\pi x)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos(n\pi x)$ for $0<x<1$ then what is the value of $(a_0+a_1)\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3061543/9464),

where OP gave his/her thoughts:

> Honestly I have no idea about how to approach this problem. I tried the expansion of $\sin x$ on the left hand side and then expand $\cos x$ on the right but end up with a mess. Then again $\cos x=(\sin x)'$, but by converting each term on the right hand side into derivative of sine does not give any sensible identity to draw out something. Really out of ideas on this one. Is there any way to do this? Please give me some hints. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Reopened, undeleted, closed, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3285344/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this question where I also provided an answer: [Integrating $\int_0^1\frac{x\ln (1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$ with restricted techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285344).

The OP from clearly provides background on how the integral appeared, although it was some kind of homework now it can be useful for others too.

Comment: It's good form to  disclose that one has an answer on the post oneself.

Comment: Hope I don't sound rude, but I don't understand what you wrote even with translate. Did you meant: It's a good thing to mention that I posted an answer to the linked question?

Comment: Yes. You should mention this. It makes clear that you are not a neutral third party. You have a personal interest in the undeletion. This does not disqualify you from making the proposal. But it is good form to be upfront about it.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2505216/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen this post: [Evaluate this limit: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n\sin n}{2n^2 - 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505216/9464)

This post is by no means missing context. OP clearly stated at the beginning what he/she tried and where he/she got stuck. This post has also a [detailed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2505222/9464) by a 50K+ user.

Comment: It might be worth noting that unfortunately that so-called detailed answer completely ignores the provided context, in that sense it's a rather poor answer, but arguably that's tangential. I'd tend to agree that this question does show reasonable context. If we take the context into account, likely it's a dupe.

Comment: Instead of saying "what goes wrong with my thoughts" or "how can I go on with my original approach", OP explicitly stated that "*Any* help will be appreciated". And @Clement C. helped this user by directly giving an argument. Not a poor answer, and there have four people considering it good. This post is an extremely poor choice for deletion.

Comment: quid does make a fair point that an answer showing how OP could go on with the original approach may be more useful for the asker. One could add such an answer after this post is reopened.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3289818/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen this post:

[How can one use the direct comparison test for $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+10k}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3289818/9464)

Even in the very [first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3289818/1) of the post, OP states his/her thoughts and difficulties he/she has. This post is NOT missing context. And it is NOT a duplicate of any other question.

Comment: Because we already have many questions where divergence of a series is deduced from a comparison with the harmonic series, this is bound to be a duplicate dozens of times over. Therefore the question should also be closed as too localized (not adding anything new to the site, and only helping the asker do their homework). *Missing context* is the best proxy we currently have, so if reopened I will vote to reclose and redelete.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Maybe I should have trie to search a bit more, but by a quick search I only found this: [Calculus II: Comparison Test for Divergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025440). (All I am saying that I am unable to confirm that there are *dozens* of posts which are close to duplicates. Although I agree that when I saw the question, I expected that there should be many similar questions.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak It is one of the standard series to use a comparison test with :-) Anyway, when the question is a (near-) duplicate IMO *showing effort/thoughts* is NOT SUFFICIENT to stop closure/deletion. The questions should have wider interest, and the context should demonstrate that.

Comment: Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at ANY level and professionals in related fields. How many questions a student asks are not supposed to be "standard"?! And is any one of the four mentioned in the first comment not standard?

Comment: @Jack Your comment about MSE being for questions at any level is a red herring---the question was not closed because of its level.  The question is a standard question which occurs (in one form or another) in many elementary texts on calculus.  Moreover, it is a question which already has an answer on MSE.  What new, valuable information does this particular question add to MSE which isn't already on the site?

Comment: *How many questions a student asks are not supposed to be "standard"?!* @Jack, not very many. The same applies to StackOverflow. Which is exactly why Jeff Atwood wrote that a new asker should spend 98% of their time on StackExchange *searching*.
Getting more and more questions does not improve the site, and is not necessary for its success any longer. On occasion it is quite the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

> **Reopened**

I propose reopening [Has Gödel’s second incompleteness theorem been formalized?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544805/has-g%C3%B6del-s-second-incompleteness-theorem-been-formalized)

The question simply asks whether there is a computer-verified version of the proof of the theorem. This strikes me as a perfectly reasonable mathematical question, and I can't see why anyone would vote to close it, much less delete it (there are currently two votes to delete).

Full disclosure: I posted an answer (the only answer) to the question, which OP has accepted. The answer attracted a downvote – I'm guessing that was done to make it easier to close and delete the question, since I can't see what objection anyone could have to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Deleted, undeleted, deleted.**

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The close notice for [How to prove that the permanent of a doubly stochastic matrix is positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568416/how-to-prove-that-the-permanent-of-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix-is-positive) says, "Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question."

The problem being solved is perfectly clear (to anyone who knows what a doubly stochastic matrix is, and what the permanent of a matrix is), and others have not needed any help answering the question, so the close notice strikes me as invalid. Please consider voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Possibly you did not get the memo: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/new-recommended-close-reason-for-questions-that-are-missing-context

Comment: @quid if a user is going to vote to close a question, and if none of the currently available close reasons applies, I reckon the user really ought to leave a comment explaining how the question doesn't measure up. What was done for this question, even if OP clicked to see the further information on "add details and clarify," gives OP no clue as to what to do. Heck, it gives *me* no idea as to what the close-voters actually had in mind. Let's reopen the question, and give the close-voters the chance to make their case.

Comment: Maybe that would have been better but there is only so much time and it fits well enough. As for you, it is hard to believe that you actually had not understood what the matter was (as opposed to disagreeing). Either way, I hope you keep the information obtained here in mind going forward.

Answer (score -1):

> **Deleted.**

2 or 3 days ago, the question [What's the connection between the Heegner numbers and 37?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718652/whats-the-connection-between-the-heegner-numbers-and-37) was asked.

(1). The first version of that question, was not eligible as a question to be asked in MSE, and **I** was the fifth user, who **voted to close the question**.

(2). In the comments:

- User @David wrote that: `37 is the largest prime for which -163 is a quadratic non-residue.`
- Then I pointed out that his comment is not right by this comment: `Consider this Legendre symbol: (−163/137)=−1.`
- Then he answered that: `The statement is more like 37 is largest prime p s.t. All primes, q: 2<q<=p have (−163/q)=−1. I would like to state this correctly and succinctly.`

(3). **Why I was convinced that his question is a good question?**

- His comment was interesting to me, because I've realized that **the phenomenon, which he pointed out,** is not accidental and **is closely related to the properties of Heegner numbers**. [**Not important**: As you can see in the comments; at first, I wrongly thought that it is related to Rabinowitz theorem. For proof of the Rabinowitz theorem see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357) by Will Jagy.]
- [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number): A Heegner number is a square-free positive integer $d$ such that the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ has class number $1$. I wrote my answer, in the comments [[see these six consecutive comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718652/whats-the-connection-between-the-heegner-numbers-and-37#comment7647095_3718652)]. If we set this definition as the definition of Heegner Numbers, then the **First case** is just the immediate consequence of the definition. I mean whether we know the total set of Heegner numbers is finite or not, we can do the first case without any use of powerful theorems like [Baker–Stark–Heegner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem), **just by the knowledge of $19^{\text{th}}$ century**. [**Very Important**: Unfortunately, in the **Second case**, I strongly used the [Baker–Stark–Heegner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem). **Not important**: If we break the second case in some new cases, then the case "$(\dfrac{-H}{q})=0$ and $q^2 \nmid (H)$" can be done in a quite elementary manner, but yet I don't have any idea to do the case "$(\dfrac{-H}{q})=0$ and $q^2 \mid (H)$".]

(4). If a curious person sees that question, then probably he/ she would click on the `show N more comments` to see the comments. So **Why do I insist to reopen that question?** An unsatisfactory answer would be something like this: (A) Suppose that a random student who does not have enough curiosity about this special question, will see this question. (+) Since this question is closed for the lack of details, (++) and since there is not an answer for it; the most probable scenario would be that he/ she will be taught there is nothing special behind this question. (B) Another unsatisfactory answer would be something like this: From a pedagogical point of view: Someone else can write a better answer, maybe someone can be able to answer it without using any powerful theorems. Finally, reading a solution as a single answer is better to follow the separated comments. At last, I should confess whether this question reopens or not, it would not cause important changes.

(5): **TOTALLY IRRELEVANT**: As a math student, I should be careful about my counting: In [my last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718652/whats-the-connection-between-the-heegner-numbers-and-37#comment7647341_3718652), I wrote `My 7th comment`, but it was my eighth comment.

---

---

---

Added after the edit:

Let's set this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) as the definition of a Heegner number. As I stated in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718652/whats-the-connection-between-the-heegner-numbers-and-37#comment7647341_3718652), the question can be considered as

- Q($1$): Let $H$ be a Heegner number, then for any prime $2 \neq q \leq \dfrac{1+H}{4}-2$ we have $(\dfrac{-H}{q})=-1$,

Or equivalently:

- Q($2$): Let $H$ be a positve square-free integer, and let $q$ be a prime number $2 \neq q \leq \dfrac{1+H}{4}-2$, such that $(\dfrac{-H}{q})=+1$. Then $H$ is not a Heegner number.

Both of these equivalent questions are very surprising to me. Now consider this question:

> - Q($3$): Let $200 \leq H$ be a positve square-free integer, then there exists a prime number $q$ such that: $2 \neq q \leq \dfrac{1+H}{4}-2$ and $(\dfrac{-H}{q})=+1$.

If I was able to prove the above question, then the [Baker–Heegner–Stark theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem), would follow immediately. So Q($3$) is not an easy question.

- Reamrk($4$): Let $\dfrac{49}{3} \leq H \stackrel{8}{\equiv} 3$, then the Gauss's upper bound [Gauss's bound, is a better bound, than Minkowski's bound, for the norm of ideals to be checked in order to determine the class number of the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-H})$], tells us: By considering [Baker–Heegner–Stark theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem), if $H \notin \{ 11, 19, 43, 67, 163 \}$, then there is a prime $q$ such that: $2 \neq q \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{H}{3}}$ and $(\dfrac{-H}{q})=+1$. Note that for $\dfrac{49}{3} \leq H$ this new bound is surprisingly smaller than $\dfrac{1+H}{4}-2$. These were some parts of my unsuccessful attempts to prove Q($3$), without use of Baker–Heegner–Stark theorem.

Comment: You ask, "Why do I insist to reopen that question?" and then you give two reasons, both of which you yourself label as "unsatisfactory". So, I'm confused. Do you have a *satisfactory* reason for insisting on reopening the question? (And, if so, can you give it without boldface and blockquote and all-caps and other annoying typographical flourishes?)

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson , 

I used the word "unsatisfactory" for the first answer (A), because I wasn't sure about the opinion of the generic person, who would see that answer; and also *I didn't have enough courage to say that answer is satisfactory to me*. 

Also, I didn't add new comments to that question, since *writhing long mathematical comments is very hard to me*, because of the lack of the editor to be aware of my LaTeX mistakes, and also there is a restriction on the total number of characters.

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson , 

I accustomed to use bold and colorful formats, for the convenience of the reader; because to me, it plays the role of change of tone in the web environment. I didn't even think that it may be annoying; thank you for notifying this subject.

Comment: @DavoodKHAJEHPOUR Can you please edit your post here down to the essential details?  There is so much extraneous commentary in it that I cannot pick out the reason(s) why you think this question should be reopened. I'll note that the question has now been deleted.

Comment: Dear @XanderHenderson Since this edit would be something related to a question, which is already deleted; I am afraid that if I continue editing my post here, then I will be punished because of some rules that I do not know. Since there is no guarantee that I will not be punished, I will not continue no longer; However, I believe that the answer to that question contained important things.

Comment: @DavoodKHAJEHPOUR You will not be punished for editing your answer to make it more clear.  If you believe that the question is worth saving, then you should *clearly* and *concisely* make your case.  Three screenfuls of oddly formatted, rambling text is unlikely to convince anyone.

Comment: @XanderHenderson If writing that question and its comments would be helpful, I will do this. Do you mean this?

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, Deleted, Reopened, Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3527292/revisions)

Please undelete and reopen [$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[nr]{x_i^{nr}+(n^{nr}-1)\prod \limits_{j=1}^nx^r_j}} \ge 1$, for all $x_i>0$ and $r \geq \frac{1}{n}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527292).

- This inequality question is clearly a conjecture made from [an existing question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370084), which I think is a fair question to ask.  Inequality conjectures on this site are often false.  This is one of the rare cases where experiments yield correct claims.  I expect that there are many inequalities that can be inferred from the inequality in question (such as [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1143635p5383491), [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1127374p5217483), [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h160010p894774), [Comment 5 of this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h514416p2890034), and even [Comment 1 of this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h519613p2926061)).  We should preserve it, to keep it a reference.
- The current answer (mine) is unsatisfactory, for it is long and too complicated.  This is not an easy inequality problem, and there should be a better way to solve it.  If my having posted an answer there is an issue for some users (which I don't understand why, it is not like reputations grant anything to me), I can make my answer a community wiki post.  Knowledge, on the other hand, is precious (and reputations are not at all precious, which is perplexing to me because a lot of arguments here are based on reputations, e.g., reputation farming, who benefits from undeleting some posts, etc).
- This is not a contextless question.  Users are often asked to provide a context, and the source of the problem is a context.  The asker stated that this was modified from [an old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370084).  You might think this is insufficient.  I disagree, but anyway, more context has been added.

Comment: You should note that the question, which is a contextless problem statement question, currently has only one answer, which was written by you.  You are not a disinterested third party in this case.

Answer (score -1):

> [**Undeleted, Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3726452/revisions)

I want [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726452/the-following-is-a-system-of-equations-where-q-2p-a-11x-1-a-12x-2) question to be to undeleted because I wrote [a long answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726452/the-following-is-a-system-of-equations-where-q-2p-a-11x-1-a-12x-2/3726528#3726528) for it and it was a correct and well-explained question.  The question now has more context.

**Edit: Can someone suggest for edits that should be made to reopen this post also? This problem is quite similar to [Siegel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma) and I don't think MSE has a post regarding such problems. I think it should be reopened also. Please consider this to be reopened.**

Comment: Thank you for being upfront about your reasons for wanting this question undeleted / reopened.  Unfortunately, I do not feel that I can vote to undelete the question–the question is a "problem statement question", and does not meet the quality standards of Math SE.  The asker has not provided any context, such as a source for the problem or any thoughts about how to approach the problem.  I am sorry that you invested your time into answering this question.  Perhaps, in the future, you will be a little choosier about which questions you choose to answer.

Comment: @Xander, we do sometimes keep low quality questions that provoke high quality answers. I can't see question or answer so I can't say whether that applies here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson [What do you mean "we"?](https://huntthedevil.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/what-do-you-mean-we-white-man/)  I was expressing my opinion (note the large number of first person singular pronouns in the text), and hoping to convince others to follow my lead.  You appear to have a contrary opinion.  Wuderbar.  But please don't phrase your opinion in such a way that you give the appearance of speaking for the rest of the community.  Again, what do you mean "we"?

Comment: BTW you linked [to your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726452/the-following-is-a-system-of-equations-where-q-2p-a-11x-1-a-12x-2/3726528#3726528) rather than [to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726452/the-following-is-a-system-of-equations-where-q-2p-a-11x-1-a-12x-2). The wording suggests that you probably wanted to link to the question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I just requested to undelete this because I have invested time to think about the solution and I solved this using pigeon hole principle. It's an undeniable fact that this a very good and seemingly unexpected application of pigeon hole principle. I think it should be undeleted. I have nothing more to say.

Comment: I thought I made it clear, Xander, that I was not expressing any opinion on the merits or otherwise of the deleted question or of Shubhrajit's answer. On the other matter you raise, I think it is a fact, and not an opinion, that occasionally we – the m.se community – find an answer of such high quality that we choose to keep it on site despite the failings of the question that prompted it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My understanding is that the community usually have huge argument about what to do with low quality question with great answers. In some heated case the mods even had to lock the question to stop the delete/un-delete war.

Comment: @Arc OK, but I see nothing in what you've written that contradicts what I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm studying Poisson Processes. If i have two overlapping time intervals of the same Poisson Process, what are the effects on PMF of the numbers of arrivals in these two intervals ?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839257/pmf-of-overlapping-poisson-processes), quoted above, was closed for lack of details or clarity. Is there anything besides what is in every textbook that is needed in order to understand it? Is there some ambiguity in the question that I cannot see?

(I posted an answer.)

Comment: I imagine that the "details" requested are not details of the mathematics but details about the person who posted the question, as to what the user does or doesn't understand about the topic. The less one knows about the user (and given a question stated as in this case, we know virtually nothing about the user), the harder it is to write an answer the user will find useful. Michael, that's how it's been going here for years now, surely you've noticed?

Answer (score -1):

> **Undeleted, closed**

Please undelete [Find nontrivial real coefficients of sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925311/290189) as the question asker self-deleted his/her own question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score -2):

**Reopened**

---

Please consider reopening [Indian Mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897316/). The question was closed as off-topic, apparently because of the existence of the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site.

As I pointed out in a comment, first, questions about history of mathematics are on-topic here. The tag [math-history](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history) has almost two thousand questions and a decent amount of recent activity.

Second, the quality of many interactions at the HSM site is sadly rather poor (I was very enthusiastic about it when it started, so this poor quality quite bothers me), and it may end up being a disservice to send this question there.

(I would actually love to see the quality at that site to raise uniformly, and hope it happens relatively soon. But that is another matter.)

Comment: I think at least the formulation of the question should be clarified a bit before it is reopened. The first answerer already misunderstood it.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll do a slight edit.

Comment: I had decided to do an edit myself. Sorry for the confusion. I'll check back in one or two hours. If it's still closed then I'll  give the final vote(s). This allows also for further editing.

Comment: No problem. I gave the edit a second pass. (And thank you.)

Answer (score -2):

I nominate https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29570/290189 to be undeleted because this meta question contains moderator's feedback to deal with serial downvotes.

Comment: What information is in that post that is not in the FAQ? Also as it was auto-delered it'd be redeleted.

Comment: @quid That post provides **real examples** of questions being serial downvoted.

Comment: How is that useful?

Answer (score -2):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3110919/revisions)

Please undelete [On a colon ideal in the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3110919/290189) because this question has got a score of 2 after OP included his/her own thoughts on the problem.  This algebraic geometry question might add value to the main site.

Comment: Selfdeleted *without answer.* No need to undelete.

Answer (score -2):

> **Deleted, undeleted, redeleted and merged with another question**

I request the undeletion of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119568/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-expressions-of-the-form-sqrta-b-sqrtc) (on denesting $\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}\,)$

Reason:
I asked this question, and it turned out to be a duplicate. However, this doesn't deserve deletion as this question contains a crucial formula that is a very useful one. It is very useful to me, and it is sad for me to see that the community is not able to access it anymore. Please undelete this question.

Comment: The answers there are dupes of the answers in the linked dupe thread (and *many* others - this is a FAQ). I see no reason to further such rampant duplication.

Comment: @BillDubuque there is a useful formula. Perhaps if you can transfer the answer to the other question?? I find it really useful.

Comment: That well-known formula is already in [Frank's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1747478/242) in the dupe (and many, many other answers here). Moreover, he *derives* if instead of pulling it out of a hat as in the answer in your thread.

Comment: @BillDubuque how is it derived? even if so, the other answer on my question has a basic method that is not included in the other question.

Comment: Please read Frank's linked answer (and the others too). That's the point of linking your question to the dupe target.

Comment: @BillDubuque oh, right.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was deleted. It seems to me that the only reason is that it is a duplicate. I do not believe that this is a reason to delete duplicated (and this was discussed recently [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29191/10513)).

Answer (score -2):

> [**Deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed as duplicate, deleted, undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3172480/revisions)

What OP wrote under the problem statement clearly show his/her thoughts:

> How can I do this if I don't know how $a_n$ is defined? I can use the given limit to get the range of $a_n$ in terms of $L$, but I lack the direction to complete the proof.

This is not a zero effort question. Please consider undeleting this post:

[Given positive sequence $a_n$ where $\lim _{n\to \infty} a_n = L, L >0$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/a_n = 1/L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3172480/9464)

Comment: Did you check if it's a duplicate? It's a very standard question.

Comment: @quid, it probably is a duplicate (although I had no luck finding an example), but then shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate rather than as off-topic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson a question might be eligible for closure for multiple reasons. It's maybe not a PSQ  in it's purest form, but it's still not a good question. I'd say if somebody wants to restore a question it's on them to make sure *no reason* applies not just the one that was chosen. Further, it would have been on the asker to make some good faith effort to find a dupe before answering (and then complaining that their answer was removed). **If** a dupe of this question is not findable what does this tell about the level of organization in those tags. The priorities are not good.

Comment: @quid, I see Jack complaining that the question was deleted, not that his/her answer was removed. As to whether Jack made a good faith effort to find a dupe, I have no way to know for sure. The tags seem reasonable, and I wouldn't expect a duplicate to use all three of them, and just searching among questions with, say, the tag "limits" seems pretty hopeless, considering how many questions have that tag. All I can really go by is the difficulty I had in finding a duplicate, using approach0.

Comment: @GerryMyerson here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171733/convergence-of-inverse-of-convergent-sequence it was pretty trivial to find.

Comment: Well, in any case they complain. We can replace the "that" by "after". On the rest, again the onus is on them. They ought to explain that there is no dupe (supposedly). Further, it is generally considered as good form to mention if one has answered oneself. Especially if it is the only answer. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @quid, well done – you're clearly better at searching than I am.

Comment: @GerryMyerson not sure about that. I might have  had the luck to use the better strategy for that example, searching for words via Google on this site not for formulas for example 'convergence of inverse of convergent sequence' works well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (and quid) I did try to find a duplicate and I indeed noticed that limit of reciprocal of a sequence away from zero should be a rather standard exercise in calculus/analysis and should have been asked before. However, I think "context" counts as  an integral part of a post, and that is why we insist on "contexts", don't we? [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] I am not able to find any same/similar confusion ("How can I do this if I don't know how $a_n$ is defined?") in any known post, for instance in the linked post in one of quid's previous comments and thus I do not think this post should be considered as an "absolute" duplicate that one should delete it.

Comment: I agree with Jack's comments above, I don't think this post should be closed if a duplicate is not found where the same confusion is addressed. To the best of my knowledge, this confusion has not been addressed before, so this post should be undeleted and reopened.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Basically a duplicate, except it doesn't require $a_n$ to be a positive sequence, was asked fairly recently at [Sequence Limit Reciprocal Law Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200658/sequence-limit-reciprocal-law-proof/3201203), where I provided an accepted answer. As for finding it, note it originally only used the tag "elementary-number-theory", but I changed it later to "limits", so searching for it initially might not have turned it up. However, I can't see the original deleted question content, but the page it brings up shows $2$ other somewhat related ...

Comment: (cont) questions: [Given: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722215/given-lim-limits-n-to-inftya-n-0-prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1a) and [How to formally prove that if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=\infty$, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150329/how-to-formally-prove-that-if-lim-limits-n-to-inftya-n-infty-then-li). Although they're somewhat different, and I haven't checked them carefully, I suspect their techniques are transferable.

Comment: The status of the question had not changed at all. What is the justification for this edit?

Comment: On the comments above, which I only see know, due to lack of a notification, that's not a particular confusion. Any generic proof will necessarily  do just fine to address this. I mean the proof you gave is completely generic. What do you think you did to address whatever specific confusion?

Comment: I agree with Brahadeesh's comment and I've undeleted the question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 what is the particular confusion and how is it addressed specifically?

Comment: @quid The quoted question in Jack's last comment answers your first question; point (3) in Jack's answer addresses your second one.

Comment: @GNU As detailed this ask nothing more than that the author understands that they might be able to do it or at least how to strat for a specific sequence like say $2n/(n+1)$. Any generic proof will do just fine, and what about the third point? Again any proof  will have to address this somehow (in one based on continuity it might be hidden). Certainly it's findable in other answers. It's just a contrived argument to save this post, and frankly I am appalled by this. Explain how this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1171755/ is not sufficient or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54754/?

Answer (score -2):

> **[Undeleted, redeleted, re-undeleted, redeleted, undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3239790/revisions)**

Please consider undeleting the question: [The asymptotic behavior of $n\ln n -n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239790/9464)

This question has four well written answers by experienced users. One answer has six upvotes and contains useful links to similar problems.

Comment: Well, I'd consider something in the spirit  of the comment as the best answer there. Anyway given the complete lack of context it's hard to know which type of answer would be useful, whence the voluminous list. Also all standard likely on the site in similar form tens if not hundreds of times. At least one answerer made the effort to link it to related posts.

Comment: Redeleted (6/17/19) by a same group of users. One initiated *three* times the delete votes and one voted three times to delete this post.

Comment: Probably I should have refrained of posting an answer there - however at the time when I posted there were some answers already and they seemed (to me) more complicated than needed. I have also included links to some other questions - you can see that similar questions are on the site (and they have similar answers). I will also say that when posting the answer I was fully aware that the question is likely to be closed/deleted.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I believe "closing" is enough for this particular post. I strongly disagree with the deletion considering the high qualities of answers. Such good contents will be useful for future readers (this is closed post is not some stupid trivial textbook exercise) and should be preserved on the site.

Comment: @Jack Well, several discussions here on meta suggest that when deciding about closing (and probably also deleting), most users take into account mainly quality of the question (and do not look at answers). Since you have mentioned that you care about preserving context, I should specifically point out that my answer contains some links to other posts which use Stol-Cesaro. Will Jagy [reposted his answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2019/6/18) in another thread. (For obvious reasons, I might be a bit biased in this particular case.)

Answer (score -2):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed as duplicate (mod)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3123692/revisions)

Please consider undeleting this post: [2011 IMC Section A Problem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3123692/9464)

This is not an ongoing contest problem. The answer is known online. @Aqua's answer (with 14 net upvotes) is a useful one.

Comment: Poorly explained answer. Had downvoted it back then.

Comment: That was a really bad excuse for deletion.

Comment: Since I did not delete it, I don't need any excuse (and I doubt the delete-voters where aware of my voting back then). Please do not write comments that might suggest otherwise as not everybody can check it easily.

Answer (score -2):

> [**Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2493482/revisions)

Please consider casting the final undelete vote and reopening this post:
[Evaluate $1+2-3-4+5+6-7-8+\cdots+50.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2493482/9464)

This question is well written and with effort. It has very well written answers, one of which gives a generalization of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Please undelete this post: [$n^4 + 4^n$ is a not a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322795/9464)

OP clearly states context for his/her question:

> This question appeared in the undergrad entrance exam of the Indian Statistical institute.
>
> When $n$ is even the proof is simple. For $=2+1$ I am utterly stuck.

True that this is a duplicate of some previous posts, but [duplicate can be useful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9588/9464). Moreover, it is not necessarily easy at all to identify this question as a duplicate:

- The useful searching engine [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) is NOT well known, neither it is mentioned on the page of [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) of MSE.
- A quick search of the expression $n^4+4^n$ on the MSE searching box [returns](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24n%5E4%2B4%5En%24) something irrelevant:
  [image]
- If one posts this as a new question: the "similar questions" box does not show any one of the duplicate:

  > [image]

["Questions that are **extremely** off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators."](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) This 5 upvoted one with three answers is not.

Comment: At some point, every math student really ought to be shown the factorization of $x^4+4$.

Comment: This is an umpteenth reincarnation. Even in 2013 when André Nicolas answered it we had already covered it many times. Also, while duplicates were seen as somewhat useful back in 2013 (when Jeff Atwood's strangedupe comment was often cited), the site has moved on since. The most recent word from above (don't remember for sure whether it is from JA or the current CEO Joel Spolsky) reads: *Over time duplicates become vast landmine fields*.

Comment: The sentence ("... landmine fields") Jyrki mentioned is from [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/) by Jeff Atwood. That one is specifically talk about StackOverflow, which is sort of the counterpart of MathOverflow. (cont.)

Comment: Jeff explicitly writes in that article the following : *But I will point out that there is plenty of precedent on the Stack Exchange network for splitting sites into "expert" and "beginner" areas with slightly different rulesets.* We've seen this for **Math vs. MathOverflow**, English vs. English Learners, Unix vs. Ubuntu... **perhaps it's time for a more beginner focused Stack Overflow where duplicates are less frowned upon**, and conversational rules are a bit more lenient?

Comment: I am not following SO much at all, but what little I have seen of it it is nowhere near the level of sophistication of MathOverflow (admittedly my observations are likely biased). But I would support walling off lower level math (like freshman and below) to a Math Learner site.

Comment: I don't get what's the contradiction even. Certainly duplicates will happen, some will be caught other won't be caught. Of those that do get caught we'll keep some that seems relevant as "sign posts" and we remove the rest without much ado (either way). Why would we want to keep them?

Comment: On search, [searching n^4 + 4^n for works like a charm](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=n%5E4+%2B+4%5En) Why would one use strange spacing, or in any case just check one version,  and include the completely irrelevant dollars?

Comment: @quid: your linked search of `n^4 + 4^n` , which does return a duplicate result, uses "strange spacing". If one searches `n^4+4^n` *without* the spacing before and after the plus sign, [one would not see the charm](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=n%5E4%2B4%5En).

Comment: The answers are all dupes of answers given many times in the past. This FAQ   occurs many times every year. There is no need to keep adding duplicate answers every time it reoccurs. Doing so makes it difficult if not impossible for users to locate the most enlightening answers.

Comment: @Jack I forgot to add that [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions) is the StackOverflow analogue of MathOverflow. Don't get mislead by the inclusion of the word *Overflow*. If SO walls off a learners' site, we should do the same.

Comment: And also, the voting already gives low level math an unhealthy advantage in the gamification aspects of the site. Simply because users are obviously not going to (and should not) vote on material over their head. You wanting to be more lenient about low level duplicates would exacerbate an already serious problem.

Comment: Well, let's forget about which spacing is strange or not. One might learn the lesson that one should search for both variations. I'd still maintain that the spacing there is the more natural way to type it. But I am glad that you seem to agree now that the dollars are useless. // And even if it was completely unnatural **it is the very spacing that was used** in that post that you want undel too. Thus at least that user likely would have used the same spacing if they had searched and keeping this as a dupe would not even help future searches (except maybe via answer, but then merge could do).

Answer (score -2):

**REOPENED, Closed**

I request to reopen [Why does $f(z) = z^n$ have no antiderivative only for $n=-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653570/why-does-fz-zn-have-no-antiderivative-only-for-n-1) It was closed as a duplicate of [Antiderivative 1/z on C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154428/antiderivative-1-z-on-c).

I disagree that it is a duplicate. The first question was a soft question and the second was a hard question. OP wasn't literally asking for a proof that $1/z$ doesn't have an antiderivative. He was asking what makes $n=-1$ "special". This is a different question. One question is soft and the other is hard.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653570/why-does-fz-zn-have-no-antiderivative-only-for-n-1#comment7525912_3653570) by the OP I have added the [tag:intuition] and [tag:soft-question] tags and voted to reopen.

Answer (score -2):

> **Deleted, undeleted, deleted**

May I request to **Undelete** and **Reopen** (or at least undelete) this question
[Prove $\frac{ab}{a^5 + b^5 + ab} + \frac{bc}{b^5 + c^5+ bc} + \frac{ca}{c^5 + a^5 + ca} \leq 1$ when $abc=1$, $a,b,c>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727218/prove-that-if-a-b-c-0-fracaba5-b5-ab-fracbcb5-c5-bc) answered by me? The question is well written and it's a very tricky inequality.

Comment: Let me invite you again to read the instruction at the top of this thread. (1)  A request should be posted as an answer below (one request per answer)

Comment: (2) Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of link"

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry.

Comment: I requested (by flagging the moderators) that both of your inequality threads be merged with their duplicates).  I hope that they oblige, although my merging requests have been turned down a few times, so I am not too optimistic.

Comment: I see @Batominovski

Comment: I didn't really understand why it was deleted?

Comment: It is likely that they will refuse to merge at least one thread.  The questions are not exactly the same in [this deleted thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723607/prove-that-if-abc-geq-1-and-a-b-c-0-then-frac11-a-b-frac1) as in [its duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606380/if-abc-1-and-a-b-c-are-positive-real-numbers-prove-that-1-over-ab1?noredirect=1&lq=1).  In the deleted thread, $abc\geq 1$ is the constraint.  In the duplicate, $abc=1$ is the constraint.  (However, this difference doesn't affect the proof at all.)

Comment: @Batominovski yeah.

Comment: You are expected to *make a case* for undeleting and/or reopening a question, Shubhrajit, not just a request.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, Shubhrajit, that you are supposed to make some attempt to try to convince us that it would be a good idea to undelete/reopen the question.

Comment: If the question does get reopened, shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate of the question Martin noted in a comment?

Comment: I voted to delete this question as it is simply the statement of the problem, with no effort shown by the asker.

Answer (score -2):

May I request to reopen this question [Prime factor of $A=14^7+14^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012344/prime-factor-of-a-1471421) so that everyone can see the beautiful answers?

Comment: No, it's written that viewable only to members who have the close and reopen vote facilities and the OP

Comment: That sentence refers to the list of close voters, not to the post itself.

Comment: @Brahadeesh If a question is closed, there are always risks of being deleted (which might be a bit harder for this question due to the vote counts of the thread).

Comment: And to @ShubhrajitBhattacharya, I think it will be easier to get it reopened if you add more contexts into the question. Right now it is a plain PSQ.

Comment: @ArcticChar I agree, but that was not what Shubhrajit meant by his words: see his first comment for clarification.

Comment: It's too late to save this question. This question is from 4 years ago, and there is no way to recover the context from the comments like you can do with some questions. This is why we provide an incentive for questions to have attempts or working shown.

Answer (score -2):

[Prove $\int g(x) f(g(x)) g'(x) \,dx = \int uf(u)\, du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897275/prove-int-gx-fgx-gx-dx-int-ufu-du)

This question has been clarified since it was first posted. This is about indefinite, rather than definite integrals. If it could only admit a formal answer rather than a logical answer, maybe it wouldn't be worth much, but that is not the case, as can be seen in the answer that I posted.

Comment: And therefore, you are proposing ... what?

Comment: What is a "logical answer"?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : I think you will see what I mean if you contrast what I wrote with the other answers.

Comment: I read the whole thing before asking.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : Did you look at the way the question was phrased before editing and at the answers other than mine as they first appeared?  It said: $$\text{begin quote}$$
I am trying to prove the formula
$$\int g(x)f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx=\int uf(u)\,du.$$
$$\text{end quote}$$ And two posted answers applied the chain rule in a formal way, and by "formal" I mean it fit the form without being fussy about whether it's logically rigorous, as in first-year calculus textbooks. My own answer began by saying that if these are indefinite integrals, then the question is$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$meaningless unless $x$ and $u$ are somehow related, and then explained how they would need to be related in order that the identity be true, and proved it. $\qquad$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : $\qquad \uparrow \qquad$ So I mean "formal" in the sense in which the equality $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(x)f(x)\,dx = -f'(0) $$is formal when done the way Paul Dirac originally did it, as opposed to the way people like Laurent Schwarz did it later. $\qquad$

Comment: I still don't see what you are proposing, Michael.

Answer (score -2):

[Tricky Calculus Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948694/tricky-calculus-problem)
This question should be reopened because I can not substitute a trig identity to solve the problem. I am doing a non-circular trigonometry problem, and doing so makes the solving of the problem null. I would need to know how to find the algebraic function that represents tangent in the form of:
$$\tan(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt.$$ That is inherently where I am stuck at.

Comment: Your Question makes no sense.  You "edited" in a postscript in which $\tan(x)$ gets replaced by $tan^{-1}(x)$.  I don't get what "a non-circular trigonometry problem" means, at least in the present context.  Either you want the derivative of tangent or the derivative of arctangent, and in either case a calculus book tells you the facts.

Comment: @Hardmath Non-Circular geometry means that you can not use trigonometry to define the principles that are being investigated.

Comment: @hardmath A calculus book does not tell me $f(t)$.

Comment: Your Question, at least in some revisions, shows that you know $f(t)$ is the derivative of tangent.  That certainly is covered by calculus textbook, and other references.  Perhaps there is some unhappiness about tangent and its derivative being "circular trigonometry" functions, but the nature of the tangent function can't be changed.

Answer (score -3):

> **[Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened, closed, locked, unlocked, deleted, undeleted, locked (for historical significance).](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2877034/revisions)**

I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877034/) question should be reopened. Thank you!

The original poster looked for the possibility to use the substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and he got a number of solutions.

By the way, the first comment of Lord Shark the Unknown is nothing.  At the least, it gives a very complicated solution which the topic starter tried to apply but without success.

Comment: Quote from the question: "I tried tangent half-angle substitution but it became too complicated." First comment on main: "Try half-angle substitution, but with a little more determination. – Lord Shark the Unknown Aug 9 at 9:54" Answer by the OP: [DNE].

Comment: "By the way, the first comment of Lord Shark the Unknown it's nothing" Pfff...

Comment: And now there's a rollback war.

Comment: This question feels like a joke that everyone gets but me. (1) Why is this question particularly bad? The OP said they tried the obvious thing but to no avail. Presumably they made a mistake, but so what? That doesn't invalidate the question. (2) Why is there such a fierce edit/close/delete war? The question is 2 months old - let it rest!!!

Comment: Rollback to Revision 9 by Alex Francisco, rollback to revision 10 by Michael Rozenberg, rollback to 9 by Alex, back to 12 by Michael, to 9 by Alex, to 14 by Michael, to 9 by Alex, to 16 by Michael. Crazy!

Comment: Please, Michael, please, please, please stop editing the tags on that question. Enough already!

Comment: This is just sorta embarrassing to watch at this point. And it's already back to 2 undelete votes, so I expect another full cycle in the next day.

Answer (score -3):

I think we need to open the following Mike Lyons's answer: [The smallest value of $x^2 + 5y^2 + 8z^2$ such that $yz+zx+xy=-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919846/)

I think it's a beautiful and right answer. We need to redact it only.

It was my mistake to delete this answer.

Comment: Note that the *question* has since been deleted.

Answer (score -3):

> **Undeleted, closed, re-deleted (not by question-asker this time)**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3129981/290189 because the question asker has self-deleted his/her own post after getting an answer.  The communnity has not got enough time to judge its value.

Answer (score -3):

I would like to see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175481/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-fracnxn-11xdx-where-0x1-assumin) undeleted and mark as duplicate but keep it alive on the network.

Also, I object to the deletion since although the questions are looking for the same thing, I must mention that they are not word by word duplicates and the context also seems a bit different. Also, the answers are not duplicates (except one which coincidentally was answered by the respective OPs of both questions).

Comment: This question was deleted by a moderator, which means that only a moderator can undelete it.  As such, there is pretty much nothing that anyone here can do for you.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I posted this on meta. Someone asked me to post here (just to be shot with 3 odd downvotes here )

Comment: Votes on meta do not mean the same thing that they mean on the main site.  A downvote means "I do not agree with this statement."  I would interpret the downvotes here as an indication that the community does not want to reopen / undelete your question.

Comment: @Aloizio Macedo can you please give some reasons on why you single-handedly deleted the question? (as it stands it looks like an abuse of power, but maybe there'a  reason that I'm missing)

Answer (score -3):

> [**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3063700/revisions)

Please undeleting this post: [How to prove that $\frac{e-1}{2e} \le \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x}dx \le \ln 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063700/9464)

OP did have his/her own attempt. This is not a zero-effort trivial question, which should not be deleted.

Answer (score -3):

The post: [GRE Subject Test - Past Papers, Books, Advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922417/gre-subject-test-past-papers-books-advice)

Hello I was told about this by hardmath [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32792/gre-advice-resource-questions). (I guess hardmath refers to this thread)

> but if you want it reopened, there is the canonical thread here on Meta to ask for that.

hardmath mentions how the question post now may be different from when the question post was 1st closed. however...not sure if it's a very good question. actually the point of the question was really just for the sake of the answer. like sharing knowledge Q&A style. I just wanted to be helpful to fellow GRE takers...

Please re-open if you think the question post deserves to be re-opened. However, if you don't, then how could the question post be improved (and I think we'll have to work under the assumption that it's a question created for the sake of the answer)?

Comment: I replied with a couple of Comments on your earlier Meta thread about improving the Question linked above.  If you like I'll post an Answer to your Meta post with more detailed advice, but I'm not arguing it should be re-opened as is.

Comment: @hardmath yes please

Answer (score -5):

> **[Undeleted, deleted, undeleted, reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2846931/revisions)**

[Minimize a+b+c+d given LCM(a,b,c,d)=1000 [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846931/111704)

Comment: I disagree.  The problem is completely unmotivated (the link at the top points to an equally unmotivated "inverse" problem, which gives a pair of problems which are unmotivated by anything other than eachother).  These are exemplars of problem statement questions.  The problems have no source, no context (theorems or definitions which could be relevant), and, lacking other context, there is not even any evidence of effort made.  I see no reason to undelete this question in it current form, and see good reason to close the linked question.

Comment: The problem is very well motivated - I was curious to the solution. It is also the source, mentioning also the problem from which I derived it. Anyways it is very unclear, what do you understand on a "motivated problem", the problems can't be motivated, only the people asking them. The voting scores of the question and answers clearly show, that a content destruction happened. I am also very shocked on your current deletion rampage, and I won't let it is it is.

Comment: The relevant rule is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): "*Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; [...] We don't like to lose great answers!*" By voting to delete the question, you violated this rule.

Comment: I disagree with the way Xander disagreed: "I see no reason to undelete this question in it current form". I disagree with the deletion as I would disagree with (potentially possible) close/deletion of this question Xander answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414862

Comment: @Jack I have no problem with the closure of the question to which you linked.  I do find your targeted citing of that question interesting, and would note that when I answered that question, I had been active on MSE for a grand total of 2 months, and had not yet learned the norms.  If I saw that question newly posted today, I would likely very quickly vote to close.

Comment: Normally when posting here, one is expected to put in an explanation for *why* this question should be undeleted, reopened, etc. The boldface line on the top is meant to indicate the status changes *after* posting, and not be a part of the request.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: "I have no problem with the closure of the question to which you linked". Sorry I do. I would disagree with closing the question you answered nicely I linked and in particular I would strongly disagree with deletion of that linked post. I do not think there was/is a "norm" for deletion so far for the site except the general rule peterh quoted in a comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Obviously I removed a message from the question to the original close voters. What relevance could it have in the case of the current undeletion request? The part you removed, stated that there is no valid deletion reason. Did that edit create one?

Comment: None of the answers there is great or even above completely standard. For those keen on rules from the help-center: "Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post."

Comment: @quid I was impressed on them. It is subjective. But their score is objective.

Comment: @quid I created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1058887/suspicious-question-deletions-from-the-last-week), to collect the similar "wise" decisions of the last week.

Comment: @peterh honestly I'd expect every moderately gifted first term students to be able to solve this. That's nothing worth keeping. As I quoted, "Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post."

Comment: @quid I suggest to compare also the results of this query to the results of other sites. It will say a lot. We have an ongoing deletion rampage. And please read a [precedent](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8058/200053) about a similar case.

Comment: For moderator who keen on different opinions/ideas from his/her own by MSE users: "Please don't abuse your power to stir discussion up when users disagree with your (possibly not so wise) idea of deletion and 'and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community' ".

Comment: That's off-topic here. But the two I opened seemed to be an egregious duplicated and worthless number theory questions.

Comment: @peterh that's not at all comparable the post you linked to. It's hard to take that seriously. Also it's off-topic here.

Comment: @quid Dupe questions with great answers should be deleted as dupe, but should not be deleted. Possibly they can be merged. Deleting questions with good answers is not what the SE model would welcome, are they dupe or not.

Comment: @peterh: I don't see how that situation on server fault is "similar". And again, I'd ask you to avoid using inflammatory language. It helps ***no one***, except perhaps you, to release pent up anger. It's inappropriate, and deteriorates the remote option that *anyone* is going to have a discussion.

Comment: @Jack so how about you respect others views or at least the rules of the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There was a mod deleted a lot of questions without prior discussion. The result was a de-modding. Now we have here a power user with del vote privileges, and with some other voters, doing the same. I think the cases are similar - maybe the largest difference is that power users have much lesser restrictions, but that is all.

Comment: If you think that this is somehow similar, you should spend a bit more time trying to learn the underlying software, the system of privileges, and what is the job of the moderators.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, I try to be nicer, but facts are facts. Having the delete vote privilege does not mean, that one can vote to delete as he likes to. Still there are rules to follow. I think, most of the deletions I've found seem contradicting the relevant rules.

Comment: @peterh and you are simply wrong about that this in violation of any rule since for the most part it's nowhere near great. Further to the precedent "I was relieved to find that Hopeless has acted as an enthusiastic but largely competent moderator, serving the community here faithfully except when it came to responding to questions/concerns regarding his actions and in communicating his efforts in cleaning up old posts."  In the end it turned out there wasn't even a problem with the deletions by themselves.

Comment: @quid Yes, but there was a problem with the massive post deletion without prior discussion. What now happens, looks very similar. 3 of my old posts were deleted within days. Do you think it was just coincidence? The SEDE query I created shows, that not I am the only one having the same problem. The comments show not I am the only one disliking the situation.

Comment: @peterh the discussion is on-going since years. Just this morning I spent an hour with an other user to analyze data about this. Users (as opposed to moderators) are severely  rated limited as concerns deletions. That you are miffed because three of your posts were deleted, does not mean that there is some problem. Yes, some users are against deletions, but again that's true since years. Maybe focus more on following rules regarding questions quality, then the issue regarding deletions will be of much less relevance. Don't cherry pick rules.

Comment: @quid The data is tricky. Also I [analyzed](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1057144/percentage-of-closure-deletion-events-compared-to-the-creation-events-per-month#graph) some data. I admit, that there is no recent sudden spike in the question deletions. This is why I started to check the score of the recently deleted questions (see my previous query). I executed the query also on other sites as comparison. My interpretation is that we have a question deleter group, and this group started to delete also useful posts.

Comment: @quid If they delete only a little bit more as they should, then they can remain below the radar. If you delete 5 questions falsely at once, it is a clear power misuse. If you delete 50 questions, where 45 deletions are correct and 5 violate the rules, and you do this in 10 days, no one will complain. Particularly because most of the deletions won't be noticed. Particularly if the deleters are high rep users.

Comment: @peterh since there is not hard and fast rule "a bit more as they should" usually will be a non-issue. Anyway the query is interesting but the high scoring ones I checked look like poor threads, in any case nothing relevant. Plus for several the selector used seems even transparent to those that follow, namely they were found among very short posts.

Comment: @quid It is your decision, what will be a mod issue. I need to notice, too, this sequence of events: 1) one of my old posts is deleted, in my opinion, falsely. 2) I [complain](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30330/111704) on the meta. 3) The post gets an undelete and a reopen. 4) 2 of my old posts are deleted. | I think, the nicest possible interpretation is that my meta post attracted some attention to my old main site posts. The lesser nice, but maybe more likely interpretation is that these were revenge deletions for my complains.

Comment: Given that the threads are poor and should be deleted, I do not see any reason not to go with the nicer interpretation. As your query shows, *relatively* better stuff is also deleted.

Comment: @quid There are site customs what we all should follow, even the mods. There is a consent, what is the required quality level of the questions. If one believes, this quality level should be higher, and votes accordingly, is imho compliant with the rules. If one does this focusing to the questions of others complaining on the meta, is imho a clear power misuse.

Comment: @peterh as explained your posts are such that relatively better ones get deleted with some frequency. Thus, I don't see what's your specific complaint. If you would complain that it's unfair that your posts that should be deleted all along only got actually deleted because you got some visibility now, then *maybe* there could be something to this. Yet that's not what you seem to do. As requested on the other post, please, explain the lasting value of the relevant threads. If there is none, according to the rules you hold dear, they should be deleted.

Comment: @quid They were interesting problems, as the voting scores say. Also the solutions were interesting. That is the lasting value. Anybody having the undelete vote privilege, can also see them.

Comment: The post is at score 0 (+3/-3). If that's your main argument it's pretty weak. (I did not even downvote myself.)

Comment: @quid There are many, significantly upvoted answers as well. And, citing the SE itself: *"we don't like to lose great answers"*.

Comment: @quid I don't understand your [sentence](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30342?noredirect=1#comment131162_30342) about the selectors. It is about the query? (The most important feature of the query, that here the post closures/deletions appear in the date as they happened, and not as the question was created. That made the query more complex, in exchange if a deletion rampage happens, it would be visible as a spike on it - even if the creation dates of the deleted posts were widely distributed in the years.)

Comment: Just because something gets a handful of up-votes it's not great. I detailed my opinion on the answers. Maybe you might realize that you are not at all well placed to judge their quality. The sentence referred to how certain posts were selected for deletion (via a query that searches for especially short questions). As said, your query is interesting, but that's mostly unrelated.

Comment: Here is an old discussion https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/under-what-circumstances-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-question-that-has-receive/16497#16497 You see all this is an "old hat." The punch-line: "To sum it up: closed questions can and should be deleted even if the have good but standard answers; only truly great answers should rather not be deleted. "

Comment: @quid While a significantly positive score of a post is not a guarantee that it is great, it is a guarantee that this is what the community likes to see. And you, as mod, should follow the consent of the community. The postulate of the SE model is that high score is the same as the high quality. This is obviously not entirely true - but it is enough close to the truth to keep the system working. And this is undermined by the massive deletions of upvoted posts without a prior consent, and this is what the SE *dislikes*, and with a good reason.

Comment: @quid A short question can be still good. The *length* of a question is obviously far worser signature of its quality, than its score (or score/view count). You are deleting short questions?

Comment: @quid Or do you think on the query? It only counts, and sums the score of its upvoted answers.

Comment: @peterh the short questions are not blindly deleted but they are reviewed for potential deletion. Well your question has 0 score [correction: -2 now], which leaves use were exactly. Five users thought they want the question closed. Maybe there view also should count for something. Of course they did not all bother to dv in addition, but there opinion seems to be clear. Kindly stop the cherry picking and the quoting of half-sentences. However you want to frame it, the thread is not good. Also the high score is a high quality is a gross over simplification, as everybody knows.

Comment: @quid 1) The "correction" (= two downs I've got) was caused by the "wise" "attention" of the meta community, just like the deletions of my posts. 2) I think you missed the point of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30342?noredirect=1#comment131175_30342). Please check it again. 3) Also the score of the answer matters in question deletion decisions, more clearly questions with good answers should not be deleted, and it is from the SE and not from some meta consent.

Comment: @peterh people evaluate your post and find it lacking. Of course you can pretend it's for other motives, but then way back then it was already closed. That some users upvoted the answer does not change that. It's well-known that often *almost* obvious stuff is especially well received because there are enough voters that can easily make sense of it.  Again the answer is not good in the way I believe good is intended there. It's a correct yet completely standard answer to simple and contrived question. The site is better without that thread.

Comment: I have edited the post ([revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2846931/revisions), the [version after my edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2846931/5)) in order to add at least [some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). I have not case my undelete vote - I'll wait first to hear whether you are satisfied with the edit and leave some time for you if you want to edit it further.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It is pretty okay! Thank you very much help in this very important recovery task!

Answer (score -5):

> **[Undeleted,reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1993009/revisions)**

- [Is the sum of singular and nonsingular matrix always a nonsingular matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993009/is-the-sum-of-singular-and-nonsingular-matrix-always-a-nonsingular-matrix)
- [archive.org backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307180930/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993009/is-the-sum-of-singular-and-nonsingular-matrix-always-a-nonsingular-matrix)

+6 question with thousands of views and with two, +18 answers. Created in 2016, deleted last week.

Found by the SEDE query [Suspicious question deletions from the last week](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1058887/suspicious-question-deletions-from-the-last-week).

Comment: Standard solve-my-problem-without-me post, and nothing spectacular about the answers. I oppose undeletion.

Comment: @T.Bongers To me, it is absolutely non-trivial, if the sum of a singular and a nonsingular matrix is always nonsingular. The example in the accepted answer was catartic to me. Your attitude would be probably acceptable on the MO, but that is another site. Here sub-phd, maybe even pre-grad level questions are allowed, and **you should view the quality and usefulness of a question on the level for which it is written, and not on yours**.

Comment: I have no idea at what level the question was written (and neither do you), because the asker never bothered to say anything at all beyond the statement of the problem. This is not a do-my-homework site, regardless of how little quality control some users want.

Comment: @T.Bongers Maybe the user 1) is enough educated to be able to think about, is the sum singular and nonsingular matrix always nonsingular 2) But he is not enough well educated to know its answer? Is it enough narrow to know, who is he? Hm? Or should he have attached his CV to his question as well?

Comment: This isn't a case for some hyperbolic slippery slope argument, and you know that. If the question had context, it could be appropriate for the site.

Comment: @T.Bongers The required "context" what you would want so strongly, is clearly visible in the post. And you know that. This is a typical case of the **dark direction** what you made from this once so friendly and open site.

Comment: I disagree with T.Bongers's comment: "Standard solve-my-problem-without-me post..." In what "standard", if exists at all, for a site "that is for people studying math *at any level* and professionals in related fields"? I disagree with the deletion in a way that I would strongly disagree with (possible in the future) deletion of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2709335/9464) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654019/9464) "standard" exercises (created 2016 and 2018) T.Bongers answered (nicely!).

Comment: @Jack Thanks for bringing those posts to my attention; I agree with your judgement of the first one (but not the second), and have started a close vote. I would delete my answer if I could, but it was accepted. Of course, it's clear that your comment is a disingenuous off-topic attempt to poison the well by calling me a hypocrite. So it goes.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Thank you for your message. "it's clear that your comment is a disingenuous off-topic attempt to poison the well by calling me a hypocrite." Please don't put any word into my mouth that I did not say at all. I am sorry that you think it in that way. I do mean what I said and I do NOT mean to be sarcastic at all. Since we are talking about "deletion", I don't think my previous comment is off-topic. And yes, if you or others were going to vote to *delete* the linked posts that you answered, I would disagree and vote to undelete.

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone to keep it civil.

Answer (score -5):

Please undelete and reopen this elementary post:
[How to find the value of the expression $\log_3(a)+\log_3(b)+\log_3(c)$ given that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the roots of $24x^3 - 121x^2 + 87x - 8 = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3172501/9464)

I answered question in this post, and I do not consider it missing context at all. OP summarized his/her attempt succinctly in the post: "Finding the roots seems complicated." (If one can find the roots $a$, $b$ and $c$, one can of course plug them into the expression $\log_3(a)+\log_3(b)+\log_3(c)$ to find its value. This is a natural attempt. OP did not notice that one does not need to solve the cubic equation in order to solve this problem.) Such attempt is by no means "I tried to solve this problem myself, but it seemed complicated."

Comment: I will reiterate the comment I left before the question was deleted: I have read the question. The comment you cite does not seem to provide much context. Nearly any question on this site could be finished with the line "I tried to solve this problem myself, but it seemed complicated." Appropriate context would be, for example, a description of where this problem comes from, and what the asker is studying right now. A presentation of potentially relevant theorems and definitions would also provide context.

Comment: Moreover, the question has also been negatively received (while I don't usually consider voting on a question to be terribly compelling, it is a factor which should be considered), and neither of the answers is terribly compelling (J.G.'s answer has the advantage of being concise, while Jack's answer seems like overkill to me---why invoke Vieta's formulae (the question appears to be a question one might find in an elementary algebra class, though that context is missing; Vieta is, to the best of my knowledge, not generally taught in these kinds of classes).

Comment: Finally, @Jack, you insist that the question has context because the asker stated "Finding the roots seems complicated."  Let us grant, for the sake of argument, that this is context.  I do not see how it is *sufficient* context.  Better context would be an indication of what the student is studying and and what level; a reference for the problem; a discussion of what theorems, definitions, or other results they know; etc.  The point of asking for "work done" is to get an indication of the level of the student.  In this case, knowing that they tried to find the roots doesn't give much insight.

Answer (score -5):

**[Undeleted, Deleted, Undeleted, Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3530529/revisions)**

This question on Laplace Transform has been deleted for no real reason. OP has showed some of his work. So there is no reason to delete this topic. Vote to undelete. Thanks.

We still need a single vote to undelete. Thanks in advance.

[Laplace Transform $\left(\frac{\cos \sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530529/help-with-laplace-transformation/3531048#3531048)

Comment: (1) The user presented two problem statements, not a single question.  (2) The user did not (contrary to your assertion) demonstrate any work---they claimed to have done some work, but did not actually demonstrate any of that work.  (3) The user provided no other context, such as a source for the problem, basic definitions... anything, really.  (4) Finally, it is poor form to ask for undeletion of a question which you have answered without disclosing your interest in the problem.  You are not an impartial third party, as  you stand to benefit from the undeletion.

Comment: Op said he used power series to solve one of the question but couldn't solve the second one . Both questions are related as I have shown in my answer. @XanderHenderson

Comment: (1) "Serie" is not a word.  (2) The user *claims* to have done a thing.  That doesn't  mean that they have *demonstrated* that thing.  Claiming to have done a thing does  not provide any context for the problem.  (3) So what if the problems are related?   The user did none of the work necessary to demonstrate that relation.  The "question" is presented as two isolated problems.  It is the job of the asker to explain how the problems are related; it is not the job of the answerers to provide that context for the asker.

Comment: I meant OP used power series. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: **No**. The user **claimed** to have used power series. A 2-year-old also can claim to use power series just because their big brother said so. Notice that you refused to address any of the 3 points @XanderHenderson brought up.

Answer (score -8):

[Ratio problem for aptitude exam in India [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3182806/111704)

None of the questions was eligible for a deletion, and also their closure reason is highly problematic.