# On Hold/Closed for broad or unclear, Then edited, then...

Tags: support, allowed-questions, closing, on-hold-questions

Kinda [dumb/n00b/challenging conventional wisdom question](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/), but what is the procedure for questions that are on hold or closed for being broad or unclear and then edited to hopefully become less broad or more clear?

I'm actually also trying to find out, like, if my question is not re-opened after sometime after some edit for improvement, then that means my question needs further editing for improvement.

Comment: Note that the first edit after being closed puts the question into the [reopen queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) while subsequent edits will not, so you should try to make your first edit count! If your question has lacked sufficient attention to get reopened, you may wish to [post your case here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ayt thanks! ^-^ Post as answer? I'll suck in the 3 downvotes for the sake of honouring you.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I understand voting is different on meta, but that means that the downvoters disagree with this question - that they somehow feel that a closed question should remain closed *even if edited*! Surely not?! [Or am I reading to much into the downvotes?]

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for the support =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that the first edit after being closed puts the question into the reopen queue while subsequent edits will not, so you should try to make your first edit count! If your question has lacked sufficient attention to get reopened, you may wish to post your case here. – Simply Beautiful Art

In order to honor Simply Beautiful Art, I will leave [this downvoted question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28863/) undeleted.