# Does this question deserve to be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Here is a question [A property of the tangent line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238468/a-property-of-the-tangent-line) that I asked where I was confused on the matter "what is the property that characterises a tangent line" and I thought that this property is that the tangent line touches the curve only once, but as has been clarified by the answer (  which is very fine ) to my question that this property is coincidental property due to a deeper property of curves ( Bezout's Theorem ).

All is good and I edited the question, so It became clear what was my confusion. And the answer given does actually answer my question. And still my question gets closed! What is so wrong with my question so it's worthy of getting  closed?

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question. The question seems to be clear now, and Arturo's answer is insightful as always. The question could use a better title though. "A property of the tangent line" is too generic in my opinion.

Comment: Very often when a Question is not stated in the best way, it will be closed (placed "on-hold") pending improvements.  Some of the underlying tension in how you originally framed the Question is still reflected in the Comments on it.  In any case the Question was closed about one day after it was asked, and you've had time to improve it (with the help of others).  In its present form I think it's a reasonably good post.  In the future consider using the [dedicated reopening thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today).

Comment: Status update: The question is reopened.