# Is it possible to downvote a deleted post?

Tags: bug, down-votes, voting

I happen to notice that someone seemed to be able to downvote a [deleted post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30441/9464).

How could this be possible? Or is it a system bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW SEDE also shows score 30 for that question: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/845254/deleted-questions-with-high-score-in-a-specific-tag?number=100&Tagname=probability Although I am not sure whether this is going to be changed after the next update of the database, or whether in the PostsWithDeleted table the score from the time of deletion is shown.

Comment: What _can_ be done to a deleted post is to keep posting comments! (moderators) \\ When I saw a mod comment on one of my old deleted meta questions I was like wow! (I received the notification). Not sure if you already knew about this tho

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No one.

But you need to differentiate between downvoting a post, and an upvote being invalidated. Accounts get deleted all the time for various reasons (e.g. self-deletions), and when those accounts have not made "a lot of impact", their votes are invalidated.

I don't know if this is the case here, but that seems as the most likely scenario.