# A question bouncing in and out of the delete graveyard

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[Are there a finite number of trees with $k$ leaves and no vertices of degree $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401393/are-there-a-finite-number-of-trees-with-k-leaves-and-no-vertices-of-degree-2)

In the 35 days or so since this question was asked, it has been closed, deleted twice, undeleted twice, and is currently has one vote towards its third deletion.  I'm new to the 10,000 rep club, but this seems like a lack of communication more than anything.

As someone new to deletion powers, can someone help me understand why this post should be deleted so single-mindedly that undeleting it twice put it back in someone's radar for re-deletion?  (Contrarily, someone might discuss why it is worth undeleting such that deleting it twice put it back in someone's radar for re-undeletion.)

(Disclaimer: the reason this particular post is on *my* radar is because I wrote the well-written, accepted, and upvoted answer.  The yoyoing doesn't seem to have an impact on my rep, but I feel like I'm a little proud of the answer and think that the OP made a fair attempt to discuss solution strategies that didn't work.)

Comment: I don't think having a "well-writen, accepted, and upvoted answer" really affects the view of those who voted to delete it, after all it was already mentioned (by atleast some from [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude)) that a good answer is not sufficient to retain a poor question. In the future if you see a good answer and worth keeping context  to a deleted question, you can also post a link to it in [GENTLE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle) so perhaps the post can be undeleted if others feels the same.

Comment: If you think a question is salvageable, use your hard earned edit privilege and improve it. That has worked for me very well in the past. Do check for duplicates first. Mostly to avoid wasting your time.

Comment: FWIW I would not vote to delete that thread. It may or may not be a duplicate (I don't frequent graph-theory), but it definitely is not a FAQ. Unlike the hundreds or thousands of limits that all can be solved by using Taylor series and add nothing worthy to the site.

Comment: @Jyrki I am confused I think you did [vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3401393/revisions) to delete the post, indeed twice?

Comment: LOL. I did not recognize/remember it after the edit had improved it. Thanks for keeping me honest @ArcticChar. Anyway, I posted my reaction to the current version. See the effect editing a PSQ has!

Comment: To be fair it did look a bit different now that some context was added. @jyrki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every user with 10k+ reputation can vote to delete closed questions, and undelete deleted questions. There is essentially no restriction on that. Unlike close/open votes, the same users can cast delete/undelete votes as many times as they like on the same post. So it is not uncommon to see delete/undelete wars.

I think most users believe that good content should be kept and bad content should be deleted. They just cannot agree on what is good.

The question you linked to is what is called a PSQ (problem statement question). It has only the problem and (almost) no motivation/background/effort. Some consider this a bad content.

Specific questions attract more votes when they are put on meta (like you just did) or in chatroom. As Martin [pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52691715#52691715), that linked question was discussed in both CRUDE and GENTLE, the two chat rooms that deal with deletion/undeletion of posts. Posts linked in [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) also attract lots of delete/undelete votes, as you can check in that thread.

It is just two rounds of deletion/undeletion and probably the moderators will not intervene. Sometimes the moderators will step in and lock the post when clearly both sides cannot stop the delete/undelete war.

Comment: Thank you for the perspective!  I suppose my point of view is that an answered question should be valued in the context of a person several years in the future who comes here with the same problem.  If the question is well tagged and titled and the search engine can find it, then that future person will either not have to post or will get a duplicate to the answer.  On the other hand, if the question is deleted, then the future person will definitely post.  But I suppose if there was only one philosophy of site management there wouldn't be a need for an undelete chat room.  ^_^

Comment: This is in the assumption that the question is not already a duplicate. @MatthewDaly For questions that have been post more than 20 times (this is not uncommon in calculus, linear algebra...), it is better to delete some version and direct others to the best ones (the one with lots of great answers in different angles, like those with the tag "FAQ"). The more mediocre post are in MSE, the harder to direct others to the best ones.