# Why is this question completely disappearing where I have answered and got a bounty of 200?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, deletion

The hidden question was:

**New numeration system, mapping to binary numeration system**

Where I have answered with the copyright notice that must be always respected and not only for my topics, and my answer was reworded by a bounty of 200

How is this possible on this site where I do refer to my published answer on your site for other purposes of investigational cases about new mathematical discoveries and publish them on other sites for public attention and awareness

I do still expect a legal explanation from others or moderators for such an action since I have given an answer up to my best efforts and knowledge where I never expected to be hidden and soon may be claimed by others as well

Kindly, don't hide my this legal inquiry like so many other topics of mine that had been hidden in so many mathematical sections at SE where not a single convincing reason was provided by all the moderators who deliberately have hidden so many other true proven discoveries of mine and since many years as well

However, I do have printed copies of my deleted issues that will be soon exposed in other opened mind sites for further investigations and true historical purposes about so many fundamental issues in mathematics

Bassam Karzeddin

Comment: Again, the same irrelevant habit, downvoting anonymously then deleting then hiding the whole issue as if nobody had ever heard of, or saw before and later stealing secretly the whole issue in so much of devilish untrusted professional many methods, but here the case is so different, and this is a question also printed already, and I don't think it is of any moral that someone gets reworded one day and be stolen in the second day, it is truly a big scandal for the entire system  and how its main purpose has become on how to steal amateurs true talents and keep safe the documented ignorance,

Comment: If you insist to hide it here, then this topic is going to be publically published in other less moderated and unmoderated sites and exactly as it happened without adding or subtracting a word, and we know that those anonymous downvoters have the most interest in hiding these topics for their own purposes, but they don't know yet that most of the populations have already become more expert people in their own fields of no true mathematics, simply observe the thousands of repeated unanswered questions asked by clever school kids  say on Quora   for example, and soon they will invade you too

Comment: community moderation is allowed here ... can't deal with it, you are free to leave.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477718/new-numeration-system-mapping-to-binary-numeration-system?r=SearchResults

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thank you for your feedback but isn't truly so strange act by moderators that a question with 9 upvotes and one answer with a bounty of 200, gets completely hidden even from my own profile, without informing the participant or even commenting or providing any valid reason for such act, I wish to know what was wrong in the question or even in the answer to delete both of them without any obvious reasons except the three moderators agreements? Does a moderator have this unlimited right on this site? wonders, at any case, it is going to be publically published in many other sites

Comment: free use policy might have a say there about copyright materials. 
cop·y·right
/ˈkäpēˌrīt/
Learn to pronounce
noun
the exclusive legal right, given to an originator or an assignee to print, publish, perform, film, or record literary, artistic, or musical material, and to authorize others to do the same.  trade·mark
/ˈtrādˌmärk/
Learn to pronounce
noun
a symbol, word, or words legally registered or established by use as representing a company or product.

Comment: You sound worse than a crank ( I am one). Being amateur has it's perks ( you can relate things they might not remember to things you've just learned and help everyone), that being said, it's important you know about the site you use to do these things.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee and as long as I don't legally copy-right them, then others are freely allowed to steal them under the sunlight and before everyone's own eyes, isn't it true this way working these days with academic professionals,? no wonder, as if the copyrighted mathematics is even true mathematics, and from the forged fake history of mathematics they show nobilities and homesites to unbelievable limits of keeping the original handwriting of genius dead boys in museums as a witness for such alleged nobility for usually dead people as always as usual with this forgotten unnoticible liy word

Comment: Moderators had nothing to do with it, Bassam. Your answer was deleted by the votes of three users, not moderators.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can see only one downvote and usually by the same moderators, but the problem isn't in this case of deleting my answer or question since this happened with my contents almost so many times with most of my contents, the problem here is so peculiar where a moderator decides to remove an answer that had been already reworded by a bounty of 200 (around 10 upvotes), and not only that but removing the upvoted question with 9 upvotes and the lonely reworded answer even from its originator and so unlike many other deletions to my contents that are still visible to me, Why all that?

Comment: Your answer was **not** removed by a moderator. Three users, **not** moderators, voted to delete your answer – **not** downvoted your answer, but voted to **delete** your answer – and that was enough to delete your answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson And so strangely, in my case those users can't say a word, and not only in that issue but with many other deleted topics, as if they could delete the proven facts, see here for example how only in one answer I could at least convince 14 persons that $\pi$ isn't a number as per this link: https://www.quora.com/When-and-who-was-the-first-to-break-mathematics/answer/Bassam-Karzeddin-1,  whereas I could convince many other hundreds in different similar answers with irrefutable rigorous proofs, where those would ultimately come here and everywhere else to make them understand  truth

Comment: If you were able to convince fourteen people that $\pi$ isn't a number, that just proves there are fourteen very stupid people on quora. Anyway, you can make a case for your answer to be undeleted at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today

Comment: @GerryMyerson The main problem with Quora is that downvotes are not recorded. OP could have 10000 downvotes but none of us would know. I suspect OP's true problem is the idea that OP thinks that there is some true math, and axiomatization is a fallacious attempt by mathematicians to reach it. Sadly, someone with this mindset can't be reached.

Comment: @Gerry Myers-on, why do you think so, just express your in mind numbers without a decimal notation but in fractions and see whether your best approximation methods like (Cushy sequence, Dedekind cuts, limits, convergence, intermediate no theorem, ..., etc) would ever be capable to give you many uncountable numbers that are strictly less than $\sqrt{2}$, and make sure that is absolutely perpetual an impossible no matter what would you jump to conclude, where true math was never based on conclusions, just because the real number isn't a matter of human false definitions or wrong decisions, sure

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-the-ethical-honesty-nobility-exist-in-todays-opened-world-among-academic-professional-experts-of-logic-philosophy-pure-physics-and-more-especially-in-mathematics-towards-armatures-public-published-discoveries/answer/Bassam-Karzeddin-1                                                                              This is the case with false maths, where also Qoura would never show you many answers that were reported by so many academic anonymous mathematicians who can't defend their mathematics but want simply protect their old wrong inherited and refuted beliefs

Comment: @DonThousand The real number is simply an existing distance relative to any arbitrary existing unity distance, the true existing number hence can be theoretically and exactly constructed, it is never a matter of human definitions but a matter of discovery, thus the real number is only the constructible number, they are space properties, hope this link is visible on Qoura: https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-natural-numbers-start-with-two-to-be-more-consistent-with-the-space-properties-that-are-only-positive-constructible-numbers/answer/Bassam-Karzeddin-1,

Comment: So what is a distance? You aren't going to win this game, my guy. BTW, there actually is a field of constructible numbers. I think you might like those.

Comment: @DonThousand This is  truly not any game, it is an old finished story about real number discovery by that Pythagorian who was thrown to see, but people again repeated the same old tragedy when expressing the true discovered irrational numbers by their decimal rational numbers and never being aware that even the decimal rational field is also endless field, thus mimicking the older Pythagoreans who didn't tolerate the discovery by going back to Euclidean rational numbers and up to date, and innocently being deceived about non-real numbers like those transedential and algebraic numbers (non-c)

Comment: So what is distance? You haven't answered my question :)

Comment: @DonThousand Please look around and see momentary space you are feeling that you are inside it, it is simply three orthogonal distances like XYZ-Axis, where a distance exists in the form of true existing numbers relative to any arbitrary existing unity distance, where also none of the shortest and longest distances ever exist, and this space is endless in both directions outwardly and inwardly as well, where numbers are only space properties that are strictly created from the true one and never by that human mind fake (but no one) like this $(0.999...)$, one is the only true creator of numbers

Comment: You're relying on "feeling"? You've lost before you've even begun. Because I feel like $\pi$ is a distance. What are you going to do about it :P

Comment: Honestly, there's nothing wrong with just wanting to deal with constructible numbers. A lot of math happens within the space of algebraic, or constructible numbers. Do math there, I guess, if that's your happy place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103324/discussion-between-bassam-karzeddin-and-don-thousand).

Comment: @DonThousand, A distance is a number, where the (shortest and longes) distances don't strictly exist, hence zero isn't a number, and if the distance is the shortest between two distinct locations then it has the same number line prosperity, where three orthogonal distances intersecting at a location form the physical space properties that is existing momentary as a state of mind as nothingness, and any distance that is not expressed exactly in constructible numbers don't exist, thus ($\sqrt[3]{2}, \pi$) aren't any existing distances, hence they aren't any real numbers, but we imagine them so

Comment: I hope you understand that just stating things doesn't make them true. Anyways, I don't get why you waste so much time rehashing things you've said a dozen times. Yes, we get it, you only think constructible numbers are platonic.

Comment: @BassamKarzeddin Also, you haven't defined constructible numbers. How would you define that, given that you use it in "proving" that $0$ and $\pi$ aren't real. Can you prove to me that you can construct $1$?

Answer (score 8):

> Kindly, don't hide my this legal inquiry like so many other topics of mine that had been hidden in so many mathematical sections at SE where not a single convincing reason was provided by all the moderators who deliberately have hidden so many other true proven discoveries of mine and since many years as well

Nobody has hidden any true discoveries of yours. You can post all you like on [viΧra](http://vixra.org), and no one here will attempt to stop you. And don't claim you have a "legal inquiry" when you don't.

> However, I do have printed copies of my deleted issues that will be soon exposed in other opened mind sites for further investigations and true historical purposes about so many fundamental issues in mathematics

What is getting exposed now is your attitude towards the mathematical community. And "opened mind" ≠ "open-minded".

> If you insist to hide it here, then this topic is going to be publically published in other less moderated and unmoderated sites and exactly as it happened without adding or subtracting a word, and we know that those anonymous downvoters have the most interest in hiding these topics for their own purposes, but they don't know yet that most of the populations have already become more expert people in their own fields of no true mathematics, simply observe the thousands of repeated unanswered questions asked by clever school kids say on Quora for example, and soon they will invade you too

Is that a threat? Do you see any real mathematician hiding your posts "for their own purposes"? And what are "fields of no true mathematics"? If a field is of "no true mathematics", what good is it for anyone to become experts in it?

> This is the case with false maths, where also Qoura would never show you many answers that were reported by so many academic anonymous mathematicians who can't defend their mathematics but want simply protect their old wrong inherited and refuted beliefs

What is your evidence that it is others who have "old wrong inherited and refuted beliefs"?

> This is truly not any game, it is an old finished story about real number discovery by that Pythagorian who was thrown to see, but people again repeated the same old tragedy when expressing the true discovered irrational numbers by their decimal rational numbers and never being aware that even the decimal rational field is also endless field, thus mimicking the older Pythagoreans who didn't tolerate the discovery by going back to Euclidean rational numbers and up to date, and innocently being deceived about non-real numbers like those transedential and algebraic numbers (non-c)

There is a **rigorous** and **precise** mathematical definition of "real number" and "algebraic number" and "transcendental number", and there are many transcendental real numbers. And... $0$ is an algebraic real number. If you have some other idea of "number", then you are **not** talking about real numbers, and it is your **responsibility** to define what you mean, rather than call others "deceived".

> I never trust the honesty, Nobility of any moderated site or any other official mathematical authorities like the alleged top-most repuitable Journals and Universities in such a very huge big issues based on personal long experience with their human orientations for unnecessary business and human normal physicology

If you don't trust Math SE, leave instead of insulting the community here. And there is no such thing as "physicology". Moderation is necessary in any functional community, [otherwise...](https://sci.math.narkive.com/pJ2WZbBU/are-most-of-the-named-angels-in-mathematics-truly-don-t-exist-at-all#post29)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/31135/edit , can this link be visible or must be hidden again from public visibility?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: 21820, please go to sci. math if you are interested to know about all your wrong math definition about a true real number, here is a traditional moderated site devoted to all kinds of old human knowledge where anything new and revolutionary is strictly not permissible by the vast majorities of the academic mainstreams, this site can't tolerate a free opinion and many people know this fact about it, they simply hide great discoveries where eventually and soon would be shamed about it, sorry to tell you  that your common understanding isn't any different from almost all acadimics, noyhing

Comment: Please yourself go. I am not interested in all your wrong math.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see,

- Potential to cite later = proof you were first.
- Questions and Answers no longer are creators property by site decorum.
- Copyright notice, is a way to be marked as spam as you're simply avertizing your own services.
- If the answer was simply a rant, like your comments, it has potential to be marked as not an answer.
- If you don't believe the history of math, then debate that at history of math and science not here
- etc.

Comment: This site is not a discovery sharing site.

Comment: @BassamKarzeddin I suggest a therapist, honestly. Learning how to accept that you are wrong is a wonderful ability. The world definitely has its flaws but no one has time to create a conspiracy to hide your findings.

Comment: @DonThousand I truly do suggest for you and for everyone else interested in human axiomatic false definitions based on choices rather than proven facts to see that their short definitions are simply not better than many wrong decisions where  a numerical counterexample based on natural numbers would certainly show the falsehood concepts they have invented are simply broken, and to see it more clearly just say if there is an existing real root for such an odd degree polynomial $(x^{49} = x^7 + 1)$, where I do claim (with many elementary proofs) that no real root ever exists, hence no any root

Comment: @DonThousand   If one is truly is lucky enough to understand only that this single polynomial of $(x^{49 - x^7 - 1 = 0)$ is impossible to have any real existing root in true real existing numbers, then certainly and immediately would realize many more important things that are false in the core foundation stone of the modern mathematics about all my alleged and proven claims, like the false hypothesis of continuity of real numbers, the false imaginary numbers, the false real numbers that aren't constructible, ..., etc, it is truly the greatest chances ever made for new true honest Nobel resrs.

Comment: @DonThousand Let me hope that you have got my concept about the non-existence of any real number assumed with infinite terms or digits, and regardless of any human axioms that are also valid actually for engineering earthy problem solutions approximations where it doesn't require the perfection of true math since they were solely discovered by scientists and engineers for the solutions of their own problems, see this: https://www.quora.com/Is-this-triangle-with-sides-3-4-4-999-a-right-angle-triangle/answer/Bassam-Karzeddin-1?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__sncid__=3899385754&__snid3__=6390474697

Comment: What is your definition of a "real number". I have a good feeling, based on your writings, that your definition is vastly different from how mathematicians define it.

Comment: @DonThousand As I did say before, the real number is an impossible definition by any intelligent beings but a matter of pure discovery, where that discovery had already finished since thousands of years ago by the Pythagorean theorem only, and numbers are the perpetual existing being created from no number one since the true creator of numbers can't be a number like them, hence would be strictly  violated once being (multiplied, divisible, powered) by them,  but can be truly added to them to recreate more of them, either directly or by true angeling to create the true irrational we can't deny

Comment: @BassamKarzeddin And there you go. The moment you say that the real numbers can't be defined, you aren't doing math. Because they are defined. You just object to them being defined based on your platonic ideals. Honestly, if that's what you want to do, fine, so be it. But don't claim that you are doing math, because you aren't. Math is based on definitions and axioms. Not "discovery" (Discoveries can be used to build intuition to do math, but aren't in themselves math)

Comment: @DonThousand, what did I claim that real numbers were already discovered being existing numbers thus can be exactly constructed, in short, real numbers are constructible numbers and nothing else, In my public published profiles on sci. math and few on Quora (that are strictly forbidden to be shown on this site, where they deleted them without providing a single reasonable reason) I have provided around 10 elementary proofs about the fact of non-existence of other alleged real numbers, but since they contradict the academic  mainstream  old concepts then they always get rid of them not wanting

Comment: Even with answers like the deleted below which got a bounty of 200 points, they delete the answer trying to protect something too important for every school students such that nobody should know anything about the proven fallibility of too many concepts in modern math., but luckily a very large number of clever school students had already got them where they are raining the Quora math section with their same question like my contents to the limit that the professional academic mathematicians have become suddenly too reluctant to answer them the way they were used to before, but keeping silent

Comment: It seems ridiculous to me this strange silent insistence by moderators not only to hide my reworded answer with 200 bounties (illegally) which was repeated here and also deleted for no stated convincing reason so far, but they insist also to hide the complete profile of mine for no obvious or written reasons, where once i asked why to delete my full profile on this link:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31284/why-does-the-full-profile-of-mine-at-math-overflow-completely-disappear-without?noredirect=1#comment137343_31284 The Moderators delete the question, not wanting anyone to

Comment: know anything about the issue, it is very mysterious to me since I have already exposed this type of traditional practice by the common moderator's sensitivity towards their many elementary fundamental wrongs beliefs about so many basic issues in mathematics, where that illustration to such incomprehensible behaviors had been published on Quora, sci. math (where no one can delete), twitter and alike for people to care placing their best achievements in such untrusted sites, due to the very narrow minds of moderators towards many well-proven and superior mathematics that they are against.