# A deleted question had 9 undelete votes and still stayed deleted. How could this happen?

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions

I noted a question that had 9 undelete votes, yet it was still deleted, and it was deleted by 10 people. Logically one could expect that it requires 10 votes to undelete, but the question still remains as to why there were 10 in the first place.

Comment: I edited to make the question more generally applicable. If there are language issues,or alike, please correct them as you see fit.

Comment: @quid The edit is fine, but I rather disapprove of what you've done to the question I asked about.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback regarding the edit. Regarding the question, your disapproval is not unexpected, but I think the question should stay deleted.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the question OP asked about was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659982/does-the-law-of-cosines-contradict-pythagorass-theorem (out of curiosity, Matt, why did you delete https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31540/8269 ?).

Comment: @Gerry The only one who could undo it was a moderator. I figured it would fall on deaf ears.

Comment: @quid Can you please justify this deletion? (Although the question is low-level, this is meant to be a site for all levels.)

Comment: @user1729 this discussion is off-topic in this thread. In any case the question had been deleted for a long time already. It's state prior to this post was restored. If anything let us discuss (at an appropriate place) if it should have been undeleted. [Crucialy note it is a duplicate and the discussion on the question itself.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of votes needed to delete a question is at least three, but can be up to ten, depending on the score of the question and the attached answers. In this case the question needed ten votes (the maximum) to be delete.

The same is then true for the number of undelete votes.

For those that want the details:

> Popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined as: question score + top-scored answer score. For example, a question with (question score 15 + top answer score 5 = 20) will require 4 deletion votes (3 base votes + 1 popularity vote).
>
> The maximum number of delete votes needed will not exceed 10.
>
> Note that the above rules apply only to questions; answers take 3 votes, regardless of score.

Quoted from [Jarrod Dixon's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/) to [Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)