# Can we have a smarter serial voting detection?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, serial-voting

Serial voting simply because of disagreement of *opinions* is toxic in the main site. While deduction of a few points does not (maybe it does) matter a lot for the victim, in the long run, **however**, it significantly misleads future readers of the site:

- it mistakenly signals that a post is problematic **while it is really not**.
- for some advanced questions that are not viewed by many users (and thus not many votes), it attempted to make a [broken window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

Here is an example of a user who posted a [question on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31606/780640) recently and was attacked by serial voting:
[image]

Two old well-written relatively advanced questions that have very few views (148 and 86 respectively) today were downvoted *within an hour*:

- [Notations in Functional Analysis: $L^p$, $L_p$, $\mathscr{L}^p$, $\mathscr{L}_p$, $\mathcal{L}^p$, and $\mathcal{L}_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035819/notations-in-functional-analysis-lp-l-p-mathscrlp-mathscrl-p)
- [Dimension of a Subspace of $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{W})$ Consisting of Only Linear Transformations of Rank $\leq r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3396449/780640)

This situation is highly impossible to be random. However, such a number of "smart" votes cannot be detected by the system serial voting detector since technically it has yet to be "serial".

Can we have a smarter detector?

Comment: The mentioned user was also downvoted right on the day when he posted his question on meta.

Comment: I didn't care about the reputation.  It doesn't feed me.  I just don't like that some people hate it when you disagree with them, and they take it personally.

Comment: Is two downvotes on a user's post considered serial voting?

Comment: @ArcticChar You might wanna check the times. One was at 16:42:20 and the other was at 16:42:04. I did also have this problem, some weeks ago (although more downvotes). And the funny thing is that 'suspicious' user is the same...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut nop. It's public info. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72152/batominovski?tab=reputation

Comment: @Magic_Isa Oh! I didn't know that. A shame, after 7 years! Thanks :)

Comment: @Magic_Isa: That's not a big issue. If for example some user visit this page, open those two posts and vote on them within the following 24 hours. Shoud it be considered serial voting?

Comment: @ArcticChar: within the following 24 hours?, nop, it would be unlikely to consider only 2 downvotes (isolated) as an abuse. But that example doesn't apply here. See the difference between the downvotes were _seconds_, 16 seconds.

Comment: What are the justifications? That 2 votes in 16 seconds is bad? I can read and understand those two questions in 1 minute and vote on it. Is that serial voting?  Say 1 min. @Magic_Isa

Comment: @ArcticChar: Let's be realistic, how in the world someone would downvote such questions? one first and 16 seconds later the other. You say, it would take you 1 minute to read and understand both, well, :) that's wow. But even you, it would take you like 30 sec for each, not 16 sec.

Comment: I could definitely down-vote the first question. I don't think that question is meaningful/interesting without further context. Just like people used $x_i$ and $x^i$ for coordinates. @Magic_Isa (And I never only talk about downvotes. What if someone upvote those two posts within 1 min? Is that serial?)

Comment: By now three users have upvote each question, most likely just because of this meta post. The unnecessary linking creates more issues as regards the "honest" score than what it points to as problem ever did.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Two posts by the same user, 6 months and 16 months old, being down voted within seconds of each other? I don't know how much a deal it is worth making, or what the best way to deal with it is, but someone is targeting that user. Plus, the $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{W})$ question is very well written - heck, having been called to my attention I just gave it an upvote -- there's no reason to down vote it.

Comment: @Magic_Isa tangentially, there seems to be an inaccuracy in your reasoning.  The time between the votes corresponds to the time for one question not two. Read Q1. Vote1. Read Q2. Vote2.

Comment: @quid Can you read & understand the Q1 or Q2  _and_ then downvote, all in 16 seconds? // Tangentially I was addressing Arctic Char's wow comments. He/she said that they could read & understand all in 1 minute.

Comment: You don't need to read it word by word understand the question. @Magic_Isa

Comment: @Magic_Isa my point is that I do not need to do all this in order to cast two votes within  16 seconds, I'd have twice the time. If they read both in a minute the distance between the votes would likely be 30 seconds. Maybe that seems short but actually relative to the time some users take to review posts it's not all that short. Don't get me wrong I am far from claiming that it is a model case for best practice in downvoting. But it's not that strange. Some users might open several tabs read variosu questions and then vote. Many things are possible. But, actually, none of that was my point.

Comment: @Magic_Isa I never commented on the situation specifically, I explained to you that there is a fallacy in your reasoning. Voting within x seconds on two questions suggest that the two were treated in 2x seconds, not in x seconds as you suggest. That's an abstract point independent of any specific judgement of the current situation. The closest I came to judging the current situation is by saying " I am far from claiming that it is a model case for best practice in downvoting", which is if anything a critique.

Comment: Or still more concretely it means that the second question was treated in x seconds. The time taken to treat the first questions does not enter at all as the voting usually will happen after the first question was read and understood. @Magic_Isa

Comment: @quid you're right. "The time taken to treat the first questions does not enter at all"

Comment: I will supply another instance that I can remember.  On August 25, 2018, I posted a comment under a question suggesting the OP of that question how the question might be solved.  A user replied to my comment telling me that I should make my comment an answer, rather than a comment.  I responded telling that user that I didn't have an answer, I just had an idea how to solve the problem, but didn't know if it would work.  I received two downvotes on two of my questions immediately on that day after this disagreement.  The disagreement wasn't even intense.

Comment: Also this doesn't seem a case of serial downvoting (some reasons are mentioned above by quid) but a case of target downvoting, where this user got downvoted after an arguing or did something that made the downvoter do that. From [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54255611#54255611) public conversation it seems that there are two reasons for downvoting, one that the posts are mediocre and the other one because the user complained (more like a side-reason, but I can be wrong).

Comment: @Zacky  Everybody can say that a post they downvoted was mediocre (and since this is a subjective opinion, I have no criticism of this claim).  However, but if one looks for another user's posts to downvote because of an argument (even if the posts were indeed mediocre), that is not a sportmanship behavior.  This should not be tolerated.  My argument with one user has resulted in me being the user's downvoting target more than twice (thrice if you counted my META incident as two because the downvoting happened on two different days).

Comment: I can try to search for another incident, but I can't remember when it happened.  I didn't flag that one particular incident, so it will be very difficult to extract that one out of my history.

Comment: @Batominovski as it can be seen from that message it wasn't tolerated: " But I can't downvote any complainer's post even twice in one day, even when they are poor to mediocre, **without receiving a warning**" so I propose to deescalate the discussion. Mainly my point is that this example is not serial downvoting, but something else.

Comment: @Zacky  I am not planning to interact with the user in the future, so there's that.  However, as in my comment about the August 25, 2018 incident, it didn't take a heated discussion for me to be a target (the discussion wasn't even initiated by me).  Just one innocent comment was enough.  I still have the link to that one chat, but I don't think it is appropriate to broadcast this here.  (It is still public but it would be very hard for anyone not knowing about the incident to find it.)

Comment: @Zacky  Downvotes usually don't bother me.  Not everybody is going to like my answers or questions, and that's what I accept.  The point of my complaints about these incidences are not really about downvotes, but about the revengeful behavior.  And the quote "I can't downvote any complainer's post [...]" sounds unethical.  Just because you complain about something, do you deserve a downvote for something else irrelevant?  (This is a rhetorical question, no need to answer.)

Comment: @Zacky: There are quite a lot of off-topic comments under Batominovski's meta post, which suggests that low rep profile may not be quite a reason for the flood of off-topic comments.

Comment: @Zacky "Wouldn't it be better to flag the moderators if someone thinks something is inappropriate and keep the comments on-topic?" Yes. That's what I did, I flagged 3 comments here, all were declined

Comment: This is a rare occurrence. You should flag a moderator, instead of complaining to meta.

Comment: @amwhy: Your comment seems to be quite irrelevant to the main concerns of the question here. On the contrary, I do not think the occurrence is very rare.

Comment: Well, I don't think you really can gauge what is rare and what is not, given your comment here, and your comment on my recent question.  But that's okay.  I commend you for trying to contribute as a very new user.  It would be nice if all users came to meta in their first week on the site.

Comment: @T.S Apparently, a certain user still considers me as a target for downvoting, despite my request to cease the interaction.  I am certain that this sinister downvoting will continue non-stop.  I have flagged for moderator intervention, but I am not sure whether this will help much.

Comment: @T.S "On the contrary, I do not think the occurrence is very rare." indeed. Actually I think there's a pattern, according to what Batominovski said in their other post and to what I observed. If this user doesn't agree (to say the least) with what you say/do, then goes quickly to one of your math post and downvotes. If this happens twice, then goes to downvote serially. Other times on other reps. are 28sec, 35sec and 17sec. of downvotes

Comment: lol I think I not made my point.. anyway the thing is that it would  be sooo nice if this user _only_ serially downvotes when they don't agree with you on something. but that's not the case, the user first say lots of unkind comments to you (to say the least), and then the downvotes come. so you see. Of course that, it's not that bad, once you _know_ them (u know u can't expect nice things from them)  but when it comes for the first time.. ugh, good luck to that new users.

Comment: @T.S  Can you believe that, after all the moderator intervention, I think a certain user has started to target me again?  I still am not sure what I did to spark this event.  I have flagged for moderator attention, but I think nothing is going to be done, like the last time.  A warning is basically nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Such things are supervised to the extent possible (it is not always possible though) and actions are taken (in the form of warnings or suspensions). However, even when we identify the source and take action the votes are not always reversed mostly for practical reasons.

It *is* annoying and even a form of abuse, but the practical implications are fortunately limited except when it happens at a larger scale. At the scale we are talking about the issue you raise are mostly a theoretical concern.

That said, it is not very clear what the specific purpose of your post is. For example, if you check the profile of a user that was accused in this context, you will see a similar pattern numerous times. If they, or anyone, posted here about every couple of votes, meta would be full of such reports.

Comment: "meta would be full of such reports" - I understand that this is a recurrent situation. Then, would it not be possible to find an automatic solution? Something like not allowing a user to downvote two answers/questions of a certain user within a specific time slot (say 1 minute). This would not eliminate the problem, but it would at least help discourage this sort of behavior.

Comment: I don't want to come of as dismissive. But quite frankly I don't think that would be any relevant improvement, especially not with a minute. If this should have an effect at all it'd need to be much longer, and then it will start to interfere with normal use. Note that actual bursts of votes are caught automatically. One vote or two votes, practically it's irrelevant. *The problem is the intent, the message that is sent.* The votes per se are often irrelevant. The bias argument is mostly irrelevant, compare my comment on OP.

Comment: This was just an idea and I agree with you. I was thinking maybe if the user is not allowed to downvote consecutively quickly, his mind will wander and maybe forget his grudge. Also maybe a pop up message to the user when such a pattern is detected, something to make him rethink (and possibly shame him :D) his intent might be an idea.

Comment: Actually a warning like you propose could make sense. Also for upvoting, which also should not be done serially. Though much fewer users complain about that.

Comment: Of course :D, as in real life. For example, if you manage a Internet network, nobody thanks you when it works. But should it not work for 10 minutes one day, all hell breaks loose. I guess it's the same for moderators here :) and people don't trully understand and appreciate your effort.