# "Improve this question" button on deleted posts goes to a page which says "This post is deleted and cannot be edited."

Tags: bug, editing, closed-questions

I went into my "recently deleted answers" tab and found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680043/derivative-of-3-cscx) (which is now deleted, so you cannot see it if you have <10k rep) which I answered. I can't normally see deleted questions as I have <10k rep, but I could see this one in my recently deleted answers.

This is what I see[image]

The one answer I can see is mine.

---

I clicked the "Improve this question" button and I got sent to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3680043/edit), and this is what I see
[image]
A page which says "This post is deleted and cannot be edited." and is otherwise blank.

I have tried this with other deleted posts, all with the same result. 
 The "Improve this question" button leads to the same blank page.

Is this a bug for me? If not, **why is there a button to "Improve this question" for me if I cannot edit the question?**
**If I cannot edit the question, I should not see this button.**

Comment: I think it might be possible for the OP to improve the Question without first undeleting, since the Question was deleted by a community vote.  So the "Improve this question" button might not work for you until the Question is undeleted.  You should post a request on the "canonical" [reopen/undelete thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) if that is your preference.

Comment: I am able to edit it. So it’s probably tied to your reputation, and the fact that you can see it at all is connected to you having answered it.

Comment: Arturo is correct. Just to explain the situation, users cannot *suggest an edit* to a deleted post. Only users who can edit the post directly (e.g. the OP, the 2000-rep users, and certainly the mods) can use the button (or the "edit" link on the post directly).

Comment: I also could edit it.  It is probably as Arturo said.