# Problem asking problem.

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I think it's been one month. Mathematics Stack Exchange doesn't accept my question. After the positive work in Stack Exchange I earned more than $500$ reputation by  answering many questions and editing problems and answers also flagged many problems. But still, that doesn't accept my question.

When will I be free from this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't know. The moderators can see that you are currently banned from asking questions, but the system does not tell us for how long, except in short-term cases.

Note that in addition to your current positive track record, you are still lugging around your older record of deleted questions which includes several questions, all with a low score, and most of which are closed.

Four of your five undeleted questions are closed, and one of these has a negative score. That is not a positive track record, as far as asking questions go. You should start by editing your existing questions. Improve the formatting, add context to them (not just what you're tried, but also why *this* problem: is it from a book, or a mock-exam, or an old test, or you just happened upon it, etc.) Once you've edited your questions, ask that they are reopened ([Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) is a good start).

If you can get your questions back to the "positive side", your ban should be lifted.

Comment: It is rather small consolation prize - but perhaps it is still worth mentioning that if a user is question-banned, they are allowed to post one new question after six months.

Comment: Thanks, I edited all four closed questions. One of them is reopened. After reopening all my questions. Will ban on me removed?@Asaf Karagila