# Advice for getting a question reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, re-open

I had recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752559/pivot-of-vectors).  There were some good answers before it got closed. However, I think there could be better answers. I don't know how to phrase my query precisely, as it's not related to a single mathematical equation or formula; rather, it is of mathematical theory which I don't understand.

I tried phrasing it and editing it countless times.

I seek the help of someone who is more familiar of the site and can advise me on how to improve my question.

It has been suggested that this meta question is a duplicate of [Requests for Reopen & Undelete Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today).  This post tells me about reopening question and reasons for closure of some questions. The reason which I was given for the closure of my question (needs detail or clarity) was not enough for me to understand 'what to do' to better my question. And I do think that some people who have answered and commented have in fact got at the idea of what I want to convey, so I am asking if some group of you **could tell me how to better my question such that it gets reopened**.

Comment: Also see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|129.9377).

Comment: bruh.. my question is very specifically for improving the question I asked. I ask a question how to open my closed question and you decide to close my question on that , ok

Comment: sis...  See my second link on an elaborate answer with many ways you can improve your question.  Glad to have helped you! You're welcome!

Comment: I have added (specific-question), see [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for the information about the purpose of this tag. If you want to ask about a general question about the reopening process and the linked question only serves as a specific example, feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: Nonetheless, @MartinSleziak  You know there is a specific thread, which I posted in my first comment, dedicated to the reopening of *specific questions*.  Why enable such users to take up space on meta, when there is a designated place for them to go???

Comment: It's specific advice for a specific question to get specifically reopened. I did not ask 'how does a question get reopened?' or the 'reason for my closure'. I asked for advice on formatting my question better because I stumped how to. I think this is an equally good problem that anyone would have to deal with in their usage of s.e

Comment: I am so sorry @amWhy now I realized that in the thread I could gain attention of others for reopening of my question

Comment: I'd recommend you also improve your post if you want it reopened and to get a better answer than those already given you.  Again, please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|129.9377).  You explicitly asked here how to improve your question.  The link in this comment will inform you now, and in the future.

Comment: The whole question I am asking what specifically should I look for? like what am I missing?

Comment: Reading your linked question, you clearly did not use the suggestions in "How to ask a good question," to improve it..  Sorry, but please actually read the linked post on "how to ask a good question."  And then, *after considering the suggestions given* apply what is appropriate to your question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, as I do not think that it is a duplicate of the "reopen request thread".  As I understand the question, the asker is not requesting that their question be reopened, but is asking what they need to do in order to improve their question so that it can be reopened (though I might be over interpreting?).  It may be that this is a duplicate question, but I do not think that it is a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: You yourself write, "I don't know how to phrase my query precisely... it is of mathematical theory which I don't understand."  However your Readers need to rely on you to be the expert on *what you are asking*.  When you find it necessary to rephrase and edit "countless times," this may be an indication that you should step back to asking something more basic, in order to build a foundation to reach what you are motivated by.  As a rule of thumb, ask "Will I be able to tell whether an Answer is correct?"  If not, then consider stepping back to a topic where you can do that.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I shall take it in my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NB:  This is general advice, meant to address the question "What do I need to do in order to get my question reopened?"  I have read the specific question mentioned in this topic, but I have not gone over it in detail, and have no intention of addressing that question specifically.  What follows is advice which is meant to help *any* asker who finds their question closed.

**Your question has been closed.  Now what?**

If your question was closed as a duplicate then, if the system is working, you have received a useful answer, and you are happy.  If not, then follow the advice given below.

If your question was closed for some deficit of quality or appropriateness for Math SE (e.g. if it was closed because it "needs clarity or context", it is "opinion based", it "seeks persona advice", etc), then you will need to edit your question in order to bring it up to the quality standards of the site.  Remember that the main goal of Math Stack Exchange is to produce a database of questions and high quality answers, hence your question should be of general interest, and should provide enough information to explain *why* it is of general interest.  This context should be added to the question via editing.

In order to get an idea of what kind of context is required in order to get your question reopened:

1. Read (and follow the advice given in) the meta question [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C129.9377).
2. Read the comments under your question.  Respond to questions and requests for clarification—*engage* with the commenters.  Finally, edit your question to address the concerns raised by the commenters.
3. Use the chat system.  The room [Constructive Feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) is a good place to get, well... constructive feedback.
4. Again, *engage* with the commenters, the people in chat, and anyone else who is trying to help.  Folk on Math Stack Exchange may often seem cold, but this is not personal—there are a large number of people who seem to regard this website as a homework completion service, and a lot of the regulars are pretty cynical and/or jaded.  Demonstrate that you are open willing to put in effort, and that you *aren't* just trying to get others to do your work for you.  Respond to comments.  Take the advice given.  And remember:  it isn't personal.

Once you have edited your question in order to bring it up to the quality standards of the site

1. Wait.  The first time that you edit your question after it is closed, it will be sent to the "Reopen" review queue, where users with sufficient reputation will be allowed to vote to reopen the question.
2. Post a reopen request in the current [reopen requests thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) (note that this link may not be the right link in the future; a new thread is started from time to time).
3. Request reopening in the [CURED chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).