# People behavior in math.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

I was struggling with a math problem and just went to send it to math.stackexchange in order to check my answer. but I see tsunami of condescension and arrogance. some people targeting the question and trying to close it at any cost. first sent a link to say it is duplicate after see this fails keep sending other links and after trying his/her best said "there is a high chance for close as missing context or other details". although it closed finally but I really don't see any connection with my question and the link they sent and it was not even contain the limit problem I wanted to check ! it is really bad behavior, some people trying constantly close specific question it made me angry. It is like I am targeting a user and downvote all their post. "community" reflects many of characteristics that put people off mathematics.

Here is question I am talking about: [Do we have $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}=e?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888910/do-we-have-lim-n-to-01n-tfrac1n-e)

It is not fair to be closed. I really demanding for reopening the question. thank you.

Comment: There seem to be two things involved in this meta question: (1) you want your question reopened, and (2) you seem not to understand why it was closed in the first place.  Regarding (1), there is a dedicated [meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692) for such requests---meta would quickly become unusable if everyone with a closed question posted a new question here.  Regarding (2), I do not think that the question was closed inappropriately.  It lacks context and has already been answered before.

Comment: Downvotes are not a personal attack against you. It is just *information* on the quality of your post.

Comment: @soheil I understand you feeling and of course there is an issue for welcomingness of the site especially for newcomer (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/389429)). Anyway in this specific case I don't think that this is the (main) point. We also have, among the community, different point of views on how duplicates should be handled (see [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: In general, before asking a question, you always should check for duplicates. If you need some more explanation, to avoid such situations, you need to add more details and the references to the questions you have already looked at.

Comment: @user Yes. you are right. maybe I exaggerated. but if the number of closed questions increase site ban the user....

Comment: IIRC, @soheil, duplicate closures do not affect the question ban.

Comment: @ArcticChar Very good ;D

Answer (score 8):

Pointing out previous Questions and Answers is not condescension but part of the practice here to further your studies.

Your underlying problem, can one replace the sequential limit $n\to +\infty$ ($n\in \mathbb Z$) with one having a continuous limit $x\to +\infty$ ($x\in \mathbb R$), is certainly a valid query.  However it has been dealt with in a large number of previous Questions on Math.SE, and in the absence of your showing that you searched for these, having them pointed out for you should be considered a benefit.

In fact it is hard to be sure if you have been thinking about the latter limit in just these terms, although most Readers will understand your post in those terms.  In order to get resolutions of problems that are well-matched to your level of studies, we ask those who post Questions to include at least brief remarks that provide *context*.  Here it might be a problem you thought of because of reading a paper or it might be something that came about as more of a class assignment.  But either way a better understanding of your interest in the Question helps Readers to respond in ways you would find more suited to your studies.

Comment: The number of times I thought I've come up with something novel, only to find a post on a forum (or a side remark from Euler, honestly) is certainly humbling. It's part of the learning experience and there's nothing to feel bad about if someone's asked your question or a variant of it first.

Comment: I actually wanted to check my answer is right or not. It shouldn't be consider as duplicate. I don't understand what is the problem of checking answer.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with searching for similar questions. the questions that members mentioned as duplicate target, Even if I saw those question before posting it I would consider asking the question too in order to find new ideas or see people verify that or not. For example in first comment a person mentioned using L'hopital rule. Which was useful for me. But so sad in a comment a user said ok for "no need for discussion for second part of your question the answer is yes your work is right and for first part vote to close"

Comment: If you are asking if the limits is correct, then the answer is yes and you have been given the answer. If you have tried to tackle the problem and want someone to check your step..... you did not show your work to us. @soheil